# Using PlotLegends with Show messes up the graphics

Tags: plotting, legending

I have already obtained the plot that I want but am having trouble legending the graph correctly.

```
plot = ListLogLogPlot[Sort[depth4], PlotRange -> {{1, 50000}, {1, 50000}}, Joined -> True, 
PlotStyle -> {Purple}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}];

line = LogLogPlot[11024 x^(-0.94232), {x, 1, 100000}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Orange, Dashed, Thick}];
line2 = LogLogPlot[31862 x^(-1.07076), {x, 1, 100000}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Green, Dotted, Thick}];

Show[plot, line, line2]
```

If I insert a legend command into the first plot, it doesn't work. I need to be able to legend my 3 curves in the graph. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Clearly the main objective here is to have a single legend for several different plots. A related problem, addressed below by F'x, is to make a legend for a single plot with several lines or data sets. That issue is also addressed in this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/creating-legends-for-plots-with-multiple-lines

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When `Show` is used the legends use `ShowLegend`. Here is a demo:

```
depth4 = Range[20]^3;
plot = ListLogLogPlot[Sort[depth4], PlotRange -> {{1, 50000},
     {1, 50000}}, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Purple},
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}];
line = LogLogPlot[11024 x^(-0.94232), {x, 1, 100000},
   PlotStyle -> {Orange, Dashed, Thick}];
line2 = LogLogPlot[31862 x^(-1.07076), {x, 1, 100000},
   PlotStyle -> {Green, Dotted, Thick}];

Needs["PlotLegends`"]
ShowLegend[Show[plot, line, line2, ImageSize -> 500],
 {{{Graphics[{Purple, Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}]}], "   depth4"},
   {Graphics[{Orange, Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}]}], "   line"},
   {Graphics[{Green, Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}]}], "   line2"}},
  LegendPosition -> {0.7, 0.2}, LegendSize -> {0.45, 0.4},
  LegendShadow -> False}]
```

[image]

Comment: great thank you!

Answer (score 29):

While in many ways Mathematica's graphics is miles ahead of its competition, the supplied legend package looks like a hack that does not belong. In its own documentation, under Inset, you will find examples of better looking legends. Building on those examples, I have a simple legend function.

```
ClearAll[simpleLegend]
simpleLegend[legendItems__,pos_]:=Module[{legendLine,offset,legend},
  offset=Module[{s,o,insetpts=10},
    s=pos/.{Left->0,Right->1,Bottom->0,Top->1};
    o=insetpts pos/.{Left->1,Right->-1,Bottom->1,Top->-1};
    Offset[o,Scaled[s]]
  ];
  legendLine[{lbl_,lineStyle_}]:={
    Graphics[{lineStyle,Line[{{0,0.5},{1,0.5}}]},ImageSize->{20,10},AspectRatio->0.5],
    Style[lbl,FontFamily->"Tahoma",FontSize->11,TextAlignment->Left,LineBreakWithin->False]
  };
  legend=GraphicsGrid[legendLine/@legendItems,Alignment->Left];
  Graphics@Inset[legend,offset,pos]
];
```

which can be used like this

```
labels={"data","eq1","eq2"};
styles={Directive[Purple],Directive[Orange,Dashed,Thick],Directive[Green,Dotted,Thick]};

depth4=Table[{x,(11024 x^(-0.94232))*RandomReal[{0.4,1.6}]}/.x->10^n,{n,0,5,0.1}];

plot=ListLogLogPlot[Sort[depth4],
  PlotRange->{{1,50000},{1,50000}},Joined->True,PlotStyle->styles[[1]],
    BaseStyle->{FontSize->14}
];

line=LogLogPlot[11024 x^(-0.94232),{x,1,100000},PlotStyle->styles[[2]]];
line2=LogLogPlot[31862 x^(-1.07076),{x,1,100000},PlotStyle->styles[[3]]];

Show[plot,line,line2,simpleLegend[Thread@{labels,styles},{Right,Top}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this solution. How do I add instead of a dashed line, traingles or circle markers?

Answer (score 14):

You can also use `Epilog->Inset[...]` as follows:

For

```
  depth4 = Range[20]^3; 
  plot =  ListLogLogPlot[Sort[depth4], PlotRange -> {{1, 50000}, {1, 50000}}, 
  Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Purple}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}]; 
  line = LogLogPlot[11024 x^(-0.94232), {x, 1, 100000}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Orange, Dashed, Thick}]; 
  line2 = LogLogPlot[31862 x^(-1.07076), {x, 1, 100000}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Green, Dotted, Thick}];
```

as in Chris's answer,

```
 Show[plot, line, line2, ImageSize -> 500, 
 Epilog -> 
 Inset[Panel[
 Grid[{{Graphics[{Purple, 
 Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}]}, AspectRatio -> .1, ImageSize -> 30], 
   Style["depth4", FontFamily -> "SketchFlowPrint", Bold, FontColor -> Purple]}, 
  {Graphics[{Orange, Dashed, 
     Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}]}, AspectRatio -> .1, ImageSize -> 30],
    Style["line", FontFamily -> "SketchFlowPrint", Bold, FontColor -> Orange]}, 
  {Graphics[{Green, Dotted, 
     Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}]}, AspectRatio -> .1, ImageSize -> 30],
    Style["line2", FontFamily -> "SketchFlowPrint", Bold, FontColor -> Green]}}, 
 Alignment -> {{Left, Left}, {Left, Left}}], ImageSize -> Full], 
 Offset[{-2, -2}, Scaled[{1, 1}]], {Right, Top}]]
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In Mathematica 10.3 you can use `LineLegend`. I myself have never liked to have a legend within the plot, so I insert it in a grid.

```
depth4 = Range[20]^3;
style1 = Directive[Purple];
plot = ListLogLogPlot[Sort[depth4], 
   PlotRange -> {{1, 50000}, {1, 50000}}, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> style1, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}];
style2 = Directive[Orange, Dashed, Thick];
line = LogLogPlot[11024 x^(-0.94232), {x, 1, 100000}, 
   PlotStyle -> style2];
style3 = Directive[Green, Dotted, Thick];
line2 = LogLogPlot[31862 x^(-1.07076), {x, 1, 100000}, 
   PlotStyle -> style3];
temp = Grid[{{
    Show[{plot, line, line2}, ImageSize -> 300]
    , LineLegend[{style1, style2, style3}, {"plot", "line", "line2"}]
    }}]
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "plot_linelegend.png", temp]
```

If you save the notebook somewhere, you will obtain directly a png image of the plot with the legend as this one

[image: Grid with plot and line legend]

Comment: You could also use `Legended` instead of `Grid`: `Legended[Show[{plot, line, line2}], 
 LineLegend[{style1, style2, style3}, {"plot", "line", "line2"}]]`

Answer (score 7):

I'm using version 10.2, and it seems that the legends from the initial plots work just fine with `Show`

```
depth4 = Range[20]^3;
plot = ListLogLogPlot[Sort[depth4], 
   PlotRange -> {{1, 50000}, {1, 50000}}, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {Purple}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"plot"}];

line = LogLogPlot[11024 x^(-0.94232), {x, 1, 100000}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Orange, Dashed, Thick}, PlotLegends -> {"line"}];
line2 = LogLogPlot[31862 x^(-1.07076), {x, 1, 100000}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Green, Dotted, Thick}, PlotLegends -> {"line2"}];

Show[plot, line, line2]
```

[image]

You'll notice that the purple line is smaller, because for some reason *Mathematica* makes the legend line longer if there is dashing.  If we make the purple line dashed (but not really dashed), then they are consistent.

```
plot = ListLogLogPlot[Sort[depth4], 
   PlotRange -> {{1, 2 50000}, {1, 50000}}, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {Purple,Dashing[{1, 0}]}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, PlotLegends -> {"plot"}];
Show[plot, line, line2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can extract `Line` directives (color, thickness, dashing, etc. specifications) from the plot itself. This means that you don't have to call for a second time for the style specifications explicitly. For complex graphics (with e.g. plot markers) it might not be this simple though.

```
depth4 = Range[20]^3;
plot = ListLogLogPlot[Sort[depth4], 
   PlotRange -> {{1, 50000}, {1, 50000}}, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {Purple}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}];
line = LogLogPlot[11024 x^(-0.94232), {x, 1, 100000}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Orange, Dashed, Thick}];
line2 = LogLogPlot[31862 x^(-1.07076), {x, 1, 100000}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Green, Dotted, Thick}];

data = Show[plot, line, line2];
styles = Cases[data, {dir__, l_Line} :> {dir}, \[Infinity]]
```

> ```
> {{Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], RGBColor[0.5, 0, 0.5]}, {Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], 
>   RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0], Dashing[{Small, Small}], 
>   Thickness[Large]}, {Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], RGBColor[0, 1, 0], 
>   Dashing[{0, Small}], Thickness[Large]}}
> ```

```
Row@{
  Show[plot, line, line2, ImageSize -> 300],
  Grid[Table[{Graphics[Append[styles[[i]], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]], 
      ImageSize -> 50, AspectRatio -> 1/5], "plot" <> ToString@i}, {i,
      3}], Spacings -> {1, 2}]
  }
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You don't need `InputForm` for this.  The `Graphics` expression is directly manipulable.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you're right, thanks for pointing it out. I guess this was just some bad habit surviving from pre-6 times.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of a direct way to do that once the individual graphs have been plotted and legended. You can, however, use `ListLogLogPlot` on a table containing values from your functions, so as to have a single call to a `Plot` function, which can thus take a `PlotLegend` option:

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"];
ListLogLogPlot[{
  Sort[depth4],
  Table[{x, 11024 x^(-0.94232)} /. x -> 10^n, {n, 0, 5, 0.1}],
  Table[{x, 31862 x^(-1.07076)} /. x -> 10^n, {n, 0, 5, 0.1}]
  },
 PlotRange -> {{1, 50000}, {1, 50000}},
 Joined -> True,
 PlotStyle -> {Purple, Directive[Orange, Dashed, Thick], 
   Directive[Green, Dotted, Thick]},
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14},
 PlotLegend -> {"data", "eq1", "eq2"}]
```

[image: resulting plot]

---

PS: you were missing the definitio for `depth4`, so I took:

```
depth4 = Table[{x, (11024 x^(-0.94232))*RandomReal[{0.4, 1.6}]} /. x -> 10^n, {n, 0, 5, 0.1}];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, however Chris Degnen's method is easier for me as i have to do this with many graphs. :)