# Creating legends for plots with multiple lines?

Tags: plotting, legending

So I have a graph with multiple lists, for e.g.

```
data = {{1,2}, {3,4}, {3,5}, {2,3} . . .}
```

If I then do `ListLinePlot[Table[{#1,Log[b,#2]}&@@@data, {b,1,10,2}]]` I have no way to generate a legend for it, that I see anyway. I cannot put anything inside the `Table` which contains the iterator. Would I do something alone the lines of `Legend-> Log[Range[1,10,2,x]]`?

Comment: Relevant question (and answers) [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3518/57).

Comment: BTW I see you are pretty quick to accept answers. Though this is fine in itself it's usually better to wait at least a couple of hours (or even days) before accepting an answer. This way you will probably get more and perhaps better answers.

Comment: An older related question is [How do I label different curves in Mathematica?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7221315/421225)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

In case you want more flexibility, it's also possible to design your own legends, for example along the lines of [this MathGroup post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/3SzRr4lIFN4/Vvmp_UU_V9gJ). For your example, the process would start with the function `legendMaker`.

Instead of repeating the same definition as in the above post, I've overhauled `legendMaker` in response to image_doctor's answer, to separate out the handling of options better.

I've tried to make the spacings and widths of the legends more customizable, and also separated the automatic extraction of the line and marker styles into a separate function `extractStyles` so that it's easier to modify if needed later.

Here I'm listing all the functions in one code block to make them easier to copy. Below, I'll go through the usage examples for these functions in the order they were written: i.e., from the low-level `legendMaker` to the high-level `deployLegend`.

`legendMaker` allows individual line styles and plot markers to have the value `None`. This makes it easier to specify custom legends, in particular when combining a line plot without markers, and a list plot without lines. This is motivated by [a related answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4495/245), so I posted an example there.

**Edit July 14, 2013**

A year has passed since the last update to this code, because *Mathematica* version 9 introduced the new command  [`PlotLegends`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotLegends.html) which in many cases should make this answer obsolete. However, **I tried to keep this answer compatible with versions 8 and 9**. This is why this update is necessary, since some functionality was broken in recent *Mathematica* versions.

The major changes were in the function `extractStyles` which tries to guess what lines and markers are being used in a given plot. This relies on the internal structure of the plots, and is therefore fragile. I tried to make it more robust.

I also added usage messages and made sure that `autoLegend` (the simplest legending function in this answer) accepts the full range of options of `legendMaker` (the more lower-level legend drawing function). All the examples below are unchanged, except that I added more information at the end.

```
Options[legendMaker] = 
  Join[FilterRules[Options[Framed], 
    Except[{ImageSize, FrameStyle, Background, RoundingRadius, 
      ImageMargins}]], {FrameStyle -> None, 
    Background -> Directive[Opacity[.7], LightGray], 
    RoundingRadius -> 10, ImageMargins -> 0, PlotStyle -> Automatic, 
    PlotMarkers -> None, "LegendLineWidth" -> 35, 
    "LegendLineAspectRatio" -> .3, "LegendMarkerSize" -> 8, 
    "LegendGridOptions" -> {Alignment -> Left, Spacings -> {.4, .1}}}];


legendMaker::usage = 
  "Create a Graphics object with legends given by the list passed as \
the first argument. The options specify any non-deafult line styles \
(using PlotStyle -> {...}) or plot markers (using PlotMarkers -> \
{...}). For more options, inspect Options[legendMaker]";

legendMaker[textLabels_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{f, lineDirectives, markerSymbols, n = Length[textLabels], 
    x}, lineDirectives = ((PlotStyle /. {opts}) /. 
       PlotStyle | Automatic :> Map[ColorData[1], Range[n]]) /. 
     None -> {None};
   markerSymbols = 
    Replace[((PlotMarkers /. {opts}) /. 
         Automatic :> (Drop[
              Normal[ListPlot[Transpose[{Range[3]}], 
                  PlotMarkers -> Automatic][[1, 2]]][[1]], -1] /. 
             Inset[x_, i__] :> x)[[All, -1]]) /. {Graphics[gr__], 
         sc_} :> Graphics[gr, 
         ImageSize -> ("LegendMarkerSize" /. {opts} /. 
             Options[legendMaker, 
              "LegendMarkerSize"] /. {"LegendMarkerSize" -> 8})], 
      PlotMarkers | None :> 
       Map[Style["", Opacity[0]] &, textLabels]] /. 
     None | {} -> Style["", Opacity[0]];
   lineDirectives = PadRight[lineDirectives, n, lineDirectives];
   markerSymbols = PadRight[markerSymbols, n, markerSymbols];
   f = Grid[
     MapThread[{Graphics[{#1 /. None -> {}, 
          If[#1 === {None} || (PlotStyle /. {opts}) === None, {}, 
           Line[{{-.1, 0}, {.1, 0}}]], 
          Inset[#2, {0, 0}, Background -> None]}, 
         AspectRatio -> ("LegendLineAspectRatio" /. {opts} /. 
             Options[legendMaker, 
              "LegendLineAspectRatio"] /. {"LegendLineAspectRatio" -> \
.2}), ImageSize -> ("LegendLineWidth" /. {opts} /. 
             Options[legendMaker, 
              "LegendLineWidth"] /. {"LegendLineWidth" -> 35}), 
         ImagePadding -> {{1, 1}, {0, 0}}], 
        Text[#3, FormatType -> TraditionalForm]} &, {lineDirectives, 
       markerSymbols, textLabels}], 
     Sequence@
      Evaluate[("LegendGridOptions" /. {opts} /. 
          Options[legendMaker, 
           "LegendGridOptions"] /. {"LegendGridOptions" -> {Alignment \
-> Left, Spacings -> {.4, .1}}})]];
   Framed[f, 
    FilterRules[{Sequence[opts, Options[legendMaker]]}, 
     FilterRules[Options[Framed], Except[ImageSize]]]]];

extractStyles::usage = "returns a tuple {\"all line style \
directives\", \"all plot markers\"} found in the plot, in the order \
they are drawn. The two sublists need not have the same length if \
some lines don't use markers "; 
extractStyles[plot_] := 
 Module[{lines, markers, points, 
   extract = First[Normal[plot]]},(*In a plot,
  the list of lines contains no insets,so I use this to find it:*)
  lines = 
   Select[Cases[Normal[plot], {___, _Line, ___}, Infinity], 
    FreeQ[#1, Inset] &];
  points = 
   Select[Cases[Normal[plot], {___, _Point, ___}, Infinity], 
    FreeQ[#1, Inset] &];
  (*Most plot markers are inside Inset,
  except for Point in list plots:*)
  markers = Select[extract, ! FreeQ[#1, Inset] &];
  (*The function returns a list of lists:*){(*The first return value \
is the list of line plot styles:*)
   Replace[Cases[
     lines, {c__, Line[__], ___} :> 
      Flatten[Directive @@ Cases[{c}, Except[_Line]]], 
     Infinity], {} -> None],
   (*Second return value:marker symbols*)
   Replace[Join[
     Cases[markers//. Except[List][i_Inset, __] :> i, 
       {c__, Inset[s_, pos_, d___], e___} :> If[
        (*markers "s" can be strings or graphics*)

        Head[s] === Graphics,
        (*Append scale factor in case it's needed later;
        default 0.01*)
        {s,
         Last[{.01, d}] /. Scaled[f_] :> First[f]
         },
        If[
         (*For strings,
         add line color if no color specified via text styles:*)
             FreeQ[ s, _?ColorQ], Style[s, c], s]
        ],
      Infinity
      ],
     (*
     Filter out Pointsize-legends don't need it:*)

     Cases[points, {c___, 
        Point[pt__], ___} :> {Graphics[{c, Point[{0, 0}]}] /. 
         PointSize[_] :> PointSize[1], .01}, Infinity]
     ], {} -> None]}]

autoLegend::usage = 
  "Simplified legending for the plot passed as first argument, with \
legends given as second argument. Use the option Alignment -> \
{horizontal, vertical} to place the legend in the PlotRegion in \
scaled coordinates. For other options, see Options[legendMaker] which \
are used by autoLegend.";
Options[autoLegend] = 
  Join[{Alignment -> {Right, Top}, Background -> White, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic}, 
   FilterRules[Options[legendMaker], 
    Except[Alignment | Background | AspectRatio]]];
autoLegend[plot_Graphics, labels_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{lines, markers, align = OptionValue[Alignment]},
  {lines, markers} = extractStyles[plot];
  Graphics[{
    Inset[plot, {-1, -1},
     {Left, Bottom},
     Scaled[1]
     ],
    Inset[
     legendMaker[labels, PlotStyle -> lines, PlotMarkers -> markers, 
      Sequence @@ 
       FilterRules[{opts}, 
        FilterRules[Options[legendMaker], Except[Alignment]]]],
     align,
     Map[If[NumericQ[#], Center, #] &, align]
     ]
    },
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
   AspectRatio -> (OptionValue[AspectRatio] /. 
       Automatic :> (AspectRatio /. Options[plot, AspectRatio]) /. 
      Automatic :> (AspectRatio /. 
         AbsoluteOptions[plot, AspectRatio]))]]
```

**Notes for `legendMaker`:**

The horizontal width of the line segment in the legend can be changed with the option `"LegendLineWidth"`, and its aspect ratio is set by `"LegendLineAspectRatio"`. The size of the markers in the legend is set by `"LegendMarkerSize"` (all these options have reasonable default values), and they can also be passed to the higher-level functions below.

The only required argument for this version of `legendMaker` is a list of labels. Everything else is optional. I.e., the function automatically determines what to do about the matching line colors and plot marker symbols (if any).

Plot markers can be defined as `String` or `Graphics` objects. To control the line colors, you can specify the option `PlotStyle`: with `PlotStyle -> Automatic`, the default plot styles are used. If you have instead prepared the plot with a different list of plot styles, you can enter that here. The option `PlotStyle -> None` is also allowed. This should be used when labeling a `ListPlot` that has no connecting lines between the points.

With the setting `PlotMarkers -> Automatic`, the legend will also display marker symbols according to the default choices that I extract from a temporary `ListPlot` that is then discarded. The default setting for `legendMaker` is `PlotMarkers -> None`.

To make the plots look nice, you can add other options for the legend appearance, e.g.:

```
opts = Sequence[Background -> LightOrange, RoundingRadius -> 10];
```

Here I allow all options that `Frame` can handle, except for `ImageSize`.

Now we prepare a plot:

```
data = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 4}};
points = Table[{#1, Log[b, #2]} & @@@ data, {b, 2, 10, 2}];
plot = ListLinePlot[points];
```

The list `labels` creates the text that you were asking for:

```
labels = Table[Row[{Subscript["Log", b], x}], {b, 2, 10, 2}]
```

> $\left\{\text{Log}_2x,\text{Log}_4x,\text{Log}_6x,\text{Log}_8x,\text{Log}_{10}x\right\}$

The legend is now displayed as an overlay over the original `plot`:

```
newPlot = 
 Overlay[{plot, legendMaker[labels, opts]}, Alignment -> {Right, Top}]
```

[image: plot legends]

The `Overlay` that is created here can still be exported and copied even though it's not a graphics box. A good way to copy it to an external editor is to highlight the plot and select `Copy As... PDF` from the `Edit` menu (that's at least where it is on Mac OS X).

A different application of `legendMaker` can be found [in this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4040/plot-legend-inside-a-show/4041#4041). That's also a good example for the difference in appearance to the standard `Legends` package, which many people consider sub-par (it's slow, old-fashioned and even crashes sometimes).

**Notes for `autoLegend`**

In response to the comment by Ajasja, I added another layer of automation that makes use of the function `legendMaker` defined above, but attempts to deduce the colors and marker symbols from the provided plot in a fully automatic way.

As an example, I took

```
p = ListPlot[Evaluate[Table[RandomInteger[3 i, 10] + 2 i, {i, 3}]], 
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Joined -> True]
```

and added labels by calling

```
autoLegend[p, {"Small", "Big", "Bigger"}, 
 Background -> Directive[LightOrange, Opacity[.5]], 
 Alignment -> {Right, Top}]
```

[image: Automatic labeling]

The function `autoLegend` takes the same options as `legendMaker`, plus the `Alignment` option which follows the conventions for `Overlay`.

Here is an example wit graphical markers:

```
p = ListPlot[Evaluate[Table[RandomInteger[3 i, 10] + 2 i, {i, 3}]], 
  PlotMarkers -> {{Graphics@{Red, Disk[]}, .05}, {Graphics@{Blue, 
       Rectangle[]}, .05}}, Joined -> True];
autoLegend[p, {"Small", "Big", "Bigger"}, Alignment -> {-.8, .8}]
```

[image: Graphics markers]

`autoLegend` is still limited in the sense that its automatic extraction doesn't yet work with `GraphicsGrid` or `GraphicsRow` (but I'll add that at some point). But at least it seems to behave reasonably when you give it several plots at once, e.g. as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463437/plotting-legends-in-mathematica/3533152#3533152):

```
plot1 = Show[Plot[{Sin[x], Sinh[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}], 
  ListPlot[Join[{#, Sin[#]} & /@ Range[-Pi, Pi, .5], {#, Sinh[#]} & /@
      Range[-Pi, Pi, .5]]]];
autoLegend[plot1, {"Sin", "Sinh"}]
```

[image: Two plots labeled]

**Edit July 5, 2012**

By creating the plot legend as an overlay, one gains flexibility because the legend created with `legendMaker` doesn't have to be "inside" any particular graphics object; it can for example overlap two plots (see also [my MathGroup post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/3SzRr4lIFN4/Vvmp_UU_V9gJ)).

However, overlays aren't so convenient in other respects. Importantly, the graphics editing tools that come with Mathematica can't be used directly to fine-tune the plot and/or legend when it's in an overlay. In an `Overlay`, I can't make both the plot and legend selectable (and editable) at the same time.

That's why I changed `autoLegend` such that it uses `Insets` instead of `Overlay`. The positioning just requires a little more code because `Inset` needs   different coordinate systems to determine its placement and size. To the user, the placement happens in pretty much the same way that the `Alignment` works in `Overlay`: you can either use named positions such as `Alignment -> {Left, Bottom}` or numerical scale factors such as `Alignment -> {0.5, 0}`. In the latter case, the numbers range from `-1` to `1` in the horizontal and vertical direction, with `{0, 0}` being the center of the plot.

With this method, the plot is fully editable, **as shown in the movie below**. The movie uses a differently named function `deployLegend`, but from now on we can define `deployLegend = autoLegend`

```
deployLegend[p, {"Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3"}]
```

[image: Screen shot of legend editing]

This is a screen capture of how the legend is now available as part of the graphics object. First, I make a color change in one of the labels to show that the legend preserves formatting. Then I double-click on the `Graphics` and start editing. I select the legend, making sure I don't have parts of the plot selected. Then I drag the legend around and rotate it.

These manipulations leverage the built-in editing tools, so I didn't see any reason to use `Locators` to make the legend movable, as was done with individual labels in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221315/how-do-i-label-different-curves-in-mathematica/7221397#7221397).

The positioning of the legend is *not* restricted to the inside of the plot. To make a legend appear off to the side, you just have to `Show` the plot with a setting for `PlotRegion` that leaves space wherever you need the legend to go.

Here is an example:

```
param = ParametricPlot[{{3 Cos[Pi t], 
     Sin[2 Pi t]}, {1 + Cos[Pi t], 
     Sin[2 Pi t + Pi/3]}}, {t, 0, 2}];

autoLegend[param, {"Curve 1", "Curve 2"}]
```

[image: parametricPlot]

So to move the legend out of the picture, you might do this:

```
autoLegend[
 Show[param, PlotRegion -> {{0, .7}, {0, 1}}], {"Curve 1", "Curve 2"},
  Alignment -> {Right, Center}]
```

[image: parametric inset moved]

The legend placement is relative to the enclosing image dimensions, as you can see - not relative to the plot range of the `ParametricPlot`. The plot region may not be the only thing you want to change, though. `autoLegend` tries to determine the total *aspect ratio* automatically, but we see that there is a bit too much white space at the top now. For that reason, I also added the option `AspectRatio` so we can set a manual value:

```
paramWithLegend = autoLegend[
 Show[param, PlotRegion -> {{0, .7}, {0, 1}}], {"Curve 1", "Curve 2"},
  Alignment -> {Right, Center}, AspectRatio -> .25]
```

This produces the same picture as above but with less white space on top.

If you want to change the relative size of the legend and/or plot, I'd suggest playing around with `ImageSize` and `Magnify`, as in this example:

```
Magnify[Show[paramWithLegend, ImageSize -> 300], 2]
```

For some code in `autoLegend`, I should credit the answer [to the question "ShowLegend values"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6380/245) where I made a similar legend for **color bars** in contour plots.

**If `autoLegend` doesn't cut it,  use `legendMaker`**

Limitations of the automatic style recognition in `autoLegend` may occur if you combine different types of plot with `Show`, as in the following example from the comments:

```
myplots = 
  Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}], 
   ListPlot[
    Table[{x, Sin[x] + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}], 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Joined -> True]];

myStyles = extractStyles[myplots]
```

> `{{Directive[Hue[0.67,0.6,0.6],RGBColor[1,0,0],Thickness[Large]],Directive[Hue[0.67,0.6,0.6]]},{\[FilledCircle]}}`

```
Overlay[{myplots,
  legendMaker[{"Sin(x)-theory", "Sin(x)-data"},
   PlotStyle -> myStyles[[1]],
   PlotMarkers -> Prepend[
     myStyles[[2]], ""]]}, Alignment -> {Right, Top}]
```

[image: overlay]

Here, the problem is that we have two lines with distinct styles, but not the same number of distinct plot markers (just `\[FilledCircle]`). To get one line with and one line without marker, I call `legendMaker` with a two-element list for `PlotMarkers`, one of which is an empty string `""`.

Comment: +1. A quick question: Wouldn't it be possible to get the PlotStyle and PlotMarkers directly from the plot one would like to add the legend to (instead of creating a fake one)?Then one could call addLegend[plot, labels, opt] and everything would work as expected and custom PlotStyle options would only have to be given once to the plot.

Comment: @Ajasja Since you got me to revisit this question, I added something that hopefully does what you want.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Finally a legend simply and aesthetic enough to use daily. Is it some how possible to avoid rasterizing the plot though? On win7 mma 8, `Overlay[]` returns a bitmap...

And using Show and Inset does not work (returns a garbled plot legend)

Comment: @Ajasja That's news to me, that `Overlay` creates bitmaps on Windows. Could you try an experiment with one of the example plots. Let's call the plot `p = autoLabel[...]`, then try `p2 = Magnify[p,2]` and see if that works. Then try `Export["p2.pdf",p2]` and look at `p2.pdf` in Acrobat Reader or some other PDF viewer. Does it appear bitmapped? If it looks pixelated _within_ the Mathematica notebook already, then that could be an issue merely with the display preferences (e.g., are you viewing at 100% or higher magnification? Just a guess...).

Comment: You were spot on! Magnify works nicely and the PDF is not pixelated either. I was not able to click and resize the graph produced by `autoLabel[]` and I thought that increasing the view magnification would not pixelate the image...

Comment: Sadly it seem that `deployLegend[]` does not work on win7. The text in the legend is [messed up](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jXVV9.png). I can resize the entire plot, which is very nice, but I can't select the legend with a single click. If I double click the legend I can't move the whole legend but just the background (or each element of the legend) as shown [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wsP1g.png). Exporting to SVG, EMF or anything else does not help either.

Comment: Using `GraphicsGrid` instead of `Grid` in `legendMaker`  [solves the problem of garbled text](http://i.stack.imgur.com/k8NfD.png).

Comment: Figured out how to select the entire legend... First double click on plot then drag to select the entire legend. Very cool.

Comment: @Ajasja Could you try if your font problem is still there with the most recent `deployLegend` (and the original `legendMaker` as above? I added `"TextMode" -> "Outlines"` in the last line of `deployLegend`, hoping that you won't get garbled fonts this way. Not sure if this works on Windows, though. I suggested this in some other answers to Windows users but never got a response...

Comment: No, still very [similar](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9YNfF.png). But the text itself looks **much** better with Outlines:) Is the any particular reason why `Grid` is preferable to `GraphicsGrid`?

Comment: @Ajasja Thanks for letting me know - so I'll leave `Textmode` in but have to think about the `GraphicsGrid` alternative. I'm seeing that it doesn't scale to fit the labels correctly, but that looks fixable. Have to do that later, though...

Comment: yes, I just discovered that myself:) But replacing `TraditonalForm` with `Text` in `legendMaker` also solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for improvements! I'd give it another +1 if I could...

Comment: @Jens Wonderful work! I only have a small bug, and I can't seem to find the right pattern matching for it: extractStyles[ListPlot[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, Joined -> True]] fails to find the color of the line.

Comment: @Jens ignore me, I forgot the PlotMarkers->None that needed to be added :)

Comment: @Jens your legend functions could be directly integrated to the Plot functions similarly to the way the PlotLegends package does it.

Comment: @FaysalAberkane Yes, that would make sense too. But of course, the more I try to integrate things with system functions, the higher the risk that something will break with the next version...

Comment: @Jens I did below what I suggested in my previous comment, it might interest you.

Comment: Excellent post. The only issue I have is that deployLegend changes the appearance of the plot itself (compare deployLegend to a "standard" plot). But I can live with autoLegend :)

Comment: @Jens Love this! +1 for awesomeness!  One problem though is that after using autoLegend ToolTips no longer work. Is there a work around that would allow ToolTips to still function?  Still a great solution!  Thanks!

Comment: @R Hall Thanks - I don't get points for this anymore since it's a community wiki, but I want to update it soon. I did figure out how to place the legend reliably without the `Overlay` that I'm using here for `autoLegend`. The method that one should use instead is `Inset`, and I've already done that for the color bar legends that I worked on in [this anser](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6380/245) to the question "ShowLegend values" - so all the pieces are there...

Comment: @RHall Could you check if `autoLegend` now works better? I tested a new version and it seems to work perfectly with tool tips after I switched to `Inset` instead of `Overlay` for the legend. If you want to up-vote it, you could do so in the answer I linked at the bottom of this answer, because that's where the idea came from.

Comment: @Jens Much better now Jens!  Tooltips work perfectly!  +1

Comment: I am just starting to play with this in the past 2 weeks. Very nice, and much better than the ad-hoc system I was using via LevelScheme.

Comment: Is there a way to put LegendOrientation to horizontal?

Comment: @de_wright I haven't implemented that option yet because I decided not to try and duplicate the entire functionality of Mathematica's own Legends. But I'll try to post a new version tomorrow if I have the time...

Comment: @Jens Thank you for this great piece of code. However, I copied your sample and on my machine the lines of the legend are shifted downwards. Do you have any idea why this might happen? Here is the [png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27906348/legend-sample.png) (that's how it looks inside Mathematica 8) and the [pdf](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27906348/legend-sample.pdf).

Comment: Playing around with `ImagePadding` helped, at least for lines without markes.

Comment: @mincos and @de_wright Sorry I didn't have time to update this yet, but it looks like some improvements are actually coming in the [next version of Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Legended.html) that may make this post obsolete. Anyway, I'm currently looking into modifying `legendMaker` to keep track of relative sizing of plot markers better. The alignment of markers with lines is always a problem with the textual (`Automatic`) markers because character symbols can't be placed with perfect accuracy.

Comment: Please add a feature for Axeslabel to be shown parallel with axes in your function

Comment: @Jens, is it possible to implement the feature of automatically rescaling the sizes of the legend background and the legend fonts in `autoLegend` when one enlarges the size of the plot by dragging the corner of it? Sometimes the relative scale between the legend and the main plot looks nice, but when I enlarge the plot to see its detailed structure, I find that the legend is not resized accordingly...

Comment: @Leo I've found that if I include `ImageSize` as a parameter of the plot being legended, it is cancelled by `autoLegend` (reverting the size back to the tiny default), at least within `Manipulate`.  I am looking for a solution to this and will post it here if I find one.

Comment: @Leo I suspect it has something to do with the answer below as Jens mentions the option `ImageSize`, but I have yet to figure it out.  I don't need rescaling even, just to allow the original plot to be the size described (within it *or* autoLegend) by `ImageSize`.

Comment: @Ghersic I think what @Leo is asking for can already be done relatively easily by combining `ImageSize` with `Magnify`. E.g., call the last parametric plot with legend that I used in the above answer `lastPlot`, then you can just do this: `Magnify[Show[lastPlot, ImageSize -> 300], 2]`. I.e., what @Leo wants is not really part of what I intended `autoLegend` to do because it can be done externally. Instead of `Magnify`, you can also try `Style[..., Magnification -> 2]`. `autoLegend` has limitations because it's supposed to be really simple to use. For more features, use `legendMaker` directly.

Comment: @LeoFang If you think my previous comment to @Ghersic helps answer your request, I could add that to my answer above. Otherwise, maybe you can give me another example to play with. When you rescale an image by dragging as you describe, the font size *never* changes. So what you're asking isn't really consistent with the normal behavior of `Graphics`, which is why I don't plan on implementing it directly in `autoLegend`.

Comment: @Jens thanks for your comment! My very first need was the same as Ghersic's, namely output a plot with legend in a desired size. However as @Ghersic has pointed out, `autoLegend` seems unable to satisfy our needs. Therefore, I turned to tune the plot size manually and left the "rescaling by dragging" comment above. So, yes, your comment above answered my question (btw, I think after `Magnify` it is much better for external document usage than before!), and it would be good to see you add it to your post for future reference. :)

Comment: @Jens One more question irrelevant to my first one. When I saw this [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28138/legends-in-combined-plot-and-listplot/28141), I thought either `autoLegend` or `legendMaker` could solve it, but I found that colors in the legend do not agree with colors in the plot. To clarify my unsuccessful attempt see this [sample file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lkdyza4sf6pr6c1/unsuccessful%20attempt%20of%20combining%20data%20points%20and%20curves.nb). Do you think there is a workaround?

Comment: Ah, I see @Jens. Thank you, your `autoLegend` function works well with 6 sliders manipulating constants within (coincidentally) 6 equations in `NDSolve` whose variables are being plotted.  This works very well and the *only* hitch comes down to wanting to maintain position coordinates relative to the extent of magnification (manipulating sliders resets the dragable location to the default specified in the definition of autoLegend), but hell... I'll do that by hand!  Thanks a million, @Jens ... A legend to all and to all a good night.  ;p

Comment: @Jens thanks for the great effort of keeping the post updated! As a MMA8 user I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: Hello Jens, recently I shifted to MMA9 because I found that in MMA8 the following MWE gives inconsistent legend font size after exporting to an eps file: `cm = 72/2.54; autoLegend[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "sin(x)"}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 9}], {"Just a test"}, 
 Background -> Directive[LightOrange, Opacity[.5]], 
 Alignment -> {0.6, 0.5}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 9}]; Export["test.eps", Show[%, ImageSize -> 9 cm]]`. Note that I use `BaseStyle` twice: one for the font size of ticks and axis labels, and another for the legend. In MMA9 it works fine but not in MMA8.

Comment: It's not an urgent bug report, just wanna let you know :)

Answer (score 21):

A small enhancement to Jens's excellent response is to generalise the options handling by defining the options for `legendMaker` to include all those applicable to `Framed`.

```
Options[legendMaker]=Options@Framed;
legendMaker[lineDirectives_, markerSymbols_, textLabels_, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{f, g}, 
  f = Grid[MapThread[{Graphics[{#1, Line[{{-.1, 0}, {.1, 0}}], 
         Inset[#2, {0, 0}, Background -> None]}, AspectRatio -> .2, 
        ImageSize -> 35], TraditionalForm[#3]} &, {lineDirectives, 
      markerSymbols, textLabels}], Alignment -> Left];
  g = Framed[f,opts]
 ]
```

Then add the extra formatting options:

```
opts = Sequence[Background -> LightGray, RoundingRadius -> 10, 
FrameStyle -> None, ImageMargins -> 10];
```

For the more cautious:

```
g = Framed[f,opts]
```

can be replaced with

```
g = Framed[f,FilterRules[{opts},Options@Framed]]
```

to discard any options not applicable to `Framed`.

A similar approach could be applied to `Grid` by the inclusion of a second options packet `opts2` in the definiton of `legendMaker`'s parameters.

Comment: One reason why I hard-coded the default options in my version is that I wanted different defaults from `Frame`, and also to disallow options that can interfere with the label. E.g., if you accidentally add `ImageSize->40` to the options it will distort the overlay. So I basically implemented a "white list" of options. Your approach is perfectly fine if one instead implements a "black list" of options using `Except` in `FilterRules`. It would just take a little more experimenting to see which other options to disallow.

Comment: Hi Jens, as ever, yes lots of ways to get where you want to go. Defining the options with Options[legendMaker]={ ... }, lets you set your own defaults if you want. Either by only defining the selecting things from Framed that you want to use, or just taking the options from Framed and then replacing the default values that you don't like.

Comment: You're right, I think that's better. I changed my answer but added a lot more option handling to keep my favorite defaults and also absorb the handling of default colors and markers in options.

Comment: @Jens, Very nice enhancements.

Answer (score 15):

Perhaps this example will help you?

```
data = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {2, 3}};
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
ListLinePlot[Table[{#1, Log[b, #2]} & @@@ data, {b, 3, 10, 2}], 
 PlotLegend -> {"A", "B", "C", "D"}, LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.4}]
```

[image]

Addressing your comment, to only specify the iterator once:

```
data = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {2, 3}};
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
iter = {3, 10, 2};
ListLinePlot[
 Table[{#1, Log[b, #2]} & @@@ data, Evaluate[{b, Sequence @@ iter}]], 
 PlotLegend -> 
  Map[ToString, Table[Log[b], Evaluate[{b, Sequence @@ iter}]]], 
 LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.4}]
```

[image]

Comment: I would like the legend to say that `[Line of Color A]  = $Log_{a} x $` and the next `[Line of Color B]  = $Log_{b} x $` etc. where $a,b,c ...$ is specified by that Table iteration

Comment: How about `PlotLegend -> Map[ToString, Table[Log[b], {b, 3, 10, 2}]]`

Comment: thank you, I believe that should work!

Comment: Anyway to increase the size of the Legend font using this?

Comment: To change font size use `PlotLegend -> 
 Map[Style[ToString[#], 14] &, 
  Table[Log[b], Evaluate[{b, Sequence @@ iter}]]]`.  You may want to use `LegendSize` too.

Answer (score 9):

I've tried to integrate the functions of Jens to the plot functions similarly to what is done in the PlotLegends package (I've adapted code found in it, if it poses a problem then I'll delete my post), here's what I've just come up with, it seems to work. The autoLegend function needs to be modified slightly.

For setting up default legend options legendMaker options must be modified.

deployLegend instead of autoLegend could be used instead in the definitions below. The functions could also be changed to allow this choice as an option.

Here's an example borrowed from the answer of Jens.

```
ListPlot[Evaluate[Table[RandomInteger[3 i, 10] + 2 i, {i, 3}]], 
PlotMarkers -> {{Graphics@{Red, Disk[]}, .05}, {Graphics@{Blue, Rectangle[]}, .05}}, 
Joined -> True,
PlotLegend -> {"Small", "Big", "Bigger"}, Alignment -> {Right, Top}]
```

It also works for the example using Show of this question [Legend of a plot: how to increase the size of the line/marker?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4474/66) using this syntax

```
Show[p,q,PlotLabel->Style["Comparison","Subsection"],
PlotLegend->textLabels,PlotStyle->manualPlotstyles,PlotMarkers->manualMarkers,
Background->Directive[Opacity[.5],Black],"LegendLineAspectRatio"->.3,
"LegendGridOptions"->{Alignment->Left,Spacings->{.7,.1},Background->{{GrayLevel[.8],None},None}},Alignment->{-.8,-.7}]
```

Here's the code

```
autoLegend[plot_Graphics, labels_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
Module[{lines, markers},
    {lines, markers} = extractStyles[plot];
    Overlay[
        {
            plot
            , 
            legendMaker[labels, opts, PlotStyle -> lines, PlotMarkers -> markers]
        }
        , 
        Alignment -> (Alignment /. {opts} /. Alignment -> {Right, Top})
    ]
];

LegendOptionNames = Map[First, Options[legendMaker]];
PlotLegendOptionNames = Union[{PlotLegend}, LegendOptionNames];

UpdateSyntax[fun_]:=
If[FreeQ[SyntaxInformation[fun], "OptionNames"],
    SyntaxInformation[fun] =
        Join[
            SyntaxInformation[fun]
            ,
            {"OptionNames" -> Map[ToString, Union[Map[First, Options[fun]], PlotLegendOptionNames]]}
        ]
    ,
    SyntaxInformation[fun] =
        Join[
            DeleteCases[SyntaxInformation[fun], "OptionNames"->_]
            ,
            {"OptionNames" -> Prepend[Map[ToString, Union[{CoordinatesToolOptions}, PlotLegendOptionNames]],Automatic]}
        ]
];

plotnames = {Show, Plot, LogPlot, LogLinearPlot, LogLogPlot, PolarPlot, ParametricPlot,
         ListPlot, ListLinePlot, ListLogPlot, ListLogLinearPlot, ListLogLogPlot, DateListPlot, DateListLogPlot, ListPolarPlot};

Unprotect[Evaluate[plotnames]];
Map[
(* Only insert a rule once if the package is loaded multiple times *)
If[FreeQ[DownValues[#], PlotLegend],
    DownValues[#] =
        Prepend[
            DownValues[#, Sort->False]
            ,
            HoldPattern[
                #[a : PatternSequence[___, Except[_?BoxForm`HeldOptionQ]] | PatternSequence[], opts__?BoxForm`HeldOptionQ]
                /; 
                !FreeQ[Flatten[{opts}], PlotLegend]
            ] 
            :>
            With[{plotOptions=Sequence@@FilterRules[{opts},Options[#]]},
                autoLegend[#[a,plotOptions], PlotLegend /. Flatten[{opts}],opts] 
            ]
        ]
]&
,
plotnames
];

Map[UpdateSyntax, plotnames];
Protect[Evaluate[plotnames]];
```

Comment: I wonder if this could cause problems if someone is _also_ using the regular `PlotLegends`... Have to play around with this a little more - in general, it could certainly improve the usability. I'll also edit my post simply to add some comments to the code so that it will be easier to extend later (when time permits or necessity dictates...)

Comment: It seems that the syntax information for `Show` is now no longer recognizing any of the `Graphics3D` options! E.g., try `Show[Graphics3D[Sphere[]], Boxed -> False]`. I am getting red syntax coloring for `Boxed` even though it still renders correctly.

Comment: Yes more care should be taken to define the Show syntax information.

Answer (score 7):

I do not like legends. I'd rather place labels next to curves using the `Text[ ]` primitive, perhaps inside an `Epilog->{ }`. Here is an example:

[image]

The code that produces the graph is, first, the definition of a function that places the text in a font of my choice, here Times:

```
txt[a_, b_, c_: {0, 0}, d_: {1, 0}, e_: ftsz] := 
 Text[Style[a, FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> e], b, c, d]
```

Then, I define the curves:

```
eq1 = (c + c^(1/2))/2 - 1 + 1/c(*the equation stored in eq1*)
d1eq1 = D[eq1, c](*first derivative stored in d1eq1*)
d2eq1 = D[eq1, {c, 2}](*second derivative stored in d2eq1*)
```

Finally, I use `Plot` to produce the curves and I place the text using `Prolog`:

```
fntandsz = {FontFamily -> "Roman", FontSize -> .7 ftsz};
dp1 = Plot[{eq1, d1eq1, d2eq1}, {c, 0, 3},
  AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  PlotRange -> {-1, 2},
  PlotStyle -> {Black,
    {Black, Dashing[{.03, .01}]},
    {Black, Dashing[{.03, .01, .002, .01}]}},
  ImageSize -> 4.5 imgsz,
  BaseStyle -> fntandsz,
  Prolog -> {
    txt[TraditionalForm@f[c], {2.3, 1.5}],
    txt[TraditionalForm@f'[c], {2.6, .65}],
    txt[TraditionalForm@f''[c], {1.3, 1.9}]
    }]
```

You must also have defined font size (`ftsz`) and image size (`imgsz`), for which I use 12 and 57 for the screen (and larger values for publishing).