# Labeling individual curves in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, legending

I need to create a plot for export and inclusion in a report. Is there a better way to label curves than `PlotLegends`? From what I've read and my personal experience, `PlotLegends` is pretty bad.

Is there a better package for legends, or, ideally, a simple way to place small text next to each curve?

Comment: aaaah... finally someone who acknowledges that ``PlotLegends` `` is horrible in the question without being stubborn about wanting to kludge through with it! Welcome, please go through [Jens' awesome answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/5) for what you want. If you want to place the label on each curve separately, then I suggest you look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221315/how-do-i-label-different-curves-in-mathematica/7221397#7221397) by Simon

Comment: Inset[] seems to be the more flexible method to annotate graphics, but positioning is manual - there is no intelligent layout, and syntax is slightly more cumbersome than positioning general Graphics elements

Comment: If `PlotLegends` is the answer you're asking the wrong question :) I second R.Ms recommendation re: code from Jens and Simon. It is always preferable to roll your own legends IMO.

Comment: @R.M `PlotLegends` is aweful. Once I accepted that and created my own system, I've been better off.

Comment: Take a look at this (mine) answer http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14149/193

Comment: sniffle... plotlegends is making me move to python......

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can make use of the following options in `Plot`, e.g. :

```
Plot[ Tooltip @ {x^2, x^3, x^4}, {x, -2, 2}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, 
      PlotRangePadding -> 1.1] /. {Tooltip[{_, color_, line_}, tip_] :>   
                                   {Text[Style[tip, 14], {.1, 0} + line[[1, -1]]], color, line}}
```

[image]

**Update (05.02.2016)**

Tried the above code in Mathematica 10.3.1 and it did not work. This code works:

```
Plot[Tooltip@{x^2, x^3, x^4}, {x, -2, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 
   1.1] /. {Tooltip[{___, dir_Directive, line_Line, ___}, 
    tip_] :> {Text[Style[tip, 14], {.1, 0} + line[[1, -1]]], dir, 
    line}}
```

**Edit**

Since there was another question in the comments I add another way of labeling curves. 
If we have to plot a graph of a family of certain functions, and insert its definition i.e.

[image]

we can make use of `Drawing Tools` in the Front End (a shortcut `Ctrl-D`)  to insert some text supplemented by appropriate arrows pointing only  a few of all functions.
We paste a simple text i.e. output of `Text[Style["n = 13", Large, Bold, Blue]]` or the definition of the functions, by double-clicking the right button of the mouse, next once the left one and selecting from menu `Paste into Graphic` to insert a data from the clipboard. Similarly we choose arrows from the section `Tools` of `Drawing Tools` and adjust them by dragging apprporiately.  Alternatively to pasting the definition of functions with `Drawing Tools`, we can make use of also `PlotLabel` option of `Plot` to insert it, i.e. `PlotLabel -> Subscript[f, n][x] == (1 - x^2/6 + x^4/120)^n`

```
Plot[ Evaluate[(1 - x^2/6 + x^4/120)^n /. n -> Range[1, 30, 3]], {x, 0, Sqrt[6] },
      AspectRatio -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> Thick ]
```

[image]

Comment: That's really nice. I do similar labeling with DateListPlot[] by using Epilog; I have created a function that checks the last datapoint in each series and generates the label automatically. The effect is similar but the code is not as compact as yours.

Comment: However in order to produce what you'd like you have to play around a bit with options, sometimes with `PlotRange`, `PlotRangePadding` and so on.

Comment: This is really brilliant. One question: is there a way to label the curve with something besides the evaluated function? For example, I have a function called A[x]. I'd like the label to be "A[x]" instead of "300/x + 25".

Comment: @xiongtx Thank you. I'm glad I could help. One can add `A[x]` label as well, but I updated my answer in another way, namely making use of `Drawing Tools` (`Ctrl+D`). I think it is a good alternative of labeling curves appropriately.

Comment: @Artes Wow, how did you find the options of `Tooltip`? I mean the `{_, color_, line_}, tip_` in the code, it seems not to be mentioned in the document.

Comment: @xzczd Look more carefully at the documentation of `Tooltip` e.g. at Scope, Options, etc. There are some other nice examples which you could use in more general ways. I think that will be useful.

Comment: Really nice solution! I updated the answer with code that works in Mathematica 10.3.1.

Comment: Your first two answers also work well with MMA11.0 but not anymore with MMA 11,2 (for example I get {x2,x3,x4} when the cursor is hovering above any of the curves of the first solution. I comment only now because the question to which you replied has been listed among the greatest hits from previous weeks in the MMA weekly newsletter.

Comment: @SigisK It would be all right if you add another answer discussing your case.

Answer (score 21):

Here is an interactive version, with definition below.

A functional plot,

```
functionplot=Plot[{Sin[x],Cos[x]},{x,0,2\[Pi]},
      Frame->{True,True,False,False},
      FrameLabel->{"x","y(x)"},
      FrameStyle->Directive[13,Italic],
      PlotStyle->Thick,
      PlotRangeClipping->False,
      PlotRange->{-1.2,1.2},
      AxesStyle->Dashed];
```

To label this plot with specified labels for each curve (`Sin`, `Cos`), run the following to get automatically updating labels based on mouse pointer proximity to each curve; click with the mouse to stick labels wherever you wish:

```
dynamicLabeled[functionplot,{{Sin,"Sine"},{Cos,"Cosine"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(The above image does not do justice to the Dynamic interactivity.)

It works with `ListPlot` too:

```
data1=Table[{x,.5Exp[-1/2 ((x-5)/1)^2]+RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0,.05]]},{x,0,10,.25}];
data2=Table[{x,-Sin[x]+RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0,.08]]},{x,2,8,.1}];
dataplot=ListPlot[{data1,data2},
       PlotStyle->{Thick,PointSize[0.015]},
       PlotRange->{-1.2,1.45},
       Joined->{True,False}];

dynamicLabeled[dataplot,{{data1,"Exponential"},{data2,"Sinusoidal"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The current state of the plot for the dynamicPlot most recently clicked can be stored in a global variable for later processing or export. In the code below this is set to `currentPlot`.

Some parts are hard-coded (arrow styling and label styling)---you can tune those to suit, or extend the flexibility. It does not handle mixed functional-data plots, but that is easy to circumvent by turning the data into an `InterpolatingFunction`, or displaying the function as a `Table` of points. Have fun.

Here is the definition of `dynamicLabeled`:

```
Clear[dynamicLabeled];
dynamicLabeled[plot_,labelling_] := DynamicModule[
  {p,x,x1,x2,storedlabels={},currentlabel,aspect,distances,xs,rs,res,ind,ps,ps1,curves,labels,pt},
  curves=labelling[[All,1]];
  labels=labelling[[All,2]];
  aspect=Options[plot,AspectRatio][[1,2]];
  Dynamic[
    p=MousePosition["Graphics"];
    If[p=!=None,
      pt={p[[1]],p[[2]]/aspect};
      Switch[curves,
        _?(VectorQ[#,AtomQ]&),
          (* list of functions *)
          rs=Quiet@FindMinimum[Norm[pt-{x,#[x]/aspect}],{x,p[[1]]}]&/@curves;
          res={#[[1]],#[[2,1,2]]}&/@rs;
          distances=res[[All,1]];
          xs=res[[All,2]];
          ps=Quiet@MapThread[{#1,#2[#1]}&,{xs,curves}];,
        _,
          (* functions is a list of data *)
          ps1=Flatten[Nearest[#,pt,1]]&/@(curves/.{x_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ}:>{x,y/aspect});
          distances=Norm[#-pt]&/@ps1;
          ps=ps1/.{x_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ}:>{x,y*aspect};          
      ];
      ind=Flatten[Position[distances,Min[distances]]][[1]];
    ];
    MouseAppearance[
      EventHandler[
        currentPlot = Show[plot,
          Epilog->{
            storedlabels,
            If[p=!=None,
              currentlabel={
                Text[Style[labels[[ind]],13],p,{0,Sign[ps[[ind]][[2]]-p[[2]]]}],
                Arrow[{p,ps[[ind]]}]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        {{"MouseClicked",1}:>(AppendTo[storedlabels,currentlabel])}
      ],
      Graphics[{PointSize[0],Point[{0,0}]}]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: This is very nice, but I have failed to understand how to "freeze" the result, e.g. to export it to a pdf file. Is that an option?

Comment: @chris Try this: `plot=dynamicLabeled[...]`, (add some arrows), `Export["some-path.pdf", plot]`

Comment: When I do this I don't have a plot with arrows. Am I missing something? Also, if I try Show[plot] it tells me "Show::gtype: "DynamicModule is not a type of graphics."

Comment: @chris Try clicking the plot to select it, then copy that into the export expression, or save selection as from the menu.

Comment: Thanks that works; I would nonethless think it would be useful to be able to freeze the edited graph within mathematica because labeling might not be the last operation on the plot. Great functionality in any case.

Comment: @crhis See update: you can assign the plot to a global variable to get access from outside the `DynamicModule`.

Answer (score 14):

Mathematica 11 comes with "[New Labeling System](http://www.wolfram.com/language/11/visualization--labels-scales-exclusions/new-labeling-system.html?product=language)", make such things much easier!

As an illustration, the first example in Artes's answer can be as simple as

```
Plot[{x^2, x^3, x^4}, {x, -2, 2}, PlotLabels -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Much more to be discovered such as `Callout` on [Visualization: Labels, Scales, Exclusions](http://www.wolfram.com/language/11/visualization--labels-scales-exclusions/index.html?product=language)

Comment: `PlotLabels` was a 10.4 addition, but refined/expanded in v11.

Comment: @rcollyer My god, I used 10.4 for several months, never knew it. Anyway, `Callout` is totally new : )

Comment: Yes, yes it is.

Answer (score 12):

I use a homebrew solution, called as follows:

```
Show[Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}], 
 tCustomLegend[{tCustomLegendItem[Line, x, PlotStyle -> Red], 
   tCustomLegendItem[Line, x^2, PlotStyle -> Blue]}, {0.2, 0.8}]]
```

Giving

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The full code is:

```
tYellow=RGBColor[1,0.8,0.2];

tColorList=ColorData[3,"ColorList"];
tColorList[[3]]=tYellow;
tColorList[[4]]=RGBColor[0,0.6,0];
tColorList = tColorList[[{6,2,4,7,5,10,8,9,3,1}]];

tCustomLegendItem::usage="tCustomLegendItem[type,text,options]";
tCustomLegend::usage="tCustomLegend[list,loc,options]";

Begin["`Private`"];
Unprotect[tCustomLegendItem];
Clear[tCustomLegendItem];

Options[tCustomLegendItem]={
    Rule[PlotStyle,{tColorList[[1]]}],
    Rule[LegendLabelStyle,{FontSize->20}]
};

SyntaxInformation[tCustomLegendItem]={"ArgumentsPattern"->{_,_,OptionsPattern[]}};

tCustomLegendItem[type_,text_,options:OptionsPattern[]]:=Module[{object,styles,gfxOpts}, 

    Switch[type,
        Line,
            object=Line[{{0,0},{4,0}}];
            gfxOpts={ImageSize->40,AspectRatio->1/4},
        Point,
            object=Disk[];
            gfxOpts={ImageSize->{40,10}},
        Square,
            object=Rectangle[{0,0}];
            gfxOpts={ImageSize->{40,10}},
        FullSquare,
            object=Rectangle[{0,0}];
            gfxOpts={ImageSize->30}
    ];

    If[Head[OptionValue[PlotStyle]]===List,
        styles=Sequence@@OptionValue[PlotStyle],
        styles=OptionValue[PlotStyle]
    ];

    {   
        Graphics[{styles,object},gfxOpts],
        Graphics[{Text[Style[text,OptionValue[LegendLabelStyle]]]},ImageSize->{Automatic,{30}}]
    }
]

Protect[tCustomLegendItem];

Unprotect[tCustomLegend];
Clear[tCustomLegend];

Options[tCustomLegend]=Join[
    Options[GraphicsGrid],
    Options[tCustomLegendItem]
];

SyntaxInformation[tCustomLegend]={"ArgumentsPattern"->{_,{_,_},OptionsPattern[]}};

tCustomLegend[list_,loc_,options:OptionsPattern[]]:=( 
    Graphics@Inset[
        GraphicsGrid[list,
            Sequence@@Evaluate@FilterRules[{options},{Options[GraphicsGrid]}],
            Alignment->{{{Center,Left}}},
            Spacings->{10,0},
            PlotRangePadding->5
        ], (* End of GraphicsGrid *)
        loc
    ] (* End of Graphics@Inset *)
)

Protect[tCustomLegend];

End[];
```

Answer (score 10):

The [SciDraw package](http://scidraw.nd.edu/) (LevelScheme successor) has support for labelling curves.  Here's an example:

```
Needs["SciDraw`"]

Figure[
 FigurePanel[
  {
   FigLine[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}], 
    LineColor -> Apricot,
    CenterLabel -> "sine", CenterLabelPosition -> 0.55, 
    TextOffset -> Top];

   FigLine[Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}],
    LineColor -> OliveDrab,
    CenterLabel -> "cosine", CenterLabelPosition -> 0.6, 
    TextOffset -> Bottom
    ];
  },
  XPlotRange -> {0, 10}, YPlotRange -> 1.2 {-1, 1},
  Style -> {FigLine -> {LineThickness -> 2}}
 ]
]
```

[image]

It also has support for positioning styled labels with anchor points.

Comment: Wow SciDraw is incredible. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @Gabriel The thanks should go to Mark Caprio, the author of SciDraw.  I'm sure he'll appreciate the feedback! :-)

Comment: Already sent! I love this package so much ... it is such a great framework.

Comment: It requires that you use its versions of plotting functions in order to be able to use the new options right?

Answer (score 9):

Here's another solution providing interactive labeling functionality similar to JxB's answer. That is, you can hover over the curves to see their label as a `Tooltip`, but then click at any point on the curve to make the label stick permanently to that position:

```
Options[burnTooltips] = {ImageSize -> 360, 
   "LabelFunction" -> (Framed[#, FrameStyle -> None, 
       RoundingRadius -> 8, Background -> RGBColor[1, .8, .4]] &)};

burnTooltips[plot_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 DynamicModule[{ins = {}, wrapper = OptionValue["LabelFunction"], 
   toolRule = 
    Function[{arg}, 
     Tooltip[t__] :> 
      Button[Tooltip[t], 
       AppendTo[arg, 
        Inset[wrapper[Last[{t}]], MousePosition["Graphics"]]]], 
     HoldAll]}, 
  EventHandler[
   Dynamic@Show[plot /. toolRule[ins], Graphics@ins, 
     ImageSize -> OptionValue[ImageSize]], {"MouseUp", 
     2} :> (toolRule = {} &)]]

p = Plot[Evaluate[Table[Tooltip[4 x/l + 2, l], {l, 10, 40, 10}]], {x, 
    0, 100}, ImageSize -> 500, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["y vs x"]];

burnTooltips[p]
```

[image: tooltip]

The picture shows a plot `p` in which `Tooltip` was used to provide labels when you hover over the lines (see the `10` with the yellow background, the mouse there too but isn't captured in the screen shot). The orange labels on the lower curves have been created by simply clicking at those spots.

The labels can be styled with the option `"LabelFunction"` as shown near the top of the code. it's a function accepting the `Tooltip` content as its argument, and outputting (by default) a `Framed` object. To make them partly transparent, e.g., one could give this option:

```
"LabelFunction" -> (Framed[#, FrameStyle -> None, RoundingRadius -> 0,
 Background -> RGBColor[1, .8, .4, .5]] &)
```

Answer (score 7):

I'll admit, I cheated. I use an energy level scheme, via [`` LevelScheme` ``](http://wnsl.physics.yale.edu/levelscheme/), to create a my legends. It is entirely manual, but they're not bad.

Here's one such legend

[image]

which was produced with this code snippet

```
Figure[{

   (* the rest of the figures code went here *)

   ScaledFigurePanel[
    {{0.03, 0.55}, {0.37, 0.77}},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}},
    FrameTicks -> None,
    Frame -> False
   ],

   (* The legend is set up as a bunch of levels *)
   SetOptions[ Lev, Thickness -> 1],
   SetOptions[ LevelLabel, FontSize -> 0.9*tickFraction*defFontSize, 
     Gap -> 4],

   Lev[ es, 0, 2, 8], LevelLabel[es, Right, "Excited State"],
   SchemeSquare[{1, 8}, Point[5], FillColor -> Darker[Blue], 
     Color -> Darker[Blue], Layer -> 3],

   Lev[ gs, 0, 2, 5], LevelLabel[gs, Right, "Ground State"],
   SchemeCircle[{1, 5}, Point[5], FillColor -> Darker[Red], 
     Color -> Darker[Red], Layer -> 3 ],

   Lev[ pc, 0, 2, 2], LevelLabel[pc, Right, "Partially Converged"],
   SchemeCircle[{0.5, 2}, Point[5], ShowFill -> False, 
     Color -> Darker[Red], Layer -> 3],
   SchemeSquare[{1.5, 2}, Point[5],  ShowFill -> False, 
     Color -> Darker[Blue], Layer -> 3]
 },
 PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1.01}, {-0.1, 1.01}},
 ImageSize -> {840, 680}
]
```

First of all, a `LevelScheme` graphic operates just like a normal graphic in that it is comprised of a stateful list, i.e. a primitive is only affected by the nearest preceding directive. For instance,

```
Graphics[{Red, Circle[], Blue, Rectangle[]}]
```

produces a red circle overlain by a blue rectangle. So, in the above legend, the level scheme will be placed on a `ScaledFigurePanel` which overlays the other plots within the `Figure` (not shown).  From there I set styling options on both the "energy level" `Lev` and its label. Each level is then constructed via

```
Lev[ aName, x1, x2, y ]
```

and `LevelLabel` finds it using `aName`. From there, it is just working on the placement of the plot symbols until they look right.

Comment: +1 "partially converged" reminds me ["almost but not quite entirely unlike tea"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Not_entirely_unlike)

Comment: @belisarius In this case, "partially converged" refers to the results of a number of iterations of a non-linear fixed point solver that almost, but not quite, converges within the tolerances you've chosen. If your curious: http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevB.78.075114

Comment: Almost but not quite confusing

Comment: @belisarius if you found it not quite confusing, then you may be ahead of me. I followed only the major points in it, and am ever grateful I don't have to implement it.

Comment: I am sure I am ahead of you ... in age

Comment: @belisarius that is entirely likely, and at least you beat me at one thing. :)

Answer (score 4):

The Mathematica 9 PlotLegends -> Placed is nicer than the old PlotLegends package.  Here's an example:

```
Plot[{BesselK[2, z], BesselK[2, 1/z]}, {z, 0.3, 3},
 AxesLabel -> {z},

 PlotLegends ->
  Placed[{TraditionalForm[BesselK[2, z]],
    TraditionalForm[BesselK[2, 1/z]]}, {Right, Bottom}]
 ]
```

Under Placed, the option that are available are: {Below,Above,Before,After, Right,Left,Center}

[image: PlotLegends Places sample]

Comment: Mathematica 9 is nicer, but legends of this type violate the proximity-compatibility principle, making it harder for the viewer to determine which label goes with which line. It is best, when possible, to put the labels at the end of each line as shown in one of the solutions above. This also increases the data-ink ratio, because it eliminates the (now) redundant lines and symbols that are present when you use PlotLegends.

Comment: I agree.  These sorts of legends are also pretty much useless if the image is printed in black and white.

Answer (score 1):

Try the new wrapper function Callout; it worked amazingly well for me with DateListPlot to make an online, continuously updating strip chart.  The legends actually moved with the data as the chart data was changed.