# Legend of a plot: how to increase the size of the line/marker?

Tags: plotting, legending

I'm using the following kind of code to do the legends of my plots:

```
PlotLegend -> {"Test1","Test2"}, LegendPosition -> {0.05, 
0.2}, LegendBackground -> White, LegendBorder -> White, \
ShadowBackground -> White, LegendSize -> {0.75 , 
0.35}, LegendBorder -> None, LegendTextSpace -> 3
```

Which gives something like

[image: Example of legend for a plot]

I would like to increase the size (width) of the line (color/type) of one item of the legend.

I know it depends on the size of the whole box, but is it possible to control that independently ?

**EDIT**

The "package" of *Jens* looks like the perfect solution for me. I used it to produce the following plot. In this case I use only one legend entry for both the data and the corresponding fit, but as he mentions in his answer they can be split.

[image]

Comment: I strongly recommend dumping `PlotLegends` for something more thorough, such as a homebrew solution. See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/creating-legends-for-plots-with-multiple-lines and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4444/labeling-individual-curves-in-mathematica/4448#4448 to name a few

Comment: @tkott, I've just [updated my post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/creating-legends-for-plots-with-multiple-lines/4028#4028) to address this type of question. I had worked on it last night and planned to do some more, but decided to update what I have now. I'll try to post an example as an answer here to show how the sizes can be changed. Although these two questions are closely related, the size issue wasn't in the earlier question linked here. I just happened to address it in the other post...

Comment: @all: Indeed I should dump PlotLegends and go for another solution. Jens' one seems to do exactly what I want !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're willing to abandon `PlotLegends` (which tkott advises in the comment and  many others would advise too), then you could work with the code posted in [this related answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/creating-legends-for-plots-with-multiple-lines/4028#4028) to achieve some customization. You'll have to execute the definitions in that post before trying the lines below.

Take the following two plots which generate the same curve first as a line and then as points from a table, using plot markers:

```
p = Plot[Evaluate[Table[1/x + i, {i, 0, 3, 1}]], {x, 0, 3}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 3}];
q = ListPlot[
   Table[Evaluate@Table[{x, 1/x + i}, {x, .5, 3, .5}], {i, 0, 3, 1}], 
   PlotRange -> {0, 3}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic];
```

Now simply say

```
autoLegend[Show[p, q], {"Asymptote 1", "Asymptote 2", "Asymptote 3"}]
```

and the result is this:

[image: Labeling two plots]

You could replace `autoLegend` by `deployLegend` above if you want to be able to edit the result as a graphic. To customize the sizes inside the legend, I'll add some options:

```
autoLegend[Show[p, q], {"Asymptote 1", "Asymptote 2", "Asymptote 3"},
 "LegendLineWidth" -> 20,
 "LegendLineAspectRatio" -> .5,
 "LegendGridOptions" -> {Alignment -> Left, Spacings -> {1, 1}}]
```

[image: Adjusted legend]

The `"LegendGridOptions"` setting takes the same options as `Grid` and determines the horizontal and vertical space between entries in the legend. The `"LegendLineWidth"` and `"LegendLineAspectRatio"` have to be changed in tandem to get the markers and lines to fill the space properly.

**Edit**

If the two plots `p` and `q` represent independent data (such as experimental  data versus theory curves), then the legend should have six instead of three entries. This is something `autoLegend` isn't able to figure out, so we have to do it using the lower-level function `legendMaker`. It needs to be given the styles for the lines and markers explicitly, as lists of six entries each. To specify that there should be *no* line or no marker, use the entry `None`.

The following example first defines the text for the legend, and the styles that appear in the two plots:

```
textLabels = 
  Map[Style[#, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
     GrayLevel[.9]] &, {"Asymptote 1", "Asymptote 2", "Asymptote 3", 
    "Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3"}];

plotstyles = Map[ColorData[1][#] &, Range[3]];

manualPlotstyles = Join[plotstyles, {None, None, None}];

markers = {Style["\[FilledCircle]", Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], 
    FontSize -> 8.96], 
   Style["\[FilledSquare]", Hue[0.9060679774997897, 0.6, 0.6], 
    FontSize -> 8.96], 
   Style["\[FilledDiamond]", Hue[0.1421359549995791, 0.6, 0.6], 
    FontSize -> 10.88]};

manualMarkers = Join[{None, None, None}, markers];
```

In the variables `manualPlotstyles` and `manualMarkers`, I added `None` in the list positions where either the line or the marker should be omitted. The result is overlayed with the combined plots (produced by `Show`):

```
Overlay[{
  Show[p, q, PlotLabel -> Style["Comparison", "Subsection"]],
  legendMaker[
   textLabels,
   PlotStyle -> manualPlotstyles,
   PlotMarkers -> manualMarkers,
   Background -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Black],
   "LegendLineAspectRatio" -> .3,
   "LegendGridOptions" -> {Alignment -> Left, Spacings -> {.7, .1},
     Background -> {{GrayLevel[.8], None}, None}
     }
   ]},
 Alignment -> {-.8, -.7}]
```

[image: Example for legendMaker customization]

This shows how some of the optional parameters can be used to get a different legend appearance.

Answer (score 6):

This may not be a right answer since the question was asked before `Mathematica` introduced the `PlotLegends` option. Using this facility, what OP asked was achieved relatively easier than the traditional methods in my opinion.

This goal can be done by simply using the option `LegendMarkerSize`. However, I found it not so evident and thus I think this post might be worth for others(and future me) seeking for a possible solution to this problem in higher versions.

The overly messy options were intentionally added to address many other possible issues.

```
marker = {Graphics[ {EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue, Opacity[1]}], 
 FaceForm[{Transparent}], Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 13]
 , Graphics[ {EdgeForm[{Thick, Black, Opacity[1]}], 
   FaceForm[{Transparent}], Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 12]
 , Graphics[]
 }; 

plotStyle = {Directive[Red, Dashing[0.01]]
  , Transparent
  , Directive[Brown, Thickness[0.01]]};

legend = LineLegend[ plotStyle  , Range[3] 
  , LegendMarkers -> marker
  , LegendMarkerSize -> {{50, 13}, {30, 12}, {30, 13}}
  , Spacings -> {3, 1}
 ]

data = Table[  {x, x^#} & /@ {0.9, 1, 1.1}, {x, 1, 10, 1}] // 
 Transpose;

ListLinePlot[data
 , PlotMarkers -> marker
 , PlotStyle -> plotStyle
 , Frame -> True
 , PlotLegends -> Placed[ legend, Scaled[{0.2, 0.7}]]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you aren't keen to write your own custom function for legends, there is always the `ShowLegend` version of the legends functionality in the `PlotLegends` package. It is just as slow as the `PlotLegend` option, but seems to offer a bit more control over the markers. It can also be used with the full array of plotting functions, not just the `Plot`, `ListPlot` and related functions.

In your specific case, you can get control over the length of the key lines by setting their coordinates appropriately, for example `Line[{{0, 0.5}, {1.4, 0.5}}]`. It took a bit of trial and error to get those numbers, but there might be a general principle behind them, relating the higher *x*-coordinate to the `LegendSize` and `LegendTextSpace` option values.

```
ShowLegend[
 Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, 
    Blue}], {{{Graphics[{Blue, AbsoluteThickness[2], 
      Line[{{0, 0.5}, {1.4, 0.5}}]}], 
    Sin[x]}, {Graphics[{Red, AbsoluteThickness[2], 
      Line[{{0, 0.5}, {1.4, 0.5}}]}], Cos[x]}}, 
  LegendPosition -> {0.5, 0.2}, LegendBackground -> White, 
  LegendBorder -> None, LegendShadow -> None, 
  LegendSize -> {0.45, 0.35}, LegendBorder -> None, 
  LegendTextSpace -> 0.6} ]
```

[image]