# Increasing the thickness of line in plot legend

Tags: plotting

I've been using the shiny new legends in V9 for my plots. However, I usually increase the `Frame`/`Axis` `Thickness` and the plot `Thickness` and I would like the thickness of the legend line to match. There is a related question ([Legend of a plot: how to increase the size of the line/marker?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4474/legend-of-a-plot-how-to-increase-the-size-of-the-line-marker?rq=1)) asked about using the previous `PlotLegends` package.

See this simple example, modified from the documentation:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.005], 
  AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.005]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've tried the obvious modification of the `LineLegend` `LabelStyle`, however, this just appears to modify the text and has no effect here:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Automatic, LabelStyle -> Thickness[0.5]], 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.005], 
  AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.005]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I found that I could set `Joined -> False` and use a thicker `line` as a `LegendMarker` but it is never as long as the normal legend line no matter how long you make the line... (also note that to get a comparable thickness it has to be set two orders of magnitude higher)

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  LineLegend[Automatic, Joined -> False, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Medium], 
   LegendMarkers -> 
    Graphics[{Thickness[0.5], Line[{{-2, 0}, {2, 0}}]}]], 
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.005], AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.005]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

now make the line really long (no change):

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  LineLegend[Automatic, Joined -> False, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Medium], 
   LegendMarkers -> 
    Graphics[{Thickness[0.5], Line[{{-100, 0}, {100, 0}}]}]], 
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.005], AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.005]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've tried to look at the `InputForm` for the plots and for just a `LineLegend` but I can't figure out what exactly I need to replace to fix this.

Comment: Note, the boxed 1 and 2 are placeholders that can be edited. Personally, I prefer `"Expressions"` to `Automatic` as it will display the equations used, for function plots, only, of course.

Comment: I think you're looking for `LegendMarkerSize`. See also: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19283/8

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I find it useful to stick with AbsoluteThickness (and related) when using PlotLegends.

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2], AxesStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

If you remove `Joined->False` it seems that you can get a better length for the given line thickness:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
PlotLegends -> 
LineLegend[Automatic, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Medium], 
LegendMarkers -> 
Graphics[{Thickness[0.2], Line[{{-10, 0}, {10, 0}}]}]], 
PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.005], AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.005]]
```

[image: thicker and longer lines]

Answer (score 9):

As a last resort you can always adjust LineLegend manually:

```
stl[n_, thick_] := Thread[{ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[;; n]], AbsoluteThickness@thick}];
leg = LineLegend[Directive@@@stl[2, 10], Automatic];
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, \[Pi]}, PlotLegends -> leg]
```

[image]

I'm quite surprised that one can't do it in more usual way..

Answer (score 5):

```
frame[legend_] :=Framed[legend, FrameStyle -> {Black, Thickness[1.]}, RoundingRadius -> 10, FrameMargins -> 2, Background -> White];
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> {{Orange, AbsoluteThickness[3]}, {Blue, Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[3]}}, PlotLegends ->Placed[LineLegend[{Style["Experimental Results", 17], Style["Numeric Results", 17]}, LegendFunction -> frame], {1.1, 0.5}], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]