# How can I mark each of several plots with a parameter that identifies it?

Tags: plotting

I've got a two variable function that I'm plotting against one axis for a few different values of a parameter

```
Clear[f, r]
f[r_] := 4 r /(1 - r)^2
i[r_, delta_] := 1/(1 + f[r] Sin[delta/2]^2)
Show[
 Table[ Plot[i[r, delta], {delta, 0, 4 Pi},
   PlotRange -> {0, 1}], {r, {0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.97}}]
 ]
```

This looks like

[image: Plot of etalon interference]

but I'd like to label each of the curves with the value of the parameter (`r = 0.1`, `r = 0.3`, ...).  I can do this manually inserting labels with the Graphics controls, but figured there's got to be a better way.

Comment: It would certainly be nice if there were some way to use `Tooltip` for this sort of thing.

Comment: Looks like there's a ToolTip like LabelingFunction for Charts, but I don't see a way to use those with Plot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd invert `Table` and `Plot` :

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]

Plot[Evaluate@Table[i[r, delta], {r, {0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.97}}], {delta, 0, 4 Pi}, 
PlotRange -> {0, 1}, PlotLegend -> {0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.97}, LegendPosition -> {0.95, 0.05}]
```

[image: plot with legends]

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing with Evaluate@ here?

Comment: @Peeter, `Evaluate[]` forces the first argument of `Plot[]` to be an explicit list of functions, which are then plotted with different colors. Execute `Plot[Table[x^k, {k, 0, 2}], {x, 0, 1}]` and `Plot[Evaluate @ Table[x^k, {k, 0, 2}], {x, 0, 1}]` to see the difference.

Comment: @PeeterJoot Without the `Evaluate` `Plot` only sees one function and thus will not get the coloring and the legend right. Just try and look at the result. Just as an aside, there is also an undocumented option `Evaluated->True` which does the same thing, but is preferable as it also results in correct scoping.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize there's a Hold attribute associated with Plot, and found an explaination of that here:

http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6894/why-do-i-have-to-put-evaluate-here

Comment: Instead of `PlotLegends`, consider using the code in this excellent answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/745. It gives much much nicer legends.

Comment: @Ajasja Thanks, very nice indeed.

Answer (score 40):

I made a function that could be used for labeling plots interactively, adding labeled Bezier arrows, preserve your labels from session to session, and a few more goodies.

Some snapshots follow:

Calling code:

```
Clear[f, r]
f[r_] := 4 r/(1 - r)^2
i[r_, delta_] := 1/(1 + f[r] Sin[delta/2]^2)
s = Plot[Evaluate@Table[i[r, d], {r, {.1, .3, .6, .97}}], {d, 0, 4 Pi}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}];
lblPlot[s, {FontFamily -> "xkcd", 16}]
```

Working area:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Result

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit:**

Per @Rojo's request, added an option to preload old exported lbls like this:

```
lblPlot[s, {FontFamily -> "xkcd", 16}, optLblsO -> oldExportedLabels]
```

As the code is too long for posting it here, you can download it by executing:

```
NotebookPut@ImportString[Uncompress@FromCharacterCode@Flatten@ImageData[
            Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pcrS.png","Byte"],"NB"]
```

**Edit**

Code added:

```
ClearAll[lblPlot];
Options[lblPlot] = {maxArrowedLbls -> 5, maxNonArrowedLbls -> 5, optLblsO -> {}};
lblPlot[s_Graphics, myStyle_List: {FontFamily -> "Times", 16}, OptionsPattern[]] :=

 (* Thanks to @WReach, @jVincent and @chris @Rojo for their useful help and code *)
 (* Errors, bugs and bad coding due to belisarius*)

 Module[{myLabel, copyToNewNB, exportLbls, printLbls, u, plotRsrv, 
         safeGuard = {"FeboAsoma"}, optLbls},

  myLabel[{str_, {p1_, p2_, p3_}}] := {Thick, Arrow@BezierCurve[{p3, p2, p1}], 
                                      Inset[Style[str, myStyle], p3, Background -> White]};

  myLabel[{str_, p1 : {_, _}}] := {Thick, Inset[Style[str, myStyle], p1, Background -> White]};

  copyToNewNB[plot_, list_] := Module[{nb},  nb = NotebookCreate[];
                               NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@plot, "Output"]];
                               printLbls[nb, list]; ];

  exportLbls[list_] := Module[{nb},  nb = NotebookCreate[]; printLbls[nb, list];];

  printLbls[nb_, list_] := (NotebookWrite[nb, 
     Cell["Reserve the following expression in your Notebook to \
restore your Labels and Arrows the next time you need to include them \
in the Plot", "Subsection", CellMargins -> {{50, 50}, Inherited}]];
    NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Join[safeGuard, list, safeGuard], "Output"]];);

  u = Array[(PlotRange /. Options[s, PlotRange])[[All, 1]] +
      Flatten[Differences /@ (PlotRange /. Options[s, PlotRange])/4] # &, 3];

  optLbls = OptionValue[optLblsO];

  Panel@DynamicModule[{pts1 = {}, pts2 = {}, lbl1 = {}, lbl2 = {}, varRsrv = "Label Import Area"},

    If[Head[optLbls] == List && Length@optLbls == 6 && 
       optLbls[[1]] == optLbls[[-1]] == safeGuard[[1]],
     {pts1 = optLbls[[2]], pts2 = optLbls[[3]], lbl1 = optLbls[[4]], lbl2 = optLbls[[5]]}];

    Column[{Dynamic@ Show[
        plotRsrv = Show[s, Epilog -> myLabel /@ Join @@
             {MapIndexed[{lbl1[[#2[[1]]]], #1} &, Partition[pts1, 3]],
              MapIndexed[{lbl2[[#2[[1]]]], #1} &, pts2]}, ImageSize -> 500],
        Graphics[{
          Dynamic@MapIndexed[ With[{i = #2[[1]]}, Locator[Dynamic[pts1[[i]]]]] &, pts1],
          Dynamic@MapIndexed[ With[{i = #2[[1]]}, Locator[Dynamic[pts2[[i]]]]] &, pts2]},
         PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]],

        InputField[Dynamic@varRsrv, FieldSize -> 55, FieldHint -> "Label Import Area"],

      Row[{
        Button["Add Labeled Arrow", 
         If[Length@pts1 < 3 OptionValue[maxArrowedLbls], 
          AppendTo[lbl1, "Arrow"]; pts1 = pts1~Join~(u)]],
        Button["Add Label", 
         If[Length@pts2 < 
           OptionValue[maxNonArrowedLbls], (AppendTo[lbl2, "Label"]; 
           AppendTo[pts2, u[[2]]])]],
        Button["Copy to new .nb", copyToNewNB[plotRsrv, {pts1, pts2, lbl1, lbl2}]],
        Button["Export Labels", exportLbls[{pts1, pts2, lbl1, lbl2}]],
        Button["Import Labels",
         (*validate the labels set, then import *)
         If[
           Head[varRsrv] == List && Length@varRsrv == 6 && 
            varRsrv[[1]] == varRsrv[[-1]] == safeGuard[[1]],
           {pts1 = varRsrv[[2]], pts2 = varRsrv[[3]], 
            lbl1 = varRsrv[[4]], lbl2 = varRsrv[[5]]}, 
           MessageDialog["You're trying to Import a label set not created by \"Export Labels\""],
           MessageDialog[{Head[varRsrv], varRsrv[[1]] == varRsrv[[-1]] == safeGuard}]]
          ;]}],

      Dynamic@Grid[Transpose[{
          (*arrows*)
          {""}~Join~PadRight[Row[{#,
                InputField[Dynamic[lbl1[[#]]], String],
                Button["Delete" <> ToString@#,
                 (lbl1 = Drop[lbl1, {#, #}];
                  pts1 = Drop[pts1, {3 # - 2, 3 #}])]}] & /@ 
             Range@(Length@pts1/3), Max[Length@lbl1, Length@lbl2], ""],
          (*non- arrows*)
          {""}~Join~PadRight[Row[{#,
                InputField[Dynamic[lbl2[[#]]], String],
                Button["Delete" <> ToString@#,
                 (lbl2 = Drop[lbl2, {#, #}];
                  pts2 = Drop[pts2, {#}])]}] & /@ Range@(Length@pts2),
             Max[Length@lbl1, Length@lbl2], ""]
          }], ItemSize -> 30]}]]
  ]

Clear[f, r]
f[r_] := 4 r/(1 - r)^2
i[r_, delta_] := 1/(1 + f[r] Sin[delta/2]^2)
s = Plot[Evaluate@
    Table[i[r, delta], {r, {0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.97}}], {delta, 0, 4 Pi},  PlotRange -> {0, 1}];
lblPlot[s, {FontFamily -> "xkcd", 16}]
```

Comment: Wow, that works really nicely.  Great work!

Comment: @PeeterJoot I like it too :)

Comment: @ belisarius - May I ask how you compressed the code into a PNG? It's very neat.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Code here http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/633/193

Comment: @ChrisDegnen A palette here http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/771/for-sale-three-potentially-useful-palettes

Comment: @ Dr. belisarius - your answer is quite useful and helps also solving my problem posted here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132268/annotating-plots-by-adding-labels-with-arrows-connecting-them-to-data-points/132327#132327But I do have other questions: 1) how do you export the plot with the arrows to a static format that can be included in other documents and shared? and 2) how can I define the size of the image? ImageSize seems not to work. thanks

Answer (score 15):

You can also use `Epilog` to place the labels on the lines.

Example:

```
Row[Plot[Evaluate@
 Table[i[r, delta], {r, {0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.97}}], {delta, 0, 4 Pi},
PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1}},
PlotStyle -> (Directive[Thick, #] & /@ {Red, Green, Blue, Orange}),
PlotRangePadding -> .05, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400,
Epilog -> {Table[(Style[Text[r, {#, i[r, #]}], 12, 
       Background -> White] &) /@ (#),
   {r, {0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.97}}]}] & /@
{{Pi}, {3 Pi}, {Pi/2, 3 Pi/2, 5 Pi/2, 7 Pi/2}}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent.  That's much more like what I was thinking.  If I try modifying the text to Text[ "R = " r, ... then strangely it displays as "0.1 R =", "0.3 R =", ... ?  Is there a way to concatonate multiple text objects at the location specified by one?

Comment: @Peeter, try Text[Row[{"R = ", r}], {#, i[r, #]}].

Comment: .. or `Text["r = " <> ToString[r], {#, i[r, #]}]`.

Comment: `StringForm[]` would also be convenient to use here...

Answer (score 1):

Using `PlotLabels` makes it straightforward:

```
f[r_] := 4 r/(1 - r)^2
i[r_, delta_] := 1/(1 + f[r] Sin[delta/2]^2)
place = {Scaled[r], After};
Show[Table[
  Plot[i[r, delta], {delta, 0, 4 Pi}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
   Frame -> True, 
   PlotLabels -> Placed[{ToString[r]}, place]], {r, {0.1,
     0.3, 0.6, 0.97}}]]
```

[image]

One can use different placements, i.e. different location specifications instead of `place`; I chose `Scaled[r]` because for this particular plot it works fine and `After` because in my opinion it looks best.

Comment: My question was old (Mathematica 8 days).  This new better labelling option was mentioned in a comment referring to: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/creating-legends-for-plots-with-multiple-lines/4028#4028

Also note that Mathematica11 appears to have further refined its Labelling methods, but I haven't purchased the upgrade to try that out.

Comment: I get it all, I just stumbled upon this question acidentally, so to speak, and thought it might be useful for future users to point them toward some update.