# How do I identify each surface in a multi-surface Plot3D?

Tags: plotting, legending

I am plotting three surfaces on a 3D plot. They differ in the value of one parameter. Is there a way to distinguish each surface for various values of the parameter?

My code is:

```
Plot3D[{
  2*(Cosh[ h/ T]*(2 + Exp[2    / T]) + Exp[-2     / T]*Cosh[3 h/ T] ), 
  2*(Cosh[ h/ T]*(2 + Exp[2  10/ T]) + Exp[-2   10/ T]*Cosh[3 h/ T] ), 
  2*(Cosh[ h/ T]*(2 + Exp[2 100/ T]) + Exp[-2  100/ T]*Cosh[3 h/ T] )},
  {T, 0.001, 1000},
  {h, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> Style[Framed["Partition Function Z"], 20, Red, 
    Background -> Lighter[LightYellow]],
  Background -> LightGray, 
  ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
  AxesLabel -> {T[kelvin], B[tesla]},
  BoundaryStyle -> Thick, 
  ClippingStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]
```

The output graphics is:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

I am trying to use `ShowLegend` because `PlotLegend` cannot work with `Plot3D` in v8...
The code I am using is:

```
Z[T_, h_, a_] := 2*(Cosh[h/T]*(2 + Exp[2 a/(T)]) + Exp[-2/(T)]*Cosh[3 h/T]);
params = {1, 10, 100};
ShowLegend[
  Plot3D[
    Evaluate[Table[Tooltip[Z[T, h, a], StringForm["a = ``", a]], {a, params}]],
    {T, 0.001, 1000},
    {h, 0, 1}, 
    PlotLabel -> Style[Framed["Partition Function Z"], 20, Red, 
      Background -> Lighter[LightYellow]], 
    MeshFunctions -> {(*#1&,*)#2 &, #3 &}, 
    Mesh -> {(*15,*)15, Range[7.5, 11, 0.1]}, 
    MeshStyle -> {(*Gray,*)Gray, Black}, Background -> LightGray, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue},
    (*PlotLegends->Table[StringForm["a = ``",a],{a,params}],*)
    AxesLabel -> {T[kelvin], B[tesla]}, 
    BoundaryStyle -> Thick,
    ClippingStyle -> Opacity[0.5]], 
  Graphics3D[{
    Table[{Arrowheads[0.0004], 
      Arrow[{{900, 0.2 + 0.25 Log10[a], 9.5},
        {50. + 5 a, 0.01 + 0.005 a, Z[50. + 5 a, 0.01 + 0.005 a, a]}}], 
      Text[Style[Framed[StringForm["J = ``", a]], Red, Background -> Lighter[LightYellow]],
        {900, 0.2 + 0.25 Log10[a], 9.5}]},
      {a, params}]}],
  {{{Graphics[{Table[StringForm["a = ``", a], {a, params}]}]}}, 
    LegendPosition -> {1.1, -.4}}]
```

Comment: It's in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot3D.html#1298077331), isn't it? "Provide separate styles for different surfaces: `PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}`". You'll want to provide three colours, get rid of `ColorFunction`, and use `Lighting -> "Neutral"`.

Comment: @RahulNarain: Thank you very much for your comment. The thing is that I don't need just one colour on each surface, but actually a gradient illustrating height.

Comment: Probably easiest to generate each plot separately using a different `ColorFunction`  for each; then use `Show` to combine the three images.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: Thank you very much for your suggestion. In that way, though will I be able to use a legend?

Comment: Your ShowLegend syntax is a little off.  Wrap `Plot3D` and `Graphics3D` in `Show[..]` so that it is a single argument  -- or you might drop the arrows if you're going to use a legend.  Then the second argument should be something like `{Table[{Graphics[{{Red, Green, Blue}[[1 + Log10[a]]], Rectangle[]}], StringForm["J = ``", a]}, {a, params}], LegendPosition -> {1.1, -.4}}`.  See belisarius's edit for another way, which preserves 3d interactivity.

Answer (score 9):

```
f[k_, h_, t_] := 2*(Cosh[h/t]*(2 + Exp[(2/t) 10^k]) + Exp[-(2 /t) 10^k]*Cosh[3 h/t]);

grad = {"LakeColors", "DarkRainbow", "NeonColors"};

Show@Table[
  Plot3D[f[k, h, t], {t, 0.001, 1000}, {h, 0, 1}, 
   ColorFunction -> grad[[k + 1]], ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {8, 8.8},
   PlotLabel -> Style[Framed["Partition Function Z"], 20, Red, Background -> Lighter[LightYellow]], 
   Background -> LightGray, AxesLabel -> {T[kelvin], B[tesla]}, BoundaryStyle -> Thick, 
   ClippingStyle -> Opacity[0.5]
   ], {k, {0, 1, 2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Or you could do something like this:

```
f[k_, h_, t_] := 2*(Cosh[h/t]*(2 + Exp[(2/t) 10^k]) + Exp[-(2/t) 10^k]*Cosh[3 h/t]);

Needs["PlotLegends`"];
GraphicsRow[{
 Show@Table[Plot3D[f[k, h, t], {t, 0.001, 1000}, {h, 0, 1},
     ColorFunction -> 
      Function[{x,y,z}, RGBColor[Sequence @@ RotateLeft[{1,0,0}, k], Rescale[z, {7.8,8.8}]]],
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
     MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
     PlotRange -> {8, 8.8},
     PlotLabel -> Style[Framed["Partition Function Z"], 20, Red],
     Background -> LightGray,
     AxesLabel -> {T[kelvin], B[tesla]},
     BoundaryStyle -> Thick,
     ClippingStyle -> Opacity[0.5]],
    {k, {0, 1, 2}}],
  Graphics@
   Legend[
      Table[{Graphics[{RGBColor[Sequence @@ RotateLeft[{1, 0, 0}, k]], Rectangle[]}], 10^k}, 
      {k, 0, 2}], LegendBorder -> None, LegendShadow -> None]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much for yur answer. How am I going to put a legend in that?

Comment: @Thanos Edited.

Comment: Thank you once again! What I really mean is not a label, but a legend illustrating which surface is which!

Comment: @Thanos Take a look at this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14149/193

Comment: mmm ... not sure how to use it with Plot3D :(

Comment: Well, me neither! :P

Comment: Adding the option `PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {10, 200}, 
   LegendLabel -> ("k=" <> ToString[k])], {Scaled[{1.2 + k .2, 0.5}], {1.0, 0.5}}]` gives something that needs fine-tuning for size and positionining; but, somehow, 3D interactivity is lost in the process.

Answer (score 5):

There are various things you might try, depending on your particular objectives.

1. If you aren't wedded to gradients, you can use `#3&` as a mesh function to indicate height.  For your particular functions, you might wish to omit `#1&` as a mesh function, since the mesh lines are parallel.
2. If you need to distinguish graphs in an notebook and not in a printout, you can use tooltips.
3. You can insert 3D graphics to draw labels & arrows to the plots.  Possibly unsatisfactory if the graph is to be rotated about.

Here is an example incorporating all three ideas (with belisarius's label).

```
Z[T_, h_, a_] := 
  2*(Cosh[h/T]*(2 + Exp[2 a/(T)]) + Exp[-2/(T)]*Cosh[3 h/T]);
params = {1, 10, 100};
Show[Plot3D[
  Evaluate[Table[
    Tooltip[Z[T, h, a], StringForm["a = ``", a]], {a, params}]], {T, 
   0.001, 1000}, {h, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style[Framed["Partition Function Z"], 20, Red, 
    Background -> Lighter[LightYellow]], 
  MeshFunctions -> {(*#1&,*)#2 &, #3 &}, 
  Mesh -> {(*15,*)15, Range[7.5, 11, 0.1]}, 
  MeshStyle -> {(*Gray,*)Gray, Black}, Background -> LightGray, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, 
  PlotLegends -> Table[StringForm["a = ``", a], {a, params}], 
  AxesLabel -> {T[kelvin], B[tesla]}, BoundaryStyle -> Thick, 
  ClippingStyle -> Opacity[0.5]],
 Graphics3D[{Table[{Arrowheads[0.0004], 
     Arrow[{{900, 0.2 + 0.25 Log10[a], 9.5}, {50. + 5 a, 
        0.01 + 0.005 a, Z[50. + 5 a, 0.01 + 0.005 a, a]}}], 
     Text[Style[Framed[StringForm["a = ``", a]], Red, 
       Background -> Lighter[LightYellow]], {900, 0.2 + 0.25 Log10[a],
        9.5}]}, {a, params}]}]
 ]
```

[image: Output from example]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The thing is that I use v8.0.0, which means that `PlotLegend` isn't working. But that's not my problem. I commented `PlotLegends -> Table[StringForm["a = ``", a], {a, params}]` and run the rest but I got 2 errors...http://i.imgur.com/uOXNa.png AND http://i.imgur.com/2W8Nx.png

Comment: After the PlotStyle option, you have to commas in a row, which translates to a Null.  The commas are likely on either side of the PlotLegends option, which you commented out -- include one of the commas in the comment or delete it.  That should cure the second error, too.

Comment: By the way, there is a [PlotLegends](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v8/PlotLegends/ref/PlotLegend.html) package in v8.

Comment: You were right about the comma...Silly me! As far as `PlotLegend` is concerned, I was dealing with a similar problem and I was suggested to use `ShowLegend[Plot3d[...],{{{Graphics[...],...}}}]` because in v8 `PlotLegend` cannot work with `Plot3D`... The thing is that I cannot get it to work... Check my edited question for the code...