# Labels for each curve on a multi-curve plot using an efficient method(without writing a large code)

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have a question on plot labeling in *Mathematica*. I have

```
y = 4 x / L + 2
```

where

```
L = {10, 20, 30, 40}
```

I want to draw a graph of y vs. x.  When I evaluate

```
Plot[y, {x, 0, 100}, 
   ImageSize -> Scaled[1.0],
   PlotLabel ->  Style["y vs X ", FontSize -> 18]]
```

I get four different lines in the same plot. I want to know how to label each line with its relevant L value; e.g., "l = 10" for the corresponding line.

Could anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: As is, your plot plots all the lines on the same plane. Do you want an inset labeling each line on the plane, or four separate plots?

Comment: yes, I want to label each line on the plane.(As l=10 for line corresponds to that)

Comment: change like this:  dat = "L=" <> ToString@# & /@ {10, 20, 30, 40};

Comment: @yulinlinyu Could you please send me the complete code which I want write?

Comment: Take a look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14149/193

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is a duplicate but I couldn't find the original - so here it is along those lines:

```
y[x_, L_] := 4 x/L + 2

dat = {10, 20, 30, 40};

Plot[y[x, #] & /@ dat // Evaluate, {x, 0, 100}, 
 Epilog -> (Text["L = " <> ToString[#], {70, 0 + y[80, #]}] & /@ dat)]
```

[image]

Comment: not like this. I want a label "l=10" near the line correspond to l=10

Comment: I am getting an error like this. SetDelayed::write: Tag List in {2+(2 x)/5,2+x/5,2+(2 x)/15,2+x/10}[x_,L_] is Protected. >>

Comment: @Vitaly Kaurov This is what I want. Unfortunately, I am getting an error. Could you explain me the reason?

Comment: @TMH You probably have some old definitions. Restart Mathematica. Or just compute `Exit` on a new line and re-evaluate.

Comment: Yes,It works now. Thanks a lot Vitaliy.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Here is a possibility (self promotional :D ) http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14149/193

Comment: @belisarius well it worked - you got a +1 ;)