# Label points in plot with a text

Tags: plotting, text, labeling

I'm a newbie at Mathematica and I couldn't find how to label the maximum and the zero of a simple function in `Plot` with their names:

```
rho[r_] = 1 - r^2;
Plot[rho[r], {r, -1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {r, \[Rho]}]
```

and i want to show the maximum on the plot with

```
Subscript[\[Rho], c]
```

and the point rho[1] with

```
Subscript[R, TF]
```

Comment: Look up `Text[]` or `Inset[]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
 rho[r_] = 1 - r^2;
 pl = Plot[rho[r], {r, -1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {r, \[Rho]}];
```

then

```
Show[{pl, Graphics[Text[Subscript[\[Rho], c], {0.05, 1.05}]],
Graphics[Text[Subscript[R, TF], {1.05, 0.05}]]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 7):

You can put `Text` and `Point` on a plot with `Epilog`.

```
Plot[rho[r - Pi], {r, 1, 5},
 AxesLabel -> {r, \[Rho]},
 Epilog -> {
   PointSize[.01], Red, Point[zero],
   Black, Point[max], Map[Text[#[[1]], #[[2]], {0, -2}] &,
    Transpose[{{-Subscript["R", "TF"],
       Subscript["R", "TF"], Subscript["\[Rho]", "c"]},
      Join[zero, {max}]}]]},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotRangePadding -> .5]
```

[image: plot]

Calculated maximum and zeroes:

```
max = {r /. Last@#, First@#} &[FindMaximum[rho[r - Pi], r]]
{3.14159, 1.}

zero = {r, 0} /. NSolve[rho[r - Pi] == 0, r]
{{2.14159, 0}, {4.14159, 0}}
```

Answer (score 6):

Using my answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14149/193), you can generate any of the following interactively:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The only change needed is to remove the "String" in

```
InputField[Dynamic[lbl1[[#]]],String]
```

and

```
InputField[Dynamic[lbl2[[#]]],String]
```

to be able to type expressions.

The interactive interface looks like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]