# Label points in a plot

Tags: plotting, labeling

Here is my code:

```
h[θ_] := (1 - θ)/θ
x = Plot[{h[θ], 2.5}, {θ, 0.1, 1}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Monochrome",
  AxesLabel -> {"θ", "h(θ)"}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"h(θ)", "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(θ\), \(^\)]\)"}, Below], 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 10},
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.01], Black, Point[{{0.2, 4}, {0.25, 3}, {0.4, 1.5}, {0.5, 1}}]}]
```

I want to label these 4 points as A,B,C,D, respectively. I tried to implement the answer from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22609/27275), but I got lost with `Map`, `Transpose`, etc.

So, I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No Map, no Transpose, no etc.

```
h[θ_]:=(1-θ)/θ;
x=Plot[{h[θ],2.5},{θ,0.1,1},
  Epilog->{
    Point[{0.2,4}],Text["A",{0.2,4},{-1,-1}],
    Point[{0.25,3}],Text["B",{0.25,3},{-1,-1}],
    Point[{0.4,1.5}],Text["C",{0.4,1.5},{-1,-1}],
    Point[{0.5,1}],Text["D",{0.5,1},{-1,-1}]
}]
```

There. See how much easier that is to understand.

Answer (score 6):

With `Callout`s and combining a separate `ListPlot` using a `Show`:

```
h[θ_] := (1 - θ)/θ
Show[
 Plot[{h[θ], 2.5}, {θ, 0.1, 1}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", AxesLabel -> {"θ", "h(θ)"},
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{"h(θ)", "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(θ\), \(^\)]\)"}, Below], 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 10}],
  With[{pts = {{0.2, 4}, {0.25, 3}, {0.4, 1.5}, {0.5, 1}}, labels = {"A","B","C","D"}},
    ListPlot[Thread[Callout[pts, labels]]]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: plot with callouts]