# How can I add label for every function in plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling

I wrote the following code:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, {Blue, Thick}}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

I want to have label for every function in plot. Please see the following picture:
[image]

Comment: `Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, {Blue, Thick}}, 
 PlotLabels -> Placed["Expressions", Below]]`

Comment: @corey979 This code not work in Mathematica version10.

Comment: @user37694 This works fine in 10.4

Comment: See [How can I mark each of several plots with a parameter that identifies it?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13906/how-can-i-mark-each-of-several-plots-with-a-parameter-that-identifies-it).

Comment: Then go basic. `Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, {Blue, Thick}}, 
 Epilog -> {Text["sin(x)", {3/2 Pi, -1.1}], 
   Text["cos(x)", {Pi, -1.1}]}, PlotRange -> {-1.2, 1.2}]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Edit to add Labeled details*

You can use `Callout` for 'in-plot' labels, for example:

```
Plot[{
  Callout[Sin[x], "Sin[x]", Below], 
  Callout[Cos[x], "Cos[x]", Below]
}, 
{x, 0, 10}, 
PlotStyle -> {Red, {Blue, Thick}}
]
```

[image: Callout]

Alternatively if you do not have version 11 you can use `Labeled` to get a similar effect, like this:

```
Plot[{
  Labeled[Sin[x], "Sin[x]", Below], 
  Labeled[Cos[x], "Cos[x]", Below]
}, 
{x, 0, 10}, 
PlotStyle -> {Red, {Blue, Thick}}
]
```

[image: Labeled]

This does lose the lines but you could make a labeling function to customise this, for example:

```
plotLabel[text_] := Graphics[{
  Line[{{0, -1}, {0, 0}}], 
  Text[Style[text, 10], {0, -2}]
},
ImageSize -> 30
]
```

Which with `Labeled` makes:

[image: CustomLabel]

Comment: My Mathematica version is 10. With this code I do not have any output.

Comment: Callout is a new function in Mathematica 11.0

Comment: `Callout` is a new function in version 11.  In version 10 you can use `Labeled` in its place to get a similar output, but it won't give you the lines from the text to the plot line.  You could construct your own label creation function with Graphics if you had a specific style in mind.

Comment: I've got 10.4 and it don't work using Placed. But it does work using Labeled. Thank you. Tony Dee