# Click on a curve to start Manipulating another function

Tags: plotting, manipulate, button

I'm able to plot two lists with a tooltip on the curves to display the name of the curve:

```
list1 = {{{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 4}}, {{0, 3}, {1, 1}, {2, 5}}};
names = {"curve1", "curve2"};
ListLinePlot[Table[Tooltip[list1[[i]], names[[i]]], {i, Length[list1]}]]
```

[image]

Now I would like to evaluate this action when I click on a curve:

```
Manipulate[dummyFunction[nameOfTheCurve, variable], {variable , {0, 1}}]
```

with dummyFunction being

```
dummyFunction[t_, u_] := If[u == 1,
  Graphics[{Green, Disk[], Black, Text[t]}],
  Graphics[{Red, Disk[], Black, Text[t]}]
]
```

and `nameOfTheCurve` being the name of the clicked curve.

I've tried

```
ListLinePlot[Table[Button[list1[[i]], Manipulate[dummyFunction[names[[i]], variable], {variable , {0, 1}}]], {i,Length[list1]}]]
```

but this doesn't work (I can't click on the curve). What's the correct syntax? And more precisely, I would like to plot the output of dummyFunction (the Disk) under the first graph, not replacing it.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to do something similar to [my answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20803/245)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the simplest version of what you want. The `Manipulate` objects are printed right under the plot.

```
list1 = {{{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 4}}, {{0, 3}, {1, 1}, {2, 5}}};
names = {"curve1", "curve2"};
dummyFunction[t_, u_] := Graphics[{If[u == 1, Green, Red], Disk[], Black, Text[t]}];

ListLinePlot[MapThread[
  Tooltip[EventHandler[#, {"MouseClicked" :> 
       CellPrint[Manipulate[dummyFunction[#2, 
          variable], {variable, {0, 1}}]]}], #2] &, {list1, names}]]
```

It has the issue that every time a curve is clicked, a new `Manipulate` is printed. To overcome this problem and only show one of the `Manipulate`s at a time, introduce an extra switch (`show`) that records whichever curve was clicked, and a variable that stores the actual `Manipulate` (`menu`).

```
list1 = {{{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 4}}, {{0, 3}, {1, 1}, {2, 5}}};
names = {"curve1", "curve2"};
show = 0;
menu = Spacer@0;
dummyFunction[t_, u_] := Graphics[{If[u == 1, Green, Red], Disk[], Black, Text[t]}];

Column@{
  ListLinePlot[
   MapThread[
    Tooltip[EventHandler[#1, {"MouseClicked" :> 
         If[show =!= #3, show = #3; 
          menu = Manipulate[dummyFunction[#2, variable], {variable, {0, 1}}], 
          show = 0; menu = Spacer@0]}], #2] &, {list1, names, 
     Range@Length@names}]],
  Dynamic@menu}
```

Even more convenient is the following setup where the appearing menu is directly inserted in `ListLinePlot` result:

```
list1 = {{{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 4}}, {{0, 3}, {1, 1}, {2, 5}}};
names = {"curve1", "curve2"};
selected = None;
dummyFunction[t_, u_] := Graphics[{If[u == 1, Green, Red], Disk[],
        Black, Style[Text[t], 14]}, ImageSize -> 40]

Dynamic[ListLinePlot[MapThread[EventHandler[#2,
     "MouseDown" :> (
       menuPos = MousePosition["Graphics"]; 
       selected = #1;
       menu = Grid[{{
           Manipulate[dummyFunction[names[[#1]], x], {x, {0, 1}}],
           Button["X", selected = None; menu = Spacer@0, ImageSize -> {20, 20}]
           }}, Spacings -> 0, Alignment -> Top]),
     PassEventsDown -> False, PassEventsUp -> False] &,
   {Range@Length@list1, list1}],
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, If[selected === 1, Dashed, {}], Red}, {Thick, 
     If[selected === 2, Dashed, {}], Blue}}, ImageSize -> 400, 
  Epilog -> If[selected =!= None, Inset[menu, menuPos], {}]], 
 TrackedSymbols :> {menuPos, selected, menu}]
```

[image]

### Edit

The second approach, in its package-ready function form:

```
f[list_, names_] := DynamicModule[{show = 0, menu = Spacer@0, dummy},
   dummy[t_, u_] := 
    Graphics[{If[u == 1, Green, Red], Disk[], Black, Text@t}, 
     ImageSize -> 60];
   Column@{ListLinePlot[
      MapThread[
       Tooltip[EventHandler[#1, {"MouseClicked" :> If[show =!= #3,
             show = #3; 
             menu = Manipulate[
               dummy[#2, variable], {variable, {0, 1}}],
             show = 0; menu = Spacer@0
             ]}], #2] &, {list, names, Range@Length@names}]], 
     Dynamic@menu}
   ];

list = {{{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 4}}, {{0, 3}, {1, 1}, {2, 5}}};
names = {"curve1", "curve2"};
Manipulate[f[list, names], {t, {"a", "b"}}]
```

Comment: Fantastic exactly what I wanted! There are a few functions I don't know so I have to take the time to read about that, and also I would need to generalize it to the case where I not only have two curves but a changing number n. Other than this it works great!

Comment: My examples are fairly general, I only left the final `Epilog` part to be converted to a `Table` or `Map`, as an exercise. Thanks for the accept, though mind that it is generally more rewarding to wait a few days before accepting an answer so that other, even better solutions could appear!

Comment: I tried to implement your second piece of code inside another custom function of mine, but for some reason nothing happens when I click on a curve. Even a simple `x = Graphics[Circle[]]` will not get plotted, but I can see with a Print[] that I reach this line. I know it's a vague question and I'm still trying to figure out what prevents the second plot to be plotted, but are there general reasons why this could happen (embedded Manipulate functions, graphs with fixed size...)?

Comment: @su1 I made an error (corrected now) by initially setting `x` instead of `menu`, which is the correct dynamic variable. Could you please check whether it still does not work?

Comment: Yes I was using another variable name so this is not the problem. I think the problem comes from a bad interaction of this piece of code with other functions I'm using around, but there are many so I can't paste everything. It's probably something very simple but I've been working on this for hours now.

Comment: I found the problem. Imagine the piece of code you gave me is found inside a function G[t_], and this function is called with a Manipulate : `Manipulate[G[t],{t,{"a","b"}}]` In this case the click event doesn't work anymore. Any idea why and what I can do to prevent that?

Comment: @su1 Please see edit!

Comment: Thanks it looks like it works, I was just about to post another question because other than Manipulate, it looked like a certain kind of data was making it impossible to click interactively. Now everything works. So the important thing here is to have a DynamicModule instead of a Module and to put variables show, menu and dummy inside?

Comment: @su1 Yes, as `show`, `menu`... should be local to the module. `DynamicModule` is only necessary to maintain localized variables of dynamic expressions "even accross *Mathematica* sessions." Localizing variables prevents the outer `Manipulate` to interfere in any form with the inner `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that this is really all you want, but not knowing any details I'll just answer the specific question how to get a `Manipulate` to run based on a click, and then have the output appear in the plot. If you want the outputs from several clicks to accumulate, you could adapt this in combination with the `AppendTo` method in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20803/245). You say the disk is supposed to appear below line 1, so I'm assuming it's not dynamically movable (again, look at my linked answer if you do want that).

```
With[
 {placedPosition = {1.6, 2}, objectSize = .5},
 DynamicModule[
  {
   object = Graphics[{}]
   },
  ListLinePlot[
   Table[
    PopupWindow[list1[[i]],
     With[{nameTemplate = names[[i]]},
      Manipulate[
       object = 
        dummyFunction[nameTemplate, variable], {variable, {0, 1}}]
      ]
     ],
    {i, Length[list1]}],
   Epilog -> 
    Dynamic[Inset[object, placedPosition, Automatic, objectSize]]
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: manipulate]

I decided to implement your `Manipulate` inside a `PopupWindow` so it's independent of the plot in which you clicked.

I may have misunderstood what you mean by "under the first graph": my interpretation was that it is placed in the same plot. If you want it to be spaced further down then just create extra space with `ImageMargins`, and change the coordinate in `placedPosition` accordingly. The variable `objectSize` is the relative size of the disk in the parent plot.

Comment: By "under the first graph" I meant in a separate graph under this one, like in Istvan Zachar's answer. I'd rather not use a Popup, but thanks, you answer was helpful too!

Comment: @su1 You should vote for all answers that you find helpful.  Note that you can also vote for the answer you Accept (check mark).