# Plane Geometry Diagrams With Labels

Tags: geometry

I can make some basic diagrams in Mathematica (stolen from their pages, for example see the below:

```
 LaminaData["FilledIsoscelesTriangle", "Diagram"]
```

However, I'm trying to make a simple, set of labelled diagrams, similar to this one, with certain angles marked, etc. Is there a tutorial anywhere that explains how to do this please?

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic of the site. Once you gain enough reputation by making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will be able to vote up and down both questions and answers. When you see good ones, please vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. As you receive help, try to give it too, by *answering questions* in your area of expertise.

Comment: You may want to look into [`AASTriangle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AASTriangle.html) and all the `*Traingle`family of functions.

Comment: Thanks rhermans. However, I don't see any options on how to label angles or sides in AASTriangle, is there another reference I am missing?

Comment: Related: [How to position text labels automatically to not overlap other graphics elements?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33006)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For simple graphics just build them step-by-step from graphics primitives.

```
Graphics[{
   (* triangle *)
  Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}],
  (* right angle symbol *)
  Line[{{0, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.1}, {0.1, 0}}],
  (* angle symbol *)
  Circle[{1, 0}, 0.2, {127.5 Degree, 187.5 Degree}],
  (* labels *)
  Rotate[
   Text[Style["opposite side (= y)", 20],
    {-0.1, 0.5}], 90 Degree],
  Text[Style["adjacent side (= x)", 20],
   {0.5, -0.1}],
  Text[Style["hypotenuse (= z)", 20],
   {0.6, 0.5}, {-1, 0}],
  Text[Style["θ", 20], {0.75, 0.08}]
  }]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

@BobHanlon answer is an amazing replication. I post this to illustrate customizability:

```
trn[a_, s_] := 
 Module[{tr = AASTriangle[Pi/2, a, s], sd, s1, s2, s3, txt, ang, dis},
  sd = {s1, s2, s3} = 
    SortBy[Subsets[tr[[1]], {2}], N[EuclideanDistance @@ #] &];
  ang = First@Cases[tr[[1]], {_?(#1 != 0 &), 0}];
  dis = 0.2 {#, #} &@(EuclideanDistance @@ s1);
  txt = MapThread[{Black, 
      Text[Style[#1, 20], Total@#2/2, #3]} &, {{"adjacent side (= x)",
       Rotate["opposite side (=y)", Pi/2], 
      Rotate["hypotenuse (=z)", -a]}, 
     sd, {{0, 2}, {2, 0}, {-0.4, -0.4}}}];
  Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Black], tr, 
    Rectangle[{0, 0}, dis], {Black, 
     Circle[ang, dis, {Pi, Pi - a}]}, {Black, 
     Text[Style["\[Theta]", 
       20], (1.2 dis {Cos[Pi - a/2], Sin[Pi - a/2]} + ang)]}, txt}]
  ]
```

Note of angle

```
Manipulate[trn[an, 2], {an, Pi/3.9, Pi/3}]
```

[image]

Comment: FYI, `Text` has a 4th argument that specifies direction (so that `Rotate` might be avoided).

Comment: @MichaelE2  thank you...always learning...had never used it, guess I didn't look at documentation closely enough

Comment: You're welcome.  I used it [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16194/movable-text-on-a-curve/16228#16228) to make text follow a parametric curve.