# Plot CSV-data; make statistical statements in Mathematica / WA

Tags: plotting, legending, csv-format

First, I'm quite new to Mathematica so sorry in advance if some questions seem to be trivial.

I have a CSV-file which looks like this:

```
"perc","l1","l2","diff"
0.005,116,148,32
0.005,352,30,322
0.005,249,49,200
0.005,23,336,313
0.0051,130,89,41
0.0051,363,46,317
.
.
.
```

*perc* is a percentage between 0…1; *l1* and *l2* are numbers, *diff* is the difference between *l1* and *l2*. Those are the first lines; the full set is ~150.000 lines long; with *perc* from 0 to 1.

I want to plot those data and WolframAlpha (and even GoogleDocs) do a good job here and I get a result like this (actually, this is not entirely correct; *perc* should be plotted on **X**, *l1*, *l2* and *diff* on **Y**; I hope you know what I mean.

[image]

[image]

This, however, only works if my CSV is less than ~4000 rows. If it's bigger, WA fails and "does not know how to interpret the data"; same for Google Docs.
So, I want to redo this in Mathematica, but I don't know how / it doesn't work.

First, I import my CSV:

`data = Import["data.csv", "Table", "HeaderLines" -> 1]`

But then I fail with `ListPlot` because I don't know what options it needs to plot the data correspondingly to WA.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your data is Imported say in data then you can use data[[All,{1,2}]] to use the first column as x and the second as y value. Plotting all three data sets would be

```
ListPlot[{data[[All, {1, 2}]], data[[All, {1, 3}]], data[[All, {1, 4}]]}]
```

If you want to print against row index, like in yopur figure you can use

```
ListPlot[{data[[All, 2]], data[[All, 3]], data[[All, 4]]}, Frame -> True,
  PlotRange -> {0, 1000}, FrameLabel -> {"row index", None}]
```

**Edit**:

To make sure that you import the data correctly you have to enforce "CSV" format. Using the "Table" format will give you the following data:

```
data // FullForm
```

> ```
>    List[List["0.005,116,148,32"],List["0.005,352,30,322"],List["0.005,249,49,200"],List["0.005,23,336,313"],List["0.0051,130,89,41"],List["0.0051,363,46,317"]]
> ```

As you see each line is interpreted as String. Use

```
data = Import["data.csv", "CSV", "HeaderLines" -> 1]
```

instead.  Now

```
data // FullForm
```

correctly gives a list of numerical list elements and the above ListPlot works.

> ```
> List[List[0.005`,116,148,32],List[0.005`,352,30,322],List[0.005`,249,49,200],List[0.005`,23,336,313],List[0.0051`,130,89,41],List[0.0051`,363,46,317]]
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this, that sounds quite logical :) However, if I try the first command, I get back a
`Part::partw: Part {1,2} of {0.0053,456,21,435} does not exist. >>`
followed by the same for 1,3 and 1,4 and a `further output stopped`. (0.0053,456,21,435 is the first data row)

Comment: Use FullForm[data] to see what is gpoing on. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works. Great job.

Answer (score 6):

[`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListPlot.html) requires a list of `{x,y}` pairs for each data set. What Markus is showing is how to get that in the right format.

For styling, read through the options for `PlotStyle` and `PlotMarkers`.

For legends, you have several options:

1. Try to use the `PlotLegend` [Package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/PlotLegends/guide/PlotLegendsPackage.html) (bleh)
2. Roll your own with the help of MMA.SE

   - Most helpful: [Creating legends for plots with multiple lines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/creating-legends-for-plots-with-multiple-lines)
   - Many other questions on plot legends: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=plot+legend