# Show parameters on graph

Tags: plotting

I am graphing the 4 PDFs for a distribution for 4 different parameters in the same graph. I want the values of the parameters to be shown in corner of the graph. How do I do this?

Comment: You can use `Text[]`, among other things. However, it would be nice if you could show a picture of what you're expecting to see from us...

Comment: Something like this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Exponential_pdf.svg/2000px-Exponential_pdf.svg.png

Comment: Oh, you want a *legend*. That's slightly tricky business, and it has been discussed a number of times before here. Have a look at [these](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=legend).

Comment: Although I answered the question, I realize this is a duplicate of [Creating legends for plots with multiple lines?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4025/245) - so it's justified to close this, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is what you get using the code posted in my answer [linked here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/245):

All you have to do is make the plot, and call the function `autoLegend` I defined in the link:

```
styles = {Black, Directive[Dashed, Black], 
  Directive[DotDashed, Black], Directive[Dotted, Black]}
parameters = {1/2, 1/3, 1/5, 1/1000};
p = Plot[Evaluate[
    PDF[ExponentialDistribution[#]][x] & /@ parameters], {x, 0, 50}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> styles];
autoLegend[p, parameters]
```

[image: legend]

Comment: So cool, thanks alot! :)