# Names disapper when using PlotLegend

Tags: plotting, functions, legending

I am using *Mathematica* 8.0.1.0 and when I use PlotLegend the names disappear.

Could you help me fix it?

Thank you.

```
<< "PlotLegends`"; 
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, PlotLegend -> {"Sine", "Cosine"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Use [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/5) instead of the `PlotLegends` package for version 8.0.1. It is not worth the time and trouble to work with the built-in package.

Comment: Thank you. I will study these functions.

Comment: If the suggestion by @R.M. works for you, I would propose closing the question because there is no great likelihood that anyone will be able to fix this particular problem. It's one of so many bugs that it's fair to say nobody cares about the `PlotLegends` package anymore, particularly since it's obsolete now. Also, I can't actually reproduce that issue in version 8 on Mac... maybe you're on Linux?

Comment: Hi, I use Windows.

Comment: OK - then you should definitely try to use the linked answer, e.g., by doing `autoLegend[
 Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}], {"Sine", "Cosine"}]`

Comment: Use `PlotLegends` instead of `PlotLegend`, and all is well.

Comment: @Jens: The function is very complicated and as a newbie I can't understand it. Is it really necessary to understand how that function is written? Thank you.

Comment: Just consider the code as a black box - it's not necessary to understand it. All you need is to look at the usage examples, there are some other ones on this site. E.g., [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5102/245). The main thing is of course to copy all the code from the first code block in my earlier answer and then evaluate the definitions before using them.