# Mathematica "prelude"

Tags: packages, files-and-directories, configuration

Is there any way to have the functions from a mathematica file be loaded on startup?

For example, in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6380/54) excellent answer, Jens helps me out and gives me some functions for creating legends for plots.  Instead of loading a file with those functions in it every time I load mathematica, can I instead put all the functions in a file and have them load every time I load mathematica?

Comment: Entering two words from your question (load startup) in the documentation search bar yields [tutorial/ConfigurationFiles](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConfigurationFiles.html) as first hit. -1 for not first searching documentation.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5293105/618728

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are several [configuration files](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConfigurationFiles.html) that you can use to load functionality at startup. They have the form

```
($BaseDirectory | $UserBaseDirectory)/(Kernel | FrontEnd)/init.m
```

where

```
$BaseDirectory
```

is for every user on the system and

```
$UserBaseDirectory
```

is for you along and `Kernel` or `FrontEnd` specifies what you are configuring. In fact, a lot of the settings under the *Preferences* menu automatically write to `$UserBaseDirectory/FrontEnd/init.m`.

In your case, you are looking to add to `$UserBaseDirctory/Kernel/init.m`.

Comment: `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory,"FrontEnd","init.m"}]` for OS independency.

Answer (score 18):

With `$UserBaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m` the most obvious place to put code which should be autoloaded has been mentioned.

But I think it might be worth mentioning that there is also the `Autoload` directory within `$UserBaseDirectory` where you can put any package file or package directory and those will automatically be loaded at startup. For the purpose mentioned I think that might be an even better place ([after having the code set up as a proper package of course...](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114957/12)).

---

Note that `init.m` files and `Autoload` packages are loaded during kernel initialization when [certain functions, such as `Throw`/`Catch`, cannot be safely evaluated](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17164/12).  A lot of complex functionality depends on these, and is therefore unsafe to use in init files.  It is generally best to limit initialization files to issuing definitions and basic operations.

---

The initialization is done in this order:

- load paclet manager
- load `$BaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m`
- load `$UserBaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m`
- load files passed with the `-initfile` command line option
- load `Autoload` packages

The loading is triggered in `SystemFiles/Kernel/SystemResources/$SystemID/sysinit.m`, which you can examine for more information on the initialization process. [Some documentation is here.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframSystemSessions.html)

[Subkernels used by the parallel tools](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ParallelComputing.html) are launched with `-noinit`, so they don't load the standard `Kernel/init.m` files. They do load `Autoload` packages.

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit, feel free to revert.

Comment: no, it just added useful information that I was too lazy too lookup or check.  As you did contribute more than me to the answer, I feel pressed to turn this into a public wiki. If you find something else to add, I'll do so :-)

Comment: It's up to you if you want to change it to wiki. I absolutely don't mind if you don't change it.