# SetOptions for every new notebook

Tags: front-end, options

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mathematica “prelude”](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/mathematica-prelude)

I'd like every plot to have a frame and Helvetica labels. I'm satisfied with

```
SetOptions[{Plot, ListPlot, ListLinePlot}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> FontFamily -> "Helvetica"];
```

except I have to type this line at the beginning of every new notebook. How can I have these options set by default every time I create a new notebook?