# StringMatchQ and Alternatives throws message in init.m

Tags: bugs, warning-messages, initialization

**Bug fixed in 11.2.0**

---

The report of [this issue](https://github.com/halirutan/MathematicaAutocompletionTweaker/issues/1), which itself relates to code of my [answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16710/187), exposed a behavior I cannot explain. If I use `StringMatchQ` in combination with `Alternative` inside the `init.m` a message is thrown on start of the kernel.

You can test this by putting this line in your `init.m`

```
StringMatchQ["name", "noMatch" | "name"];
```

and when you start the kernel you see two messages saying

> Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[False] returned to top level.

Surrounding the statement by `Catch` does not help. The solution is to substitute this regex-alternative into a logical `Or`

```
StringMatchQ["name", "noMatch"] || StringMatchQ["name", "name"]
```

but that doesn't explain the issue. What am I missing here?

Comment: Yes, I got the same.  Also, `StringMatchQ["name", "noMatch" | "name"]` returns `False` in a new notebook if it's in init.m.  If I change `"noMatch"` to something like `"foo"` it returns `True`.  When I take it out of init.m and restart Mathematica, it returns `True`.  Seems like a bug somewhere...

Comment: I can't test right now, can only guess. When one uses Mathematica - style patterns in string-related functions, those patterns get compiled to regexes. This procedure is the likely source of exceptions you see. Why this only happens in the `init.m` files I have no idea, can't dig deeper at the moment. It could be for example that it relies on Java and Java is not yet available, or may be something else of a similar nature.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That's odd. I haven't even tested the real return-value, only investigated in the `Throw`. Nice finding.

Comment: Apparently `Catch` doesn't work properly in the `init.m` file.  I get the exhibited error message if I put `Catch[Throw[False]]` in my init file using V7, V8 or V9.  In the example at hand, a `Catch` is used in ``StringPattern`Dump`rule1b`` (called by ``StringPattern`PatternConvert`` called by `StringMatchQ`).

Comment: @WReach It is not the first time that I saw `Catch` failing. It looked like `Catch` is tied to a particular stack, and in some cases it looks like evaluation is using different stacks for parts of it. I may have just given a wrong explanation, but this is what it looked like. I did not have the time to dig deeper and obtain a fully satisfactory answer for these cases.

Comment: This bug persists in version 10

Comment: related: [Uncaught Throw generated by JLink or UseFrontEnd](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7626491) and [Possible Bug of loading Package @ Mathematica 10.1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84539/142).

Comment: @WReach Good find. The whole initialization process is a bit mysterious and when you look at the LinkSnooper communication, there is a lot that happens. Would you mind to join the [chat] for little bit? I have a question about something related and you are one of the few people that can probably point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Cause**

The problem is due to a bug involving `Catch` and `init.m` that occurs in (at least) *Mathematica* versions 7, 8 and 9.  It has been reported to Wolfram Support and they have acknowledged it as a bug.  At time of writing, WRI has offered neither diagnosis nor workaround for this problem.

**Reproduction Steps and Analysis**

To reproduce the issue, place the following expression in the `init.m` file and then restart the session:

```
$result = StringMatchQ["name", "noMatch" | "name"];
```

The message window will show two instances of the message *Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[False] returned to top level*.  Furthermore, `StringMatchQ` no longer functions correctly in the new session:

```
$result
(* False *)

StringMatchQ["name", "noMatch" | "name"]
(* False *)
```

This second result is *extremely* disturbing since it means that all evaluations in the new session that could potentially involve `StringMatchQ` must be treated with suspicion (and who knows what else is suspect as well).  The good news is that occurrence of this problem must be extremely rare because it has gone unnoticed since at least 2008.

Judicious use of `Trace` and similar debugging tools reveals that it is possible to produce the exhibited error messages using a simpler form:

```
Catch[Throw[False]]
```

However, this simpler form does not corrupt the behaviour of `StringMatchQ`.

`Catch` is relevant to the current matter at hand because `StringMatchQ` calls `` StringPattern`PatternConvert ``, which in turn calls `` StringPattern`Dump`rule1b ``.  This last has the following replacement rule (in outline):

```
(List|Alternatives)[a__] :>
  If[Catch[(If[!SingleCharacterQ[#1],Throw[False]]&) /@ {a};True], ...]
```

This rule is applicable to the exhibited troublesome expression because it involves the use of `Alternatives`, and a `Throw` occurs because the strings are longer than single characters:

```
StringMatchQ["name", "noMatch" | "name"];
```

**Workaround**

Experimentation reveals a workaround, for versions 8 and 9 at least.  `Catch` and `StringMatchQ` will operate properly if run as an immediate scheduled task instead of directly inline.  For example, we can place the following lines in the `init.m` file:

```
RunScheduledTask[
  $result = StringMatchQ["name", "noMatch" | "name"]
; RemoveScheduledTask @ $ScheduledTask
, {0}
]
```

The resulting session functions properly:

```
$result
(* True *)

StringMatchQ["name", "noMatch" | "name"]
(* True *)
```

Apparently, the scheduled task environment is isolated from whatever causes this problem.

I cannot stress enough that this is an empirical result with neither proper explanatory backing nor WRI endorsement.

Comment: (1) I am at a loss to explain the subsequent failure of the `StringMatchQ` outside to the initialization phase. I wonder if it might be a caching effect specific to that particular invocation (why it would be cached I do not know)?

Comment: (2)  The issue with init.m is that various "exceptions" (things handled with signalling) are disabled when it is run. `Throw` is such a being. By the time it is seen, after reenabling, the surrounding `Catch` is long gone. There is some experimental work in progress to address this but I do not know (yet) whether it will prove to be successful, let alone when it might be released.