# Possible Bug of loading Package @ Mathematica 10.1

Tags: packages

When I open mathematica, there will pop-up some messages

[image]

where

```
<< package`
```

is in the following file

```
FindFile["init.m"]

(*
    C:\Users\HyperGroups\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Kernel\init.m
*)
```

package content in the package file:

```
BeginPackage["Test1`"]

Test1::usage = "";

Begin["`Private`"];

Nearest[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}, 5]

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

I've tried * Mathematica * 10.1@Windows and 10.0[without this problem]

Seems the problem is related with some special functions, like Nearest

Comment: Problem confirmed in 10.1.0 under Windows 7 x64.

Comment: should this be tagged as a bug?

Comment: Certainly it is one, but a fix would be (very) non-trivial. I tend to view it as more of a limitation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update**

This has been fixed in a general way as of version 11.2.0. For more details, see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110243/handling-kernel-start-what-is-a-full-initialization-stack-and-what-place-the-au?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer.

---

This is a known issue. It is not about package loading (or `Nearest`) but about `Catch`/`Throw` not working correctly when used during kernel initialization. For example, just putting the following in `init.m`

```
Catch[Throw[1]]
```

will result in similar behavior. See also [Arnoud Buzing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/105/arnoud-buzing)'s post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626491/uncaught-throw-generated-by-jlink-or-usefrontend).

The workaround I've been using is to run any init code depending on `Catch`/`Throw` as a scheduled task, e.g.

```
task := Get["package`"];
RunScheduledTask[task, {1}]
```

Comment: I must be missing something... nowhere in the OP's code is there a call to `Catch` or `Throw`.  Should I understand that there are calls to these functions inside `Nearest`?

Comment: @QuantumDot Yes, see e.g. `TracePrint[Nearest[{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32}, 20], _Catch, 
 TraceInternal -> True]`