# Error "Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[False] returned to top level" given each time I open a new Mathematica 10.1 session

Tags: bugs, warning-messages

**Bug fixed in 10.1.0 via paclet update**

---

Since a few days now, each time I open a new Mathematica session I get the small red error popup window with the error messages:

```
Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[False] returned to top level.
```

repeated many times, as you can see from this screenshot:

[image]

Apart from the error window, Mathematica seems to work without problems.
I didn't do anything "strange" with Mathematica recently, no new installation or update or anything of the sort.

What does this error mean, and what are the possible causes and fixes?

Comment: I have the very same `problem' since today! I just tried plying with the cloud since 2-3 days ago... could that be somehow related?

Comment: I actually never did anything related to the cloud.. To my knowledge at least

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eventually, I was able to reproduce this problem. The way to fix it is to delete the `MLCleaner-1.0` directory in `$UserBaseDirectory/Paclets/Repository`, then restart *Mathematica* and run `RebuildPacletData[]`.

The underlying reason is the same as in [84539](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84539), though it was triggered by the use of a different top-level function depending on `Throw/Catch` during kernel startup.

Comment: This did the trick, thank you very much! Only one thing: the folder MLCleaner wasn't rebuilt with that command, is this a problem? What is it for?

Comment: @glance Glad it worked! `MLCleaner` is a small, one time use utility paclet. Its only purpose is to uninstall a broken Machine Learning paclet update that was causing problems for some users. This instance of `Throw` messages will be automatically fixed by a `MLCleaner` update which I understand is undergoing final checks before being uploaded to the paclet servers.

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem and this solution worked for me.

Comment: Likewise - just happened to me on Ubuntu

Comment: I suffer this,but I cannot find `MLCleaner` in that folder.This is [all items](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws726.png) I have.

Comment: @yode I doubt you are having the same problem. The symptoms may look similar but is likely caused by a different piece of code.

Comment: I cannot think up what invalid operation I have made

Comment: @yode it is likely to be more useful for you to open another question for the problem you are experiencing, and see there if it is indeed caused by the same issue as this one

Comment: @glS The bug is disappear now,and it is be more annoying,I mean the kernel of Mathematica become more easy to crash.Sad day..

Comment: @ilian This happened to me and I isolated it to the subfolder `StructuredArrayPatch-1.0` -- can you tell me what that is/was?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I believe this is intended for backward compatibility when the next version introduces a change in the internal structure of e.g. QuantityArrays. Since the new format can appear in downloaded data (which can be shared between several versions of Mathematica) the patch allows older versions to convert it to the format they understand. Which version was this and did you have anything in your init.m file?  As a workaround, I would edit the PacletInfo.m so the patch code does not run on startup, but it could still be loaded manually if needed.

Comment: @ilian Thank you.  I am using version 10.1.0.  The ``Throw`` message still appeared when using `-noinit` so I don't think it's a conflict with my init.m file?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, I see where the problem is. There was a change in how the Paclet Manager processes the comma-separated version list in PacletInfo.m, but that fix only went in version 10.2. Version 10.1 will still give the messages, which are the undesirable result of a StringTrim call during kernel startup (so e.g. someone who used StringTrim in init.m would get similar errors). This should have been tested better before releasing a paclet update that would retroactively affect 10.1. I have let the appropriate people know about this bug.

Comment: @ilian I'm still being bugged by this; could you nudge someone to fix this soon?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was hoping it was already fixed. We had to release a set of individual StructuredArrayPatch paclets for each version. The update should happen automatically in due course, but just in case, please try `PacletSiteUpdate /@ PacletSites[]; PacletUpdate["StructuredArrayPatch"]`

Comment: @ilian Thank you!  That appears to have downloaded the update `StructuredArrayPatch-1.0.2.1` but I had to manually delete the old folder `StructuredArrayPatch-1.0` before the error went away.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly this same problem two days ago. I tried numerous fixes, but I finally had to uninstall Mathematica and all of its library files, and then I did a clear install of Mathematica. This fixed the problem, except it initially seemed to have broken my CUDA.

After the clean install I couldn't get Mathematica to automatically sign me into the Wolfram cloud, but that problem was fixed by executing CloudConnect[] in new Mathematica session.

My broken CUDA was fixed by manually downloading the Mathematica 10 CUDA resources file from the Wolfram server and then executing:

Needs["CUDALink`"]

CUDAResourcesInstall["path-to-download", Update->True]