# What could cause an "Uncaught Throw[$Failed,CURLLink`Utilities`Exception] returned to top level." error message?

Tags: warning-messages, web-access, automation, general-utilities

I am running a program in Mathematica that uses web browser automation, and is also connected to my email account. The program runs fine for a while, but after a few hours, I end up getting the following message:

```
Uncaught Throw[$Failed,CURLLink`Utilities`Exception] returned to top level.
```

The output that I get with the error message is the following:

```
Hold[Throw[$Failed, CURLLink`Utilities`Exception]]
```

I have done some searching on this site and others, but can't seem to find anything very related, except for this post:

[Error "Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[False] returned to top level" given each time I open a new Mathematica 10.1 session](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85013/error-thrownocatch-uncaught-throwfalse-returned-to-top-level-given-each-t)

Do these two cases seem similar enough that I should be able to resolve this issue by following the same steps provided by Ilian in the other post? Thanks!

Comment: What version of mathematica are you running? And, what OS, too?

Comment: @rcollyer - I'm running version 12.0, and it's on Windows 10.

Comment: Next question, what functions are you using in your "web browser automation"? ``CURLLink`Utilities`Exception`` is used every where in CURLLink, so any info is helpful.

Comment: @rcollyer - Sure, I'm using WebExecute a lot, as well as MailServerConnect. There are obviously others, but those are the ones that I think are the most likely to be causing the error.