# Is it possible to define a new built-in function in Mathematica?

Tags: functions, variable-definitions, built-in-symbols

Say I want to define a function to do integration by part, is it possible to define it as a new built-in function in Mathematica, so that I don't need to define it every time I want to use it?

Comment: Is this enough? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6502/5478

Comment: A bit more organized, but also more work is to [make a package](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29324/12), then autload [like this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114957/12) or [like this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8221/12).