# Basic Dynamic Interface Programming that returns variables to nb functions

Tags: programming, dynamic, gui-construction

I have a dynamic module that contains some basic PopupMenu's and Buttons but also need to use the variables returned from these buttons and PopupMenu's in my nb functions outside of this DynamicModule.  Here is the code:

```
DynamicModule[{var = 1, var2 = 3},
 Dynamic[Column[Join[
  {PopupMenu[pass2Fun1 = Dynamic[var], {1 -> "Return 1", 2 -> "Return 2", 
   3 -> "Return 3"}, ContinuousAction -> True]},
  Switch[var, 1,
   {Button["One", Module[{data = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]}, {}], 
   Method -> "Queued"]}, 2,
    {Button["Two", Module[{data2 = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]}, {}], 
     Method -> "Queued"], 
     Button["Three",Module[{data3 = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]}, {}], 
     Method -> "Queued"]}, 3,
    {Button["Four", Module[{data4 = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]}, {}], 
    Method -> "Queued"],
  PopupMenu[pass2Fun2 = Dynamic[var2], {3 -> "choice 1", 4 -> "choice 2", 
    5 -> "choice 3"}, ContinuousAction -> True]}
 ]]], TrackedSymbols :> {var, var2}]]
```

pass2Fun1 and pass2Fun2 are variables that are needed outside the Dynamic Module, and of course so are the SystemDialogInput variables.

Take for example the If statement code where we can test to see if the variable pass2Fun1 ==1   To run this test place the above Dynamic Module code in a cell and check to see that the variable pass2Fun1 is filled as Global`  Then run the If statement code in another cell to see if you get a good printed result.

```
 If[pass2Fun1 == 1,
 Print["This works", pass2Fun1],
 Print["Broken", pass2Fun1]]
```

The If statement can not see the variable pass2Fun1==1 but If I print that variable it prints.  If I check the context and the context path both are Global`.

Now for the fun Part:  In a separate cell evaluate:

```
pass2Fun1=1;
```

Then run the If statement again.  Now the code runs fine.  I thought we had a solution but further checking revealed this strange behavior.   After trying Rojo's code below you will see that this If statement will still not complete. So in both the example code above and Rojo's solution below the result in the If statement test is the same.  Rojo's code in the above function:

```
DynamicModule[{pass2Fun1 = 1, pass2Fun2 = 3}, 
Dynamic[Column[
  Join[{PopupMenu[
     Dynamic[pass2Fun1], {1 -> "Return 1", 2 -> "Return 2", 
      3 -> "Return 3"}, ContinuousAction -> True]}, 
   Switch[pass2Fun1, 
    1, {Button["One", 
      Module[{data = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]}, {}], 
      Method -> "Queued"]}, 
    2, {Button["Two", 
      Module[{data2 = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]}, {}], 
      Method -> "Queued"], 
     Button["Three", 
      Module[{data3 = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]}, {}], 
      Method -> "Queued"]}, 
    3, {Button["Four", 
      Module[{data4 = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]}, {}], 
      Method -> "Queued"], 
     PopupMenu[
      Dynamic[pass2Fun2], {3 -> "choice 1", 4 -> "choice 2", 
       5 -> "choice 3"}, ContinuousAction -> True]}]]], 
  TrackedSymbols :> {pass2Fun1, pass2Fun2}]]
```

My question:
What is the best method to get the variable data from another nb a Button or PopupMenu to the functions in a different nb? These nb functions control the generation of results based on the input data and the variables pass2Fun1 & 2 and the SystemDialogInputs.  Should all the functions be called inside the DynamicModule or made Global?  Even if it's made Global as in the case above, how do I make sure the variable is filled in such a way as to be useful to other functions?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: It would help to better understand your question to provide a use case example and the behaviour you'd like. For example, what do you mean by "to get the variable data to the functions in a notebook"?

Comment: Thanks, still have some doubts that I think are relevant. So all you want to do with those variables is have some other interface element display some result of processing them? No need to have them available to write new code and evaluate cells playing with the data? Is the interface element that shows the rsult part of the same cell or from another one? If it's from another one, is it already part of the notebook or generated when you click a button or something (as a dialog would for example?)

Comment: If what you want is to simply have them available in a variable, to play around, do further calculations, etc, it makes the most sense to me to store them in a kernel variable. It can be global or it can belong to a context

Comment: You still don't provide code to test. I'd honestly suggest you edited your question, and at least append at the end whatever code you think should be run (the one you refer to from my answer) so that anyone with a fresh kernel can be sure what to copy and paste to see what you mean

Comment: The code in my answer not only uses a `pass2Fun2` and uses numbers 3,4 and 5 for the choices, so you could never expect it to assign `pass2Fun1` the number 1

Comment: @Rojo Since I'm not being allowed to change the variables to fit my example. Please try it yourself.  Here is the code:

Comment: Thanks. You just have to remove `pass2Fun1` and `pass2Fun2` from your `DynamicModule` variable list if you want them to be global. Do `pass2Fun1=1;pass2Fun2=3; Dynamic[Column...`. Given that you have no local variables you don't even need the `DynamicModule`

Comment: @Rojo That works and is extendable!  Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your `PopupMenu` wrong

This is the proper way to write it if you want `pass2Fun2` to be kept updated with the `PopupMenu` selection

```
PopupMenu[
Dynamic[pass2Fun2], {3 -> "choice 1", 4 -> "choice 2",
5 -> "choice 3"}, ContinuousAction -> True]
```

This goes for both popups

You had

`PopupMenu[pass2Fun2 = Dynamic[var2], ...`

After doing those changes you need to remove `pass2Fun1` and `pass2Fun2` from the local variable list of your `DynamicModule` if you want to be able to access them from other cells

Comment: `PopupMenu[pass2Fun1 = Dynamic[var1], ...` might be considered unconventional but the global value still updates using the OPs code --  in my notebook anyway. So while this is more elegant, and the way you would normally write this sort of code,  what does it actually fix (a question for @RHall)

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, `PopupMenu[pass2Fun1 = Dynamic[var1]...` doesn't keep the global up to date. But the global, in `StandardForm` displays as the dynamic value of `var1` which is local to a different cell. So as long as the cell doesn't "resynch" with the kernel, it maay work visually, but I think that's playing with fire

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch the OP, for example, couldn't use the global as a parameter to another function (because it was actually a Dynamic[var] and not a value), so he got confused. Then he tested assigning `pass2Fun1=1` manually, but now could never get the `PopupMenu` to ""update"" `pass2Fun1` any more dynamically

Comment: @RHall, the Popup was changing the local "var", but doing nothing to `pass2Fun1`. But `pass2Fun1` was linked visually to the "var" so it appeared to more or less work fine

Comment: @Rojo I see. yes very confusing.

Comment: Note that you can do this `pass2Fun1 /. Dynamic -> Identity` outside of the DM to get the value.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch yes, it does. I'm intrigued if that technique can be useful in some cases. Note however that it is not general. If the dynamic that updates the variable doesn't need to call the kernel you won't get it updated

Comment: @Rojo I have used it now and then -- for example if you want to dynamically modify something and then save the "settings" for later regular use programmatically (e.g. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7547/how-to-position-legends-exactly-where-i-want-them/7548#7548). I was just throwing it out there. This entire question confused me about what the OP was seeking and it seems it was really just about how to make an argument to `Popup` dynamic.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch found something that shows this problem very clearly if you have time to look at it.  Thanks!

Comment: @RHall Rojo and Mike, clean up these comments a bit, will you please?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard to be frank I think this question needs to be removed and R Hall needs to start again.

Comment: @RHall I think it is time to scrap this question and take a step back. The construction of your example has several problems. If you want the data variables to be available globally why have you made them `Module` variables etc. If you simply want to know how to use a variable within a dynamic module in other parts of you notebook then present an example with one control and one variable and let someone show you that. Normally I would suggest reading `InheritScope` and `TaggingRules` but I think you need to read the various `DynamicModule` and `Dynamic` tutorials first. I am voting to close.

Comment: @RHall I rejected your edit because the context was not sufficient for me to understand why you need to change the variables in Rojo's answer, given that you use those variables in the question too. Consider leaving a comment here for Rojo with your intended change

Comment: @R.M.  Rojo requested the change because the variable name he used was different than the test. So I made the change for that reason.  That is in his comments above.

Answer (score 3):

This answer maybe redundant, if not it may clarify what is required or not.

This is a minimal function that creates a dialog holding a popup which is linked to a `Dynamic` kernel variable without the use of `Module` or `DynamicModule`.

```
ff[] := (pup = 
   PopupMenu[
    Dynamic[pass2Fun1], {1 -> "choice 1", 2 -> "choice 2", 
     3 -> "choice 3"}, ContinuousAction -> True]; 
  CreateDialog[{pup}];)

ff[];
```

As far as I can tell the two remain in sync if the kernel variable is set or the menu item selected.

Does this meet the criteria for the OP?

Comment: Yes it does,  Thanks very much!