# Drag and Drop an Attached Cell

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells

I'm trying to create an attached cell that can be mouse dragged.  I'm envisioning mouse-dragging the blue header bar to bring the entire header and the graphic to a new location at which point both will be locked to that location.  The graphic needs to be rotatable by mouse-drag.

This is what I have so far:

```
AttachCell[EvaluationNotebook[], DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}},
   
   EventHandler[Graphics[Inset[Style[Grid[{
         
         {Button["Close", NotebookDelete[EvaluationCell[]], 
           ImageSize -> All, Appearance -> Button]}, {Plot3D[
           Sin[x y], {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 3}, ImageSize -> 300]}},
        
        Frame -> True,
        Background -> {None, {LightBlue, White}}], 
       Deployed -> False],
      Dynamic[pt]],
     
     PlotRange -> 10, ImageSize -> Scaled[1], Frame -> False],
    
    {"MouseDragged" :> (pt = MousePosition["Graphics"])}, 
    PassEventsDown -> True, PassEventsUp -> True]], Center, 0, 
  Center];
```

Notice in the video below I can drag the graphic anywhere using the header.  However, a mouse-drag inside the graphic is both rotating the graphic and dragging the graphic causing the strange behavior.   I want the grid draggable but only from the blue header as I still want to rotate the graphic. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: On a semi-related note, Mike Honeycrunch created this kind of functionality inside a manipulate using locators (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162574/33996) although I don't think locators would be applicable in my question here.

Comment: With this approach you can't select within the parent notebook, are you fine with that?

Comment: @Kuba Yes.  No need to select anything in the parent notebook while the attached cell is active.  Having the ability scroll the parent notebook is all I need as shown in the animation above.

Comment: Just curious… this is part of a lesson I am working my students.  I’m hoping to find a solution.  I would be willing to pay someone but probably not appropriate on this site I’m guessing.  Can anyone direct me to where I can get something like this built?  I hope this question is not inappropriate.

Comment: @Bflat Why not create a new window of notebook?

Comment: Since an attached cell and a new window quite different.  The former exists in a single notebook and is locked within the notebook. Those are features I need to my application. .

Comment: @Bflat How about a new cell which you can jump in and out?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however the point of my question is to create a locked attached cell.  A new window or a new cell are not the same thing.  In the latter case, I would not be able to see a locked popup and also scroll through information in the background for referencing which is my primary reasons for asking this question.

Answer (score 3):

### Update

My code works well if linksnooper is used (see the video).

[image]

This may be related to the change of performance, event frequency, dynamic update strategy or caches.

I'm still looking for a way to configure that.

---

### Discussion

Quite strange, this sometimes works and sometimes doesn't work:

```
cell = With[{plot = ToBoxes@Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 3}, ImageSize -> 300]},
    Cell[BoxData@DynamicModuleBox[{pt = {0, 0}},
        GraphicsBox[InsetBox[
            PanelBox@StyleBox[
                GridBox[{
                    {TagBox[
                        ButtonBox["Drag to move and click to close", ButtonFunction :> NotebookDelete[EvaluationCell[]]]
                    , EventHandlerTag@{"MouseDragged" :> (pt = MousePosition["Graphics"]), PassEventsDown -> True, PassEventsUp -> True, Method -> "Preemptive"}]},
                    {DynamicBox[ToBoxes[pt,StandardForm]]},
                    {plot}
                }]
            , Deployed -> False]
        , Dynamic@pt, Top]
        , PlotRange -> 10, ImageSize -> Scaled@1, Frame -> False, Method->"Preemptive"]
    ]
    , "Text"
    , Editable -> False]
];
AttachCell[EvaluationNotebook[], cell, Center, 0, Center]
```

Once it works, you can try to drag the 3D graphics and meanwhile move the mouse to the button for severaltimes, then it may break down again.

[image: attachcell]

And if you try `cell //CellPrint` instead, that works stably.
[image: cellprint]

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me.  It may be related to the error I get that DynamicModuleBoxOptions is not an option for DynamicModuleBox. (i.e. "DynamicModuleBoxOptions -> {Method -> "Preemptive"}" is highlighted in red.

Comment: @Bflat Oh, that was a mistake, I pasted the wrong version of code.

Comment: hmmmm.  It still doesn't seem to work.  The attached cell appears but does not let me move it at all and the figure doesn't rotate.  All I can do is click to close.  I'm running Mathematica 13.0 on a MacOS 12.0.1

Comment: @Bflat I updated two videos. It's true that my code is buggy, however I want to show: the code that works well as a normal cell may fail when it becomes an attached cell.

Comment: I ran it on 12.3 and then on 13.0. it partially worked on 12.3 with cellprint but no rotation.  With cell print I get the rotation but no drag.   On 13.0 it seems to work less.  : /. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Thank you so much for working on this.  I'm going to award the points for your work so far.  If you figure it out great, but you've at least led me in the right direction regardless.

Comment: @Bflat This is related to internal details of the front-end. I'm afraid that we may need a WRI staff to answer this.

Answer (score 3):

This works. Instead of attaching the graphic using dynamic Graphics Inset, I attached it directly to the notebook using the Attached Cell. To move the attached cell around the notebook I used event handlers that refresh on mousedrags while deleting their traces.  That was tricky.  .  I think this is cleaner... but a bit harder to do.  Here is a video and code below.  If anyone wants to clean up my code... please do.  I'm not much of a programmer and would like to see how I can be more efficient.

[image]

```
mo = EventHandler[
   DynamicModule[{x = 0}, Button["Close"], 
    Initialization :> (k = 
       AttachCell[EvaluationBox[], 
        DynamicModule[{}, 
         Style[
          Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 3}, ImageSize -> 300, 
           SphericalRegion -> True, ImagePadding -> 10, 
           Background -> LightYellow, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
          Deployed -> False], InheritScope -> True], Bottom, 0, Top])],
   {"MouseClicked" :> (NotebookDelete[ParentCell[k]])}];

g[Dynamic[k_]] := 
  SetOptions[k, CellEventActions -> {"MouseDragged" :> (None),
     "MouseUp" :> (SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], Next, Cell];
       SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], Before, CellContents]), 
     PassEventsDown -> True
     }];

f[Dynamic[attachedCell_, init_]] := 
  SetOptions[ParentCell[k], CellEventActions -> {
     "MouseDragged" :> (
       NotebookDelete[init];
       NotebookDelete[attachedCell];
       attachedCell = 
        AttachCell[InputNotebook[], mo, {Left, Top}, 
         Offset[MousePosition["WindowAbsolute"]*{1, -1}, 0]];
       g[Dynamic[k]];
       f[Dynamic[attachedCell, init]];
       
       ), PassEventsDown -> True}];

DynamicModule[{init, attachedCell, p},
 
 Button["Start",
  SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], Before, CellContents];
  init = AttachCell[InputNotebook[], mo, Center, 0, Center];
  SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
   CellEventActions -> {"MouseDragged" :> (None)}];
  
  SetOptions[k, CellEventActions -> {"MouseDragged" :> (None),
     "MouseUp" :> (SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], Next, Cell];
       SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], Before, CellContents]), 
     PassEventsDown -> True
     }];
  SetOptions[ParentCell[k], CellEventActions -> {
     "MouseDragged" :> (
       NotebookDelete[init];
       NotebookDelete[attachedCell];
       attachedCell = 
        AttachCell[InputNotebook[], mo, {Left, Top}, 
         Offset[MousePosition["WindowAbsolute"]*{1, -1}, 0]];
       
       g[Dynamic[k]];
       f[Dynamic[attachedCell, init]];
       
       
       ), PassEventsDown -> True}]
  ]]
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to continuously delete and recreate a cell upon drag?  Is it because there is no way to dynamically adjust the coordinates of the attached cell once it's created?

Comment: Well, I did find this for CellPrint:  `Slider2D[Dynamic[xy], {0, 100}]
CellPrint[Cell["x", CellMargins -> Dynamic[{xy, xy}]]]`.  Any way this could work for attached cell?

Comment: Have you explored trying to create a new (small sized) notebook window with no frame? If you did, perhaps you could give me a hint as to why it wouldn't work, so I don't go down a path that ends in a dead-end.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I forgot the issue...As you can see in the code in my original question above, I can move the attached cell if I move the object it's attached to.  It works as you suggest.  However, it forced the 3D graphic itself to rotate when I moved the entire graphic.  I couldn't get around this.  Try it.  My solution was how I got around the issue.  I am hoping there is a faster method based on my original code without repeatedly deleting the traces... but I couldn't make it work with the 3D graphic.  If you find a way... I'd really like to see.

Comment: I tried attaching a small size notebook, but the attached cell can't do that.  Also, there is the other issue with the window appearing on top of the primary window.  That option broke in Mathematica for windows and notebooks a while back.