# Awkward output of TeXForm

Tags: output-formatting, latex

When I try to format a number that has a big exponent with TeXForm the following happens:

```
In[1]:= TeXForm[1.543*10^-10 ]

Out[1]//TeXForm=
    \text{1.543$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-10}
```

But I would like to get something like `1.543 \cdot 10^{-10}`. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 5):

You could use `ScientificForm[]` for starters:

```
TeXForm[ScientificForm[1.543*10^-10]]
   1.543\times 10^{-10}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is another approach that addresses some issues you may (or may not) encounter: With the built-in formats like `ScientificForm`, there is an aesthetic problem:

```
TeXForm[ScientificForm[1.*10^-10]]
```

> `1.\times 10^{-10}`

Notice that trailing decimal points are printed after machine-precision numbers even when there's no digits to the right.

Also, you wanted a centered dot to represent the multiplication. Both of these issues can be addressed with the following wrapper function:

```
tF[x_?MachineNumberQ] := 
 TeXForm@NumberForm[x, 
   NumberFormat -> (DisplayForm@
       RowBox[Join[{StringTrim[#1, RegularExpression["\\.$"]]}, 
         If[#3 =!= "", {"\[CenterDot]", 
           SuperscriptBox[#2, #3]}, {}]]] &)]
```

An example is:

```
tF[1.34 10^-10]
```

> `1.34\cdot 10^{-10}`

A slightly different way to implement this would be to declare this as a `Format` that only kicks in during `TeXForm` output:

```
Format[tN[x_?MachineNumberQ], TeXForm] := 
 NumberForm[x, 
  NumberFormat -> (DisplayForm@
      RowBox[Join[{StringTrim[#1, RegularExpression["\\.$"]]}, 
        If[#3 =!= "", {"\[CenterDot]", 
          SuperscriptBox[#2, #3]}, {}]]] &)]

Format[tN[x_]] := x
```

With this, you could wrap any expression you want with the `tN` function, and it will display as if `tN` weren't there. But if you apply `TeXForm`, the output is changed:

```
tN[1. 10^-10]
```

> $1. \times 10^{-10}$

```
TeXForm[%]
```

> `1\cdot 10^{-10}`

The centered dot and the removed decimal point can be seen only in the last line where `TeXForm` was applied.

It depends on the application whether you would want to use a wrapper with a `Format` like `tN`, or a simple conversion function like `tF`.

The formatting in these wrapper functions relies on `NumberForm`, and I basically borrowed the function `trimPoint` from my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6380/245).

Comment: One might also consider using `MantissaExponent[]` for such manipulations...

Comment: That's the same thing that `NumberFormat` does. Here the main point is that you want the flexibility provided by `NumberForm` to introduce, e.g., the `\cdot` multiplication symbol.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @Jens should be good enough, but unfortunately defining [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) formats using [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) works only at the top level. For instance:

```
tN[1.543*^-10] //TeXForm
```

> $1.543\cdot 10^{-10}$

works well, while:

```
{tN[1.543*^-10]} //TeXForm
```

> $\{\text{1.543$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-10}\}$

does not. One can instead define [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rules:

```
Clear[tN];
tN /: MakeBoxes[tN[x_Real], TraditionalForm] := MakeBoxes[
    NumberForm[
        x,
        NumberMultiplier -> "\[CenterDot]"
    ],
    TraditionalForm
]
```

Then:

```
tN[1.543*^-10] //TeXForm
```

> $1.543\cdot 10^{-10}$

and

```
{tN[1.543*^-10]} //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{1.543\cdot 10^{-10}\right\}$

both work as expected.