# Copy ScientificForm as Latex?

Tags: latex

I have a matrix

```
M = {{-2.78787*10^-6, 0, 0}, {0, 0.00074904, 0}, {0, 0, -0.119373}};
```

which I'm converting into `ScientificForm`, with 3 digits precision

```
ScientificForm[M, 3]
(* {{-2.79*10^(-6),0,0}, {0,7.49*10^(-4),0}, {0,0,-1.19*10^(-1)}} *)
```

I would like to copy this exact form as a $\LaTeX$ code. Unfortunately, copying as $\LaTeX$ yields

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -\text{2.7878728277032345$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-6} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0.00074904 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -0.119373 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

instead of the nice `ScientificForm`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use TeXForm instead of "Copy as LaTeX"

```
TeXForm[ScientificForm[M, 3]]
(* \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -2.79\times 10^{-6} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 7.49\times 10^{-4} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1.19\times 10^{-1} \\
\end{array}
\right) *)
```

which, when rendered in LaTeX, gives

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -2.79\times 10^{-6} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 7.49\times 10^{-4} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1.19\times 10^{-1} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

One problem you may have is if you had your zeros defined numerically, in which case  you get ugly trailing decimal places,

```
M = {{-2.78787*10^-6, 0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.00074904, 0.0}, {0.0, 
     0.0, -0.119373}};
TeXForm[ScientificForm[M, 3]]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -2.79\times 10^{-6} & 0. & 0. \\
 0. & 7.49\times 10^{-4} & 0. \\
 0. & 0. & -1.19\times 10^{-1} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

A simple application of `Chop` works in that case:  `TeXForm[ScientificForm[Chop@M, 3]]`.  If you have numbers like `1.0` that you would prefer to be `1` then you need to follow Jens's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14593/9490) here.