# Improving ContourPlot and Table output

Tags: legending, list-manipulation

I am trying to examine the results of and NDSolve solution for a BVP, and the output is not at all "pretty".  Here's the code:

```
*d = .0005;        (* diffusion coefficient (L^2/t *)
v = .0010;         (* velocity (L/s) *)
r = 3.;            (* depth of lower boundary condition *)
xmax = r/1.;       (* maximum plotted value of x *)
NDSolve[
  {
     D[c[t, x], t] == d*D[c[t, x], x, x] - v*D[c[t, x], x],
     c[0, x] == UnitStep[x - .002] - UnitStep[x - .15],
     Derivative[0, 1][c][t, 0] == c[t, 0]*v/d,  
     c[t, r] == 0
  },
  c,
  {t, 0, 50},
  {x, 0, r}];
q = Evaluate[c[t, x] /. % ];
Table[{x, q}, {t, 50, 50}, {x, 0, r/2, .05}]
ContourPlot[q, {t, 0, 50}, {x, 0, xmax/5},
  ColorFunction -> Hue,
  Contours -> 20,
  AspectRatio -> .75, 
  PlotPoints -> 25,
  Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> {"time", "distance"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Concentration"]
Plot3D[q, {t, 0, 50}, {x, 0, xmax}, PlotRange -> All]
```

There are two things I'd like to be able to change in the output:

1. The output by the `Table` command is one long line that wraps until it's done. I'd like to see two columns, one for `x` and one for `q`.  The value of `q` should be `t = 50`, and `x` should be the sequence `{x, 0, r/2, .05}`.
2. I have been unsuccessful getting the `ContourPlot` to print out a legend showing which colour represents what values of the dependent variable `q[t,x]`.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`Flatten` the list of solutions:

```
q = c[t, x] /. 
   Quiet@Flatten@
     NDSolve[{D[c[t, x], t] == d*D[c[t, x], x, x] - v*D[c[t, x], x], 
       c[0, x] == UnitStep[x - .002] - UnitStep[x - .15], 
       Derivative[0, 1][c][t, 0] == c[t, 0]*v/d, c[t, r] == 0}, 
      c, {t, 0, 50}, {x, 0, r}];
```

Set `t=50` (locally) and use `TableForm`. You can add the option `TableHeadings`:

```
TableForm[
   Block[{t = 50}, Table[{x, q}, {x, 0, r/2, .05}]],
   TableHeadings->{None,{"x","q"}}]

(* x      q
   -------------------
   0.     0.35899
   0.05   0.385767
   0.1    0.392973
   0.15   0.38057
   ... *)
```

Of course you can also use `Grid` and/or add more options and `Style` to further improve the appearance of the table.

For the legend you might want to look into [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6236/showlegend-values/6380#6380).

I just used `DensityPlot` with the minimum and maximum values of `q` to build a simple legend:

```
legend = DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, -0.045, 1},
   AspectRatio -> 10,
   ColorFunction -> Hue,
   FrameTicks -> {False, True},
   PlotLabel -> "q(x,t)", 
   ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {40, 10}}, 
   ImageSize -> {60, 225}]
```

Use the same `ImagePadding` in the plot to have the frames align:

```
plot = ContourPlot[q, {t, 0, 50}, {x, 0, xmax/5}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, Contours -> 20,
  AspectRatio -> 0.75, 
  PlotPoints -> 25,
  FrameLabel -> {"time", "distance"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Concentration", 
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {40, 10}}, 
  ImageSize -> {300, 225}]
```

Finally, display the result with `Row`:

```
Row[{plot, legend}]
```

[image]

Comment: einbandi - thanks for a great reply.  I tried your suggestions and they work great.  thanks again! - eric

Comment: You're welcome! You may have noticed that your question was downvoted. Here are some tips to get better votes plus more/better answers to your future questions: 1) Read the [FAQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Mathematica.html) section. 2) Use the [Mathematica Documentation Center](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Mathematica.html) and this site's search function thoroughly *before* posting your question (you might want to check [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18606#18606) out).

Comment: 3) Try to post *minimal* working examples. The more code people have to go through, the more time they have to spend with your question and the less likely it is to get good answers. 4) Try to show as much effort of your own as possible. 5) Note that you can mark an answer that satisifes your need as your *accepted* one by clicking the green tick mark below the vote number.