# Table in a Legend

Tags: legending

Calculated data:

```
data= {{3.54216*10^6, 5.43391*10^6}, {3.5422*10^6, 
      5.43392*10^6}, {3.54224*10^6, 5.43393*10^6}, {3.54215*10^6, 
      5.43395*10^6}, {3.54219*10^6, 5.43396*10^6}, {3.54223*10^6, 
      5.43397*10^6}, {3.54214*10^6, 5.43399*10^6}, {3.54218*10^6, 
      5.434*10^6}, {3.54222*10^6, 5.43401*10^6}, {3.54213*10^6, 
      5.43403*10^6}, {3.54217*10^6, 5.43404*10^6}, {3.54221*10^6, 
      5.43405*10^6}, {3.54212*10^6, 5.43407*10^6}, {3.54216*10^6, 
      5.43408*10^6}, {3.5422*10^6, 5.43409*10^6}};
```

How can I present these data as an Table {i,x[i],y[i]} next to a graphic as a legend? I tried this finally with:

```
e = data &;
legends = AccountingForm /@ e[x];

legend = Overlay[{legendMaker[legends]}, Alignment -> {-.5, -.8}, 
  ImageSize -> 400]
```

using the function [legendMaker](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/creating-legends-for-plots-with-multiple-lines) but I am not happy with my result. The best way would be to have it as an excel-like table. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Do you means something like this?

```
data = Map[AccountingForm, data, {-1}];

Grid[Transpose[Prepend[Transpose[data], Graphics[{ColorData["Rainbow"][#], Disk[]}, 
 ImageSize -> 10] & /@ Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[data] - 1)]]], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Vitally Kaurov, this was what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

My interpretation of *"next to a graphic"* is slightly different than Vitaliy's:

```
Framed@Row[
     {ListLinePlot[data/10^6, ImageSize -> 350, PlotLabel -> "My Plot"], 
      Grid[Transpose[{Range@Length@data, Map[AccountingForm, data, {2}]}] /. 
                                                                      {x_, {y__}} -> {x, y}, 
       Frame -> All]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

Using Jens's [`extractStyles`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/125) function with further styling:

```
lstplt = ListPlot[List /@ data, PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledCircle], 24}, 
         Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 600];
legendmarkers = extractStyles[lstplt][[2]];
legendlabels =  Map[Style[AccountingForm[#], FontFamily -> "Calibri"] &, data, {-1}];
styledheaders = Style[#, Bold, FontFamily -> "Calibri"] & /@ {"", "X", "Y"};
legendGrd =  Grid[Prepend[ Transpose[Join[{legendmarkers}, Transpose[legendlabels]]],
   styledheaders], Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[.9],
   Alignment ->{Center, Center}, Background ->{None, {GrayLevel[.5],{GrayLevel[.8]}}}];
Panel@Row[{Show[lstplt, ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 600]], legendGrd}, 
      Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

For `xCharts` with the `ChartLegends` option, one can use a series of `ReplaceAll`s to change the content and styling of the legend:

```
bcdata={RandomChoice[CharacterRange["A", "Z"]], #[[1]], #[[2]], RandomReal[]} & /@ data;
bc = BubbleChart[bcdata[[All, 2 ;;]],
   ChartStyle -> "SolarColors",
   ChartElementFunction -> "NoiseBubble",
   ChartLegends -> 
     Row /@ Map[Style[AccountingForm[#], FontFamily -> "Calibri"] &, bcdata, {-1}],
  Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400];
headers = {"", "OBS", "X", "Y", "Z"};
styledheaders = Style[#, Bold, FontFamily -> "Calibri"] & /@ headers;

Panel[bc /.
 {Row[x___] :> Sequence[x], Rectangle[__] :> Disk[]} /.
  Grid[{{x_, {y__}}}, z___] :> {x, y} /.
  Column[x___] :> Grid[Prepend[x, styledheaders],
      Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[.9],
      Alignment -> {Center, Center},
      Background -> {None, {GrayLevel[.5], {GrayLevel[.8]}}}] /. 
 Framed[x__, y___] :> x]
```

[image]

Finally, one can extract the marker shape ("NoiseBubble" in the example above) using

```
  noiseBble = Cases[bc, PolygonBox[x___] :> Polygon[x], Infinity][[1]];
```

use it in the legend by replacing

```
  Rectangle[__]:>Disk[]
```

with

```
 Rectangle[__]:> Polygon[{noiseBble[[1, 1, 1 ;; -1 ;; 3]]}].
```