# Calculate proportion of values for dates

Tags: list-manipulation, curated-data

At work, we were discussing when is it the best time to change to winter tires for bikes and/or cars.

Using `WeatherData[]` and `DateListPlot[]`, it was fairly straightforward for me to create the diagram below:

[image: Mean temperature per day in Stockholm]

*Fig 1 Mean temperature per day in Stockholm, red is negative and a risk without winter tires.*

The code for this is

```
cityTemp = WeatherData["Stockholm", "MeanTemperature", {{1977, 1, 1}, {2011, 12, 31}, "Day"}];
iceRiskDays = Select[cityTemp, Last[#] < 0 &];

yearStrip[ dataItem_] := {{0, Part[First[dataItem], 2], Last[First[dataItem]]}, Last[dataItem]}

DateListPlot[{yearStrip[#] & /@ cityTemp, yearStrip[#] & /@ iceRiskDays} ]
```

My question is: **How do I calculate for each day the proportion of values for that day that are below 0 Celsius?** (e.g. for a date at the end of November, the proportion is likely to be bigger than 0.5)?

My attempts to do this ended with trying to create separate lists for each date, but I felt that this was a less elegant way and also creates less "fit" with DateListPlot.

Comment: You know about `Count[]`?

Comment: Yes, but where I get stuck is how to "map" Count to the list and to "count" the number of values for a date and also count the number of values that - in this case - are negative.

Comment: Something like `Count[cityTemp, {d_List, t_?Negative}]`? BTW, you might also be interested in the functions `Split[]`/`SplitBy[]`.

Comment: Split/SplitBy looks promising, didn't know about it.. If I follow your guidance, the solution should be to use Split and Count to get the number of values per date and then use SplitBy and Count to get the number of negative values per date.

Comment: I'm getting confused... by "date", did you mean "month"? There is only one (mean) temperature assigned to each date; for each month, the number of temperature values corresponds to the number of days (of course).

Comment: No, not month, day. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Okay, to summarize: you want a count (and from there the proportion) of the number of "cold" days for each month, for all those years?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6120/discussion-between-fredrikd-and-j-m)

Comment: +1, But your question contains a wrong assumption: As soon as the temperature drops below `+7 C` the rubber of summer tires is too hard and winter tires are recommended ;-)

Comment: Another misleading assumption is that the only days with risk of ice are those with *mean* temperatures below $0$. A better indicator would be days with a *low* near $0$. (Ice can be common even with lows slightly above $0$, but a low below $0$ is a pretty clear indicator that moisture will freeze. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nice question. First I wrote your code in this way. Where we don't need the function `yearStrip`

```
{date,year,month,day,temp}={1,1,2,3,2}
cityTemp=WeatherData["Stockholm","MeanTemperature",{{1977,1,1},{2011,12,31},"Day"}];
cityTemp[[All,date,year]]=0
iceRiskDays=Select[cityTemp,#[[temp]]<0&];
DateListPlot[{cityTemp,iceRiskDays}]
```

Where we get the same result:

[image]

Now we can group the day-month information using `GatherBy` in this way:

```
dataGather=GatherBy[cityTemp,#[[date,{month,day}]]&];
getNegativeProportion[data_]:=N@Total[UnitStep[-data]]/Length[data]
negativeProportionList=Sort[{#[[1,1]],getNegativeProportion[#[[All,temp]]]}&/@dataGather];
movAvg=MovingAverage[{N@AbsoluteTime@#[[date]],#[[temp]]}&/@negativeProportionList,14];
DateListPlot[{negativeProportionList,movAvg},Joined-> True,PlotStyle-> {Blue,Red}]
```

Where we get:

[image]

With the red line as the moving average for 14 days!

Comment: I am new to MMA, so I have to ask for a pointer to the documentation of first assignment {date, ...} = {1,1..}

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica. This is just a form of make the rest of the code simpler to read when using Parts. It's equivalent to do date=1; year=1 and so on.

Answer (score 6):

Following @J.M. if you are after the likelihood of icy days as a function of month

```
ff[x_] := Select[cityTemp, #[[1, 2]] == x &] // (Count[#, {d_List, t_?Negative}]/Length[#]) &

{Range[12] - 1/2, ff /@ Range[12]} // Transpose // 
ListLinePlot[#, InterpolationOrder -> 0,AxesLabel -> {"Month", "likelihood"}] &
```

which suggests in January its about  15%  (from where I live) and 60 % in Stockholm (Brrr...)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comparing Paris to Stockholm (using the nice package [autoLegend](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/1089))

```
ff[x_, temp_] := Select[temp, #[[1, 2]] == x &] // (Count[#, {d_List, t_?Negative}]/
 Length[#]) &

{{Range[12] - 1/2, ff[#, cityTempS] & /@ Range[12]} // Transpose,
{Range[12] - 1/2, ff[#, cityTempP] & /@ Range[12]} // Transpose} // 
ListLinePlot[#, InterpolationOrder -> 0,
AxesLabel -> {"Month", "likelihood"}] &//autoLegend[#, {"Stockholm","Paris"}] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Stealing yet again another suggestion of @J.M. we can look at global warming ;-)
This time we look at the faction of days with ice as a function of year:

```
 dat = Map[Count[#, {d_List, t_?Negative}]/Length[#] &, 
  SplitBy[cityTempP, {#[[1, 1]] &, #[[1, 2]] &}], {2}] // Rest;
 fP = LinearModelFit[Mean /@ dat, {1, x}, x];

 dat = Map[Count[#, {d_List, t_?Negative}]/Length[#] &, 
 SplitBy[cityTempS, {#[[1, 1]] &, #[[1, 2]] &}], {2}] // Rest;
 fS = LinearModelFit[Mean /@ dat, {1, x}, x];

 Show[Plot[{fS[x], fP[x]}, {x, 1, 31}, AxesLabel -> {"year", "Likelihood"}],
 ListPlot[{fS["Data"], fP["Data"]}]]// autoLegend[#, {"Stockholm", "Paris"}] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And finally for the sake of contributing something original (the code for [FilledErrorPlot](http://pastebin.com/08KWB9aT)), let us launch the climate-skeptic versus climato-believer debate while illustrating the famous [Lies, damned lies, and statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lies,_damned_lies,_and_statistics) methodology on two different ways of plotting the same data; guess which is which ;-)

```
Show[dat // Transpose // FilledErrorPlot[#] &,
Plot[{fS[x]}, {x, 1, 33}, 
PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], ColorData[10][1]], 
AxesLabel -> {"year", "Likelihood"}], AspectRatio -> 1.5, 
PlotRange -> {0.035, 0.45}, AxesOrigin -> {0., 0.035}, 
AxesLabel -> {"year", "Fraction of \n icy days"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

versus

```
Show[dat // Transpose // FilledErrorPlot[#, ErrorOnMean -> False] &,
Plot[{fS[x]}, {x, 1, 33}, 
PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], ColorData[10][1]], 
AxesLabel -> {"year", "Likelihood"}], AspectRatio -> 0.5, PlotRange -> {-0.5, 1}, 
AxesLabel -> {"year", "Fraction of \n icy days"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: To compute the proportions for all the months of those years: `Map[Count[#, {d_List, t_?Negative}]/Length[#] &, SplitBy[cityTemp, {#[[1, 1]] &, #[[1, 2]] &}], {2}]`

Comment: Yes, it is a likelyhood function that I am after but for a days (there is about 12000 / 400 = 30 values per days which is ok for me). If I understand your counting to months is done in the {Range[12]... code, will experiment with this. (Stockholm is considered to be in the warm, comfortable, south part of Sweden..)

Comment: will try autoLegend. Check the order of "Paris" and "Stockholm" in the AxesLabel part, I think you put in the wrong order.

Comment: @FredrikD oops... well spotted.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a slightly different approach using `GatherBy`.

Reformat dates to be just {month, day}:

```
shortDates = {DateString[First@#, { "Month","Day",}], Last@#} & /@  cityTemp;
```

Group the values by day and month, count the days on which the temperature is not positive:

```
probs = Count[#[[All, 2]], t_?NonPositive]/Length@# & /@    
        GatherBy[Sort@shortDates, #[[1]] &];
```

Plot the likelihoods:

```
   ListLinePlot[probs, AxesLabel -> { "Day Number","Likelihood"}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

You can calculate different likelihoods by adjusting the short date conversion string, for a month value just switch the date reformatting to months:

```
shortDates = {DateString[First@#, {"Month"}], Last@#} & /@ cityTemp;
```

Answer (score 4):

If my understanding of the question is correct, this does the job:

```
cityTemp = WeatherData["Stockholm", "MeanTemperature",
                       {{1977, 7, 1}, {2011, 12, 31}, "Day"}];

(* proportions; I ignore February 29 for this *)
props = Array[(Count[#, {_List, _?Negative}]/Length[#]) &[Cases[cityTemp,
              {Prepend[Rest[DatePlus[{2011, 1, 1}, #]], yr_], temp_}, Infinity]] &, 365, 0];

Take[N[props], 5] (* sample *)
   {0.705882, 0.588235, 0.705882, 0.676471, 0.705882}
```

To plot these proportions, you can do this:

```
DateListPlot[props, {{2011, 1, 1}, {2011, 12, 31}, "Day"},
             FrameLabel -> {None, "Proportion"}, Joined -> True]
```

[image: plot of proportion of cold days]

Pick the day of the year with the most number of "cold" instances:

```
Pick[Array[Rest[DatePlus[{2011, 1, 1}, #]] &, 365, 0], props, Max[props]]
   {{2, 18}}
```

So, at least for Stockholm, February 18 is often a cold day.