# Indicating the probability that a weather datum is above/below some given value on a geographic map

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, curated-data, geography

With help of the previous questions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13030/calculate-proportion-of-values-for-dates), I am analyzing weather data as daily `MeanWindSpeed` of some cities with the following code:

```
  {date, year, month, day, wind} = {1, 1, 2, 3, 2}

  cityWind1 = WeatherData["Bodo", "MeanWindSpeed", {{1973, 1, 1}, {2013, 5, 1},"Day"}];
  cityWind1[[All, date, year]] = 0

  slowWinddays1 = Select[cityWind1, #[[wind]] < 21 &];
  DateListPlot[{cityWind1, slowWinddays1}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

I have two problems.

1. I want to calculate the probability of the days that mean wind speeds higher than 21 km/hr and show it in the plot. It could be monthly or weekly outlet. I know the algorithm is too easy, but sorry guys I am new in town!
2. Most important, how can I show this probability in different geographic regions based on data from the available stations of that region. For example, assign a color to Norway and vary intensity to indicate the probability on the geographic map. That is to say, the more intense the color, the higher the probability.

Comment: I some some problems with your post: 1) you mentiona a previous question, but don't provide a link to it. 2) you talk about the probability the wind speed exceeds a certain value, but your code selects cases where the wind speed is below that value 3) I have no idea what "It could be monthly or weekly outlet" or "probability of the days that mean wind speeds higher than 21 km/hr" mean.

Comment: Hi,1-The link is provided 2-no problem!! you can calculate either lower than or higher than probability.3- Look at the link you will find what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint for the mapping thing:

```
d = {2013, 5, 1}; 
cords = Select[Reverse[CityData[#, "Coordinates"]] & /@ CityData[{All, "Norway"}], Head@# == List &];
Show[ListContourPlot[Join@@ {#,List@WeatherData[#,"MeanWindSpeed",d,d,"Day"}][[1, 2]]} & /@ cords], 
     Graphics[{Gray, Opacity[.5], CountryData["Norway", "Polygon"]}]]
```

Comment: belisarius thanks for the hint.Could you please show at least one day on the map?I think hint needs some hints!Please check

Comment: MANY THANKS!!!It was all!!

Comment: how can I show `ContourLabels` and `PlotLegends` on the map .it doesnt show that

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick answer for your first question (I'll let someone else handle the mapping (that's a lot of data to sort through).

Let's look at the *wonderful (cough)* city of Houston.

```
winddata = WeatherData[{"Houston", "Texas"}, "MeanWindSpeed", 
   {{1973, 1, 1}, {2013, 5, 1}, "Day"}];
```

Gather those values by day:

```
daysorted = GatherBy[winddata, #[[1, {2, 3}]] &];
```

Calculate the probability of each of those days exceeding a certain wind speed:

```
windspeed = 10;    
probs = Most[Probability[x >= windspeed, x \[Distributed] #[[All, 2]]]& /@  daysorted];
dates = Most@daysorted[[All, 1, 1]];
plotprobs = Transpose[{dates, probs}]; (*prepare for plotting*)
```

Plot away:

```
winddata[[All, 1, 1]] = 0;
slowWinddays1 = Select[winddata, #[[2]] < windspeed &];
plot1 = DateListPlot[plotprobs, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 600];
plot2 = DateListPlot[{winddata, slowWinddays1}, ImageSize -> 600];
Column[{plot2,plot1}]
```

Aside: Yes, you don't have to use `Probability`, but why not?

[image]

Comment: Hi.Many thanks!But I think we have not some data in some places and thats the reason in some area we might have missing `Probability` .Am I right?BTW how can I add all months abbreviations to the plot?

Comment: As I read the plots, you have posted them in the order `plot2` above by `plot1`, while your code displays them in the order `plot2` above `plot1`. Suggest you edit to change the order.

Comment: @m_goldberg, Aye, good call, I'll swap them in code...