# Show Legend with 3D ListPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating legends for plots with multiple lines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/creating-legends-for-plots-with-multiple-lines)

I am trying to plot the color bar that shows the data range for the data plotted by `ListPlot3D`. I want to ask if I can use the `ShowLegend` command with the `LisPlot3D`? My code is as the following :

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"];
s = Import["C10002.xls"]
Rotate[ListPlot3D[s, PlotRange -> {0.048, 0.22}, Mesh -> None, 
  AxesLabel -> 
  Style[StandardForm[\[Phi]], FontSize -> 20, FontWeight -> "Bold"]],
  30 Degree, {0, 1, 0}]

ShowLegend[
  ListPlot3D[s, PlotRange -> {0.048, 0.22}, Mesh -> None, 
  AxesLabel -> 
  Style[StandardForm[\[Phi]], FontSize -> 20, FontWeight -> "Bold"]],
  LegendPosition -> {1.1, -.4}]
```

I will be very thankful for your help.

Comment: I would say this is a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4025/5 Do not use the `PlotLegends` package... it is absolutely terrible.

Comment: More to the point, there is an example of a `ListPlot3D` in the [`PlotLegends` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/PlotLegends/tutorial/PlotLegends.html) that shows how to use `ShowLegend` in that context. The main trick is to include a second argument to instruct `ShowLegend` what colors and data range to use, e.g. `{ColorData["Rainbow"][1 - #1/0.22] &, 10,  " 0", "0.22",  LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.4}}`.

Comment: By the way, Yousef, welcome to Mathematica.SE! Please consider [registering your account](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/login). That way, you can use the same account from different locations and accumulate any reputation you might gain from upvotes on your posts.

Comment: Verbeia Thanks so much for your comments it helped me so much ! I agree with you that PlotLegends is a poor package.