# Extra lines in the legend of a ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating legends for plots with multiple lines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/creating-legends-for-plots-with-multiple-lines)

Why does the legend of this plot have 5 lines (in mathematica 8, at least) instead of 3?

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[Table[{k Cos[x], k*Sin[x]}, {k, 1, 3}]], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Purple, Thick], 
   Directive[Thick, Orange, Dashing[{.03}]]}, 
 PlotLegend -> Range[1, 3], LegendPosition -> {.5, -.8}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How could I plot the legend correctly?

--EDIT--

This is not an answer, but it may come handy to someone with the same problem:

[Creating legends for plots with multiple lines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/creating-legends-for-plots-with-multiple-lines)

replacement of `PlotLegend` works.

Comment: This seems to be another example of the many problems of the much-vilified pre-9 `PlotLegends` package.