# ParametricPlot and PlotLegends don't seem to cooperate

Tags: plotting, bugs, legending

**Bug introduced in 9.0.1**  -- fixed in 10.0.0?

---

I noted that only part of the legend shows up in `ParametricPlot` using v9's `PlotLegends`:

```
ParametricPlot[{{t, t}, {t, 2 t}}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{1, 2}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Inspecting the figure's `FullForm` gets me (among other things)

```
LineLegend[
 List[
   Directive[EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0.5`]], Hue[0.9060679774997897`, 0.6`, 0.6`]]
 ], List[1, 2], 
 Rule[LegendLayout, "Column"]]
```

It looks like Mathematica forgot to add the second color. Adding the color manually gets me the full legend. This looks like a bug, but perhaps I'm missing something?

I also noticed that virtually all examples in the "Options/PlotLegends" section of the `ParametricPlot` doc page yield a result differing from the pre-rendered image. Again, this looks like a bug, perhaps introduced by a last-minute addition. I'm using v9.0.1. Anyone with v9.0.0 care to check whether it exists there as well?

Comment: The problem seems to be that the plot legends code is not parsing the first argument to `ParametricPlot` correctly and identifying the different functions. It incorrectly lists all the terms as a single entry and this can be seen by setting `PlotLegends -> "Expressions"`. In essence, the bug is the equivalent of plotting 2 curves but labeling only 1 (but somewhere inside, the code _does_ know that there are 2 curves, since the line color is pink)

Comment: Both legends show as expected in Version 9.0.0 (on Windows Vista 64 bit)

Comment: And legends show as expected if you use [this old method](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/245) with `autoLegend`...

Comment: @kguler So, as hypothesized, something added in the latest update breaks `PlotLegends` in this case.

Comment: If you have **10.0.0** installed would you please check to see if this was fixed in that release?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have no installation of v10 at a release lower than 10.0.1. It works correctly there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The work-around posted by rcollyer can readily be generalized to work for an arbitrary number of parametric functions.

```
With[{funcList = {{t, t}, {t, 2 t}, {t, t/2}}},
  With[{n = Length@funcList}, 
    Legended[ParametricPlot[funcList, {t, 0, 1}], 
      LineLegend[(ColorData[1][#])& /@ #, #]& @ Range @ n]]]
```

[image]

Comment: @kguler gives a nice variation of this in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72045/10 that still uses PlotLegends (with Placed), still using LineLegends to workaround the bug as you have done.

Answer (score 5):

To flesh out your method, you can do the following

```
Legended[
 ParametricPlot[{{t,t},{t,2 t}},{t,0,1}],
 LineLegend[{ColorData[1][1], ColorData[1][2]}, {1, 2}]
]
```

[image]

which, as noted, requires you to set the color information by yourself. This is the most straightforward workaround.

Incidentally, it is often cleaner to look at the `InputForm` instead of the `FullForm` as things like `List` are not fully expanded. For this, I often use something like this,

```
Plot[{x^2, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> Automatic] /.
  Legended[_, {p_Placed, ___} | p_Placed]:> InputForm@p[[1]]

(* 
 LineLegend[{Directive[Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6]], 
  Directive[Hue[0.9060679774997897, 0.6, 0.6]]}, {1, 2}, 
  LegendLayout -> "Column"
 ]
*)
```

Comment: Apparently, Wolfram tech support was wrong when they told me "there is no good way of working around the problem".

Comment: @m_goldberg This was the line of solution I was hinting at in my question.

Comment: @rcollyer I have the habit of using `FullForm` because that's the form that will be used in pattern matching, but I agree that `InputForm` is often much clearer and is preferable when one just wants to see what's going on.

Comment: @m_goldberg don't necessarily blame them, I've been staring at this particular code for quite a while, so I have a good feel for how it works.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I had the same habit until I had to start looking at `Graphics` objects. `FullForm` would drive you insane pretty quickly.

Answer (score 3):

I queried Wolfram technical support on this issue. Here is their reply:

> Our developers are aware that PlotLegends is currently not working well
>   with ParametricPlot.  This problem should be fixed in a future version of
>   Mathematica.
>
> Unfortunately, there is no good way of working around the problem with
>   PlotLegends at the current time.  If you really need a legend with a
>   ParametricPlot, you might have to use the older PlotLegend function, which
>   is still available in Mathematica.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in Version 10!? -> [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72661/no-legends-in-parametric-plot)

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [Phab](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/6402/phab) the example in the question works in *Mathematica* 10.0.2:

```
ParametricPlot[{{t, t}, {t, 2 t}}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{1, 2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I arrived at this thread after observing a similar problem in 10.1.0.  `PlotLegends->Automatic` gives up after 15 curves.  Fortunately, I can still make the legends show correctly with `PlotLegends->LineLegend[Range[n]]` for n at least as big as 26.

Comment: @djphd Indeed, that is a known issue.  The limitation is not arbitrarily fifteen, but rather the number of colors in the style.  Please see [(66057)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66057/121) for more.