# PlotLegends won't generate automatically more than 15 labels in v10

Tags: plotting, legending

**Update: NOT fixed in V10.0 - 12.0.0**

---

While testing the examples from this recent [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65978/how-can-i-plot-a-large-number-of-functions-and-use-a-to-signal-more-inbetw), i've noticed a problem in V.10 with **`PlotLegends`** when it has to **automatically** generate more than 15 labels (i.e. when there are more then 15 functions to plot). There's no problem with V.9.

The problem concerns the option values : [`Automatic`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Automatic.html) and `"Expressions"`. For example :

```
Plot[Evaluate[Range[20] + x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[Range[20] + x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

No problem however when you specify explicitly the labels in the legend :

```
Plot[Evaluate[Range[20] + x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotLegends -> Range[20]]
```

[image]

Comment: As I understand Mr.Wizard's answer, I would not consider this a bug but surmise it is a conscious, reasonable (undocumented) design decision by WRI.  Have you reported it to WRI and did they have a response?

Comment: @MichaelE2 No, I did not and do not actually plan to report that, it' s rather a minor problem, there are simple workarounds. Since it works in version 9 and there are no obvious reason why it have to be modified, I tagged it as a "bug". If not, it should be at least tagged in some way I guess ... "undocumented change" ;) I have actually bookmarked several posts which, I think, lack at least a warning tag. I've planned to post a question about that to meta because that bug tag mechanism is not actually clear for me.

Comment: I do think such restrictions ought to be documented (under "Possible Issues") so that users don't waste time trying to figure out why it doesn't work.  And perhaps a warning message and way to override.  My preference would be the V9 way plus a warning when the number of legends exceeds the number of colors.  I mention this just in case someone at WRI takes a look. :)

Comment: @SquareOne I removed the bugs tag according to community practice, as there is neither consensus nor confirmation (from WRI) that this is a bug.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We may observe that the automatically generated legend limits the number of legend items to the number of available colors in the given color scheme.  Using this utility function:

```
plot[scheme_] := Plot[Evaluate[Range[20] + x], {x, -5, 5},
   PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotStyle -> scheme]
```

Observe the result for indexed color scheme #42 which has only four colors:

```
plot[42]
```

[image]

There are eight in #26:

```
plot[26]
```

[image]

As since there are 21 in #60 all your lines have a legend:

```
plot[60]
```

[image]

And if you specify a gradient color scheme:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Range[50] + x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 PlotStyle -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, well, obviously. Otherwise they aren't distinguishable. (Yes, this was a well duh moment for me.)

Comment: @Kuba no it doesn't. You just need a color scheme that has enough colors, otherwise the legend algorithm says it can't distinguish them. So, they're not useful.

Comment: @rcollyer I know :) I should have GoldenBadge "Missunderstood guy"

Comment: The number of colors in the "Expressions" scheme is indeed 15. `Plot[Evaluate[Range[20] + x], {x, -5, 5}, 
    PlotLegends -> "Expressions"] // 
   Cases[#, RGBColor[_, _, _], -1] & // Union // Length` gives 15.

Comment: @SquareOne `"Expressions"` is not a color scheme.  The [default colors for `Plot` in v10](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54629/121) are given by `ColorData[97, "ColorList"]` (length 15).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks for the links. The doc is really not clear about that.

Comment: 10 colors is the most common for "Indexed" colors and 21 is the maximum number of colors. `Tally[Length@ColorData[#, "ColorList"] & /@ Range@Length@ColorData["Indexed"]]` gives `{{15, 24}, {9, 14}, {10, 48}, {11, 7}, {8, 7}, {6, 1}, {7, 1}, {4,1}, {13, 4}, {12, 2}, {21, 2}, {14, 2}}`

Comment: @Bob A shorter way to write that: `Length /@ ColorData["Indexed", "ColorList"] // Tally`

Comment: @MrWizard - Thank you, that is much better.

Answer (score 3):

You can use indexed colors as color function to generate as many distinct colors as you like. For example, although

```
Length @ ColorData[97, "ColorList"]
```

> 15

we can generate 100 distinct colors mapping `ColorData[97]` on `Range[100]`

```
ColorData[97] /@ Range[100] // CountDistinct
```

> 100

```
ColorData[97, "Range"]
```

> {1, ∞, 1}

```
ColorData[97, "ColorFunction"]
```

[image]

```
ColorData[97, "ColorFunction"] // InputForm
```

[image]

A nice illustration suggested by @Mr.Wizard in comments:

```
ArrayPlot[Partition[ColorData[97] /@ Range[500], 21], 
 Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> White, ImageSize -> 1 -> 30]
```

[image]

So ... if we use `PlotStyle -> (ColorData[97]/@Range[20])` the issue goes away:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Range[20] + x], {x, -5, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> (ColorData[97] /@ Range[20]), 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

and with `PlotLegends -> Automatic` we get

[image]

Note that removing the `PlotStyle` option or the setting `PlotStyle -> 97` or `PlotStyle -> ColorData[97]` we get only 15 distinct colors:

```
colorswithdefaultplotstyle =  Cases[Plot[Evaluate[Range[20] + x], {x, -5, 5}, 
    PlotLegends -> "Expressions"], {Directive[_, col_, ___],
   _Line} :>  col, All];

{Length @ #, CountDistinct @ #} & @ colorswithdefaultplotstyle
```

> {20, 15}

This works for all 113 indexed colors.

```
$Version
```

> 11.3 .0 for Microsoft Windows (64 - bit) (March 7, 2018)

Comment: Crazy!  I always thought they were cyclic and it never occurred to me to check.

Comment: I rather like this illustration: `Grid[Partition[ColorData[97] /@ Range[500], 21], Spacings -> {0, -0.1}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, great idea. I updated with a variation of your suggestion.