# Different color for different lines in the Lineplot

Tags: plotting

I have a 30 different line plot I wanted to represent it with different color, How to carry this, I used [`ColorData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorData.html) function to generate different color, but it is not exceeding more than 15

```
colors = ColorData[63, "ColorList"][[;; 30]];
Show[Table[ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{xaxis[[i]], yaxis[[i]]}],Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> colors[[i]]]]
```

Comment: related  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66055/plotlegends-wont-generate-automatically-more-than-15-labels-in-v10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
colors = ColorData[63] /@ Range[30]
```

[image]

to get 30 different colors from color scheme `63`.

```
CountDistinct @ colors
```

> 30