# No legends in parametric plot

Tags: plotting, legending

plotting some descibing functions, I wondered why I don't get any legends in my plot.

The describing functions (and options):

```
N1[a_] := (4 d)/(π a)
N2[a_] := (4 d)/π 1/(I ϵ + Sqrt[a^2 - ϵ^2])
N3[a_] := (4 d)/(π a) Sqrt[1 - (ϵ/a)^2] - I (4 d ϵ)/(π a^2)
N4[a_] := (4 d)/(π a) E^(-I ArcSin[ϵ/a])

opt = {d -> 1, ϵ -> 5}
```

and the `ParametricPlot`

```
ParametricPlot[{
   (*{Re@N1[a],Im@N1[a]},*)
   {Re[N2[a]], Im[N2[a]]},
   {Re@N3[a], Im@N3[a]},
   {Re@N4[a], Im@N4[a]}
   } /. opt, {a, .001, 1000},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotPoints -> 1000,
 MaxRecursion -> 15,
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

(The first function is out commented, because it has wired behavior. Bonus for the one who can explain it ;-) )

What I get is this:

[image]

Why are there no legends? Is it because of the userdefined functions?

Comment: see [parametricplot-and-plotlegends-dont-seem-to-cooperate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21104/parametricplot-and-plotlegends-dont-seem-to-cooperate)

Comment: @Nasser According to Mr. Wizard's answer the problem behind your link doesn't last for Mma V10!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a variation of [Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/121).  By using `/.` the head of the first argument is `ReplaceAll` rather than a `List`, and the styling subroutine of `ParametricPlot` does not know what to do with it.

Make the substitutions part of the definitions and you get this:

```
N1[a_] := (4 d)/(π a)                                       /. opt
N2[a_] := (4 d)/π 1/(I ϵ + Sqrt[a^2 - ϵ^2])                 /. opt
N3[a_] := (4 d)/(π a) Sqrt[1 - (ϵ/a)^2] - I (4 d ϵ)/(π a^2) /. opt
N4[a_] := (4 d)/(π a) E^(-I ArcSin[ϵ/a])                    /. opt

opt = {d -> 1, ϵ -> 5}

ParametricPlot[
 {{Re@N2[a], Im@N2[a]},
  {Re@N3[a], Im@N3[a]},
  {Re@N4[a], Im@N4[a]}}, {a, .001, 1000}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 1000, 
 MaxRecursion -> 15, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the link to the topic with an explanation why it doesn't work.