# Font size in PlotLegends, using Table to generate the list in the legend

Tags: legending, list-manipulation, fonts, labeling, plotting

I am currently trying to get to graph with several functions as below. My problem is that I cannot change the font size in the legend (authomatically generated numbers by "Table" function). This code below is the best what I can get. Does anyone know how to insure that also automatically generated numbers have font size of 16 (or any).

### Thanks!

```
<<PlotLegends`
Plot[
  Evaluate[(g (-1+q)^2 (a+b+g (1-q ) s)^2)/((a+b+g-g p q)^3) 
             /.{q->4/5,p->1/4,a->0.1,g->500,s->Range[0.1,3,0.4]}
  ],
  {b,0,100},
  AxesLabel->{b,F},
  PlotLabel->Style["q = 4/5, p = 1/4",FontSize->14],
  PlotStyle->Directive[Thick],
  PlotLegend->Table[Row[{Style["s = ",Bold,Italic,FontSize-> 16],i}],{i,0.1,3,0.4}],
  LabelStyle->Directive[Italic,FontFamily->"Helvetica",FontSize->12],
  LegendPosition->{0.5,-0.8}
]
```

Comment: If you have version 9 you should probably switch to the much better, built-in `PlotLegends` functionality.

Comment: Thank you for editing my code, I failed to do it properly...

Comment: No, unfortunately I have Version 7... I saw that in 9 it is much more efficient...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use ``` Style[StringForm["s = ``", i], Bold, Italic, 16] ``` to combine number and string (and quite a bit of `PlotLegends` parameter fumbling):

```
<< PlotLegends`
Plot[Evaluate[(g (-1 + q)^2 (a + b + g (1 - q) s)^2)/((a + b + g - g p q)^3) 
               /. {q -> 4/5, p -> 1/4, a -> 0.1, g -> 500, s -> Range[0.1, 3, 0.4]}
     ], 
 {b, 0, 100}, 
 AxesLabel -> {b, F}, 
 PlotLabel -> Style["q = 4/5, p = 1/4", FontSize -> 14], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick], 
 PlotLegend -> Table[Style[StringForm["s = ``", i], Bold, Italic, 16], {i, 0.1, 3, 0.4}],
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Italic, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 12],
 LegendPosition -> {0.85, -0.55}, 
 LegendSize -> {0.6, 1.}, 
 ImageSize -> 600
]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks to both of you for your answers!! Both are extremely helpful. I will see which I will apply at the end as in fact I have several graphs (using "GraphicsGrid") but the same legend for all. But the hints you gave me provide already a lot of flexibility. Thanks again!!

Comment: @Cactusenok If you like it an upvote and/or accept would be nice   ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In your legend, you can replace the line

```
Row[{Style["s = ",Bold,Italic,FontSize-> 16],i}]
```

by this:

```
 Row[{"s = ", i}, BaseStyle -> {Bold, Italic, FontSize -> 16}]
```

Here, I just used an option for `Row` to specify the style, because both elements of `Row` are intended to have the same style. Your statement had `Style` wrapping only the first element of the `Row`.

**However**, the formatting of `PlotLegends` is so incredibly bad that the newly increased size of the legend gets cut off.

Therefore, I would suggest instead to use my `autoLegend` function: copy the first code block in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/245) and do this:

```
p = Plot[Evaluate[(g (-1 + q)^2 (a + b + g (1 - q) s)^2)/((a + b + g -
           g p q)^3) /. {q -> 4/5, p -> 1/4, a -> 0.1, g -> 500, 
      s -> Range[0.1, 3, 0.4]}], {b, 0, 100}, AxesLabel -> {b, F}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["q = 4/5, p = 1/4", FontSize -> 14], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick]];

autoLegend[p, 
 Table[Row[{"s = ", i}, 
   BaseStyle -> {Bold, Italic, FontSize -> 16}], {i, 0.1, 3, 0.4}]]
```

[image: autolegend]

For more instructions on how to change the placement and format of the legend, see the linked post.