# Control legend size when autoLegend is used with LinTicks

Tags: graphics, legending

It looks simple, but I'm been trying to solve this issue for days, but no luck yet. So, here I used `LinTicks`, as customized option and another graphic option.

Here is my code. I'm always trying to make it simple, but this thing gets heavier with a graphic option (autoLegend). If you know better way, please, let me know.

Please, find more information about [autoLegend](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/creating-legends-for-plots-with-multiple-lines/4028#4028) here. In addition, you can find [CustomTicks here](http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/), which I had to run the package before running my code.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

(autoLegend inserted here)

```
σ = 5.67*^-8;(*Stefan-Boltzmann Constant*)
ϵ = 1;(*Emissivity*)
α = 1;(*Absorbtivity*)
τ = 1;(*Transmittance*)
g = 1*^3;(*Solar radiation 1Kw/m^2" *)
c = 2.28;(*Concentration*)
receff[x_] := α τ - (σ ϵ (x^4 - 293.15^4))/(c g);
syseff[x_] := (α τ - (σ ϵ (x^4 - 293.15^4))/(c g)) (1 - 293.15/x);
without = 
  Plot[Evaluate[{receff[x], syseff[x]}], {x, 293.15, 1073.15}, 
    PlotStyle -> (Directive @@@ 
      Transpose[{Join[ConstantArray[Dashed, 1], 
         ConstantArray[Thick, 1]], 
        Flatten[ConstantArray[{Black, Red}, 1]]}]), Frame -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{250, 1000}, {0, 1.05}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Temperature (K)", "Efficiency (%)"}, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], 
   FrameTicks -> {LinTicks[0, 1100, 200, 5], LinTicks[0, 1, 0.4, 5], None, None}, 
   ImageSize -> Large];

autoLegend[
 Show[without], {"Reciever w/ 2.28 Sun", "System w/ 2.28 Sun"}, 
 Background -> Directive[None, Opacity[.5]], Alignment -> {0.43, 0.8}]
```

I was able to make big text for Ticks, but I couldn't get Legend big.  I used Lintick to keep Ticks with high resolution image. When I enlarge an image without LinTicks, I lost Ticks. That's why I used LinTicks. But if you guys know to get around this, please, let me know too. Because I have to run the LinTicks package every time before I run this code to work.

If you know how to make it big, please, help me. It would be very appreciable. Thank you.

---

Here was what I got. As you can see, ticks are big as I wish, but I wasn't able to control the size of legend.

[image]

Comment: Please try to provide a shorter piece of code that illustrates the essence of your question.

Comment: So you're obviously using the [code from my answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/245). You shouldn't post such things without a link. Also, you're apparently using [LevelScheme](http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/). It will make it almost impossible for people to reconstruct what you're doing if you don't cite your sources. But I still don't understand the question. Do you have a problem that occurs only when using `autoLegend` with `LinTicks`? What version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: You can probably just add the option `BaseStyle -> Larger` to the `autoLegend` call. There is more information on controlling the dimensions of the legend in my linked post.

Comment: This link will hopefully tell you directly what to do: [Font size in PlotLegends, using Table to generate the list in the legend](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24806/245). I guess you want `autoLegend[Show[without],{"Reciever w/ 2.28 Sun","System w/ 2.28 Sun"},Background->Directive[None,Opacity[.5]],Alignment->{0.3,0.8},BaseStyle->{FontSize->18}]`

Comment: Oh, I apologize for not citing references. This is my first post here and I'm still running about the rules here. Thank you for your comments. I edited my previous post according to you guys comments. I'm using Mathematica 9.

Comment: Hi Jens, thank you so much for your comments. I tried by varying numbers in "BaseStyle->{F‌​ontSize->18}". But it doesn't change the font size.

Comment: If you're not using version 8 or before, you shouldn't need `autoLegend` unless you want backward compatibility for some reason. `autoLegend` was meant to be simple and concise to use, so it doesn't have many options.

Comment: Just to clarify: my suggested solution `BaseStyle->{F‌​ontSize->18}` does work without problem in *Mathematica* version 8 for which the `autoLegend` function was originally written. I tested it together with the `CustomTicks` package used in the question, too.

Comment: I now checked my suggestion above in version 10, too. It works there as well. So I can't reproduce your issue at all. Maybe it's specific to version 9. However, since I cannot reproduce the problem in version 10, I'm voting to close this as too localized.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem in the final form stated in the comment cannot be reproduced in versions 8 or 10 with `LevelScheme` installed and `autoLegend` used as suggested in the comments and linked answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Verbeia's advice, I tried to use the existing functions built in *Mathematica* and tried to make simple as possible. I was able to slim down my code. It looks simpler and cleaner. Thank you Verbeia for your advice.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
σ = 5.67*^-8;(*Stefan-Boltzmann Constant*)
ϵ = 1;(*Emissivity*)
α = 1;(*Absorbtivity*)
τ = 1;(*Transmittance*)
g = 1*^3;(*Solar radiation 1Kw/m^2" *)
c = 2.28;(*Concentration*)
receff[x_] := α τ - (σ ϵ (x^4 - 
     293.15^4))/(c g);
syseff[x_] := (α τ - (σ ϵ (x^4 - 
        293.15^4))/(c g)) (1 - 293.15/x);
Plot[Evaluate[{receff[x], syseff[x]}], {x, 293.15, 1073.15}, 
 PlotStyle -> (Directive @@@ 
    Transpose[{Join[ConstantArray[Dashed, 1], 
       ConstantArray[Thick, 1]], 
      Flatten[ConstantArray[{Black, Red}, 1]]}]), Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{250, 1000}, {0, 1.05}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Temperature (K)", "Efficiency (%)"}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[{"Reciever w/ 2.28 Sun", "System w/ 2.28 Sun"}, 
     LegendMarkers -> Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {12, 24}, 
     LabelStyle -> 20], {0.73, 0.8}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My main suggestion would be to use existing legending functionality in version 9+, e.g. `LineLegend` rather than hack things together from scratch like this.

I think the main issue with your code and the reason it does not work, is that you are not actually providing any means for text-formatting options to affect your labels. The relevant piece of code in `legendMaker` is

```
Text[#3, FormatType -> TraditionalForm]
```

You should change this to something like

```
Style[Text[#3, FormatType -> TraditionalForm], FilterRules[opts, Style]]
```

You then need to make the functions actually accept and pass the options to `Style`. The way you are using `OptionsPattern`, this won't work currently.  As the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptionsPattern.html) says,

> `OptionsPattern[]` uses the default options of the nearest enclosing function.

So an option that is not explicitly defined for `autoLegend` or `makeLegend` won't get passed down. The way around that is to change the function definition from

```
legendMaker[textLabels_, opts : OptionsPattern[]]
```

to

```
legendMaker[textLabels_, opts : OptionsPattern[{legendMaker, Style}]]
```

And similarly for `autoLegend`.

I won't fix up the code for you completely because I honestly think that you should base your `autoLegend` function on the existing built-in legending functionality. You could then just use `LabelStyle` to style your text.

Comment: Hi Verbeia, thank you so much for your comments. I just started run Mathmatica and am trying to run hard, but it is not easy at all. After picking up very basic, I started worked on graphics, so I can use Mathematica for my real life, but yes, I don't have a sound understanding of Mathematica yet. Thank you so much for your advice. I will try.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you are a beginner I would suggest trying to do simple things first, like using the built-in legending functionality instead of taking custom stuff from this site that was designed for an earlier version of the program. Since you mention in another comment that you are using version 9, none of this extra complexity is necessary.

Comment: I totally agree. My rule of thumb is to write simple as much as I can, but I ended up like this messed codes. The reason I used LinTicks was that Ticks were disappeared after exporting the graph in high resolution as discussed here. [link] (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51367/export-high-resolution-figure-causes-missing-ticks) This is how I ended up with LinTicks. In addition, I thought autoLegend make my code simple, but I guess I was wrong. I will listen your advice. Thank you so much for your help.