# "Save Graphic As..." does not include plot legends

Tags: plotting, export

I am creating some plots with `Show` but unfortunately the `PlotLegends` seems to be out of the bounding box when saving the graph.

Sample code:

```
data1 = {1, 2, 3};
data2 = {3, 4, 5};
Show[ListPlot[data1, PlotLegends -> {"Somedata1"}], 
ListPlot[data2, PlotLegends -> {"Somedata2"}]]
```

Is there a way to include them so they can be exported along with the image?

Comment: @YvesKlett, ill fix that straight away.

Comment: @YvesKlett, went a tad too quick. It should be fixed now.

Comment: If you want to export it as a raster image, you can always use `Rasterize`.

Comment: Have you tried the `legendMaker` and the `autoLegend` functions in this [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/creating-legends-for-plots-with-multiple-lines)? It works perfectly for me and is the best solution for legends in MMA I've ever discovered on this site.

Comment: Actually, you can use `Export` command to export your result as a picture such that `Export["test.jpg",(*your result*)]`. By this way the legend is included.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
data1 = RandomReal[10, {10}];
data2 = RandomReal[10, {10}];
Show[ListPlot[data1, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Somedata1"}, {1, .5}]], 
ListPlot[data2, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Somedata2"}, {1, .4}]]]
```

For different colors, just one `ListPlot` is enough sometimes.

```
ListPlot[{data1,data2},PlotLegends->Placed[{"Somedata1","Somedata2"},{1,.5}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have found a way of making a pdf or eps file from a Plot with a Legend. Click on the plot till everything is selected, including the legends. Then save it a a pdf or eps file.... and that is it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Show[]`, you should use all the data set in a single `Plot[]` (for your case it is `ListPlot[]`). It will automatically assign different `Style` or `PlotMarker` to distinguish different plots. And you can always put the legend at your desired position. As an example

```
data1 = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, .1}]; label1 = "Sine";
data2 = Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, .1}]; label2 = "Cosine";

Needs["PlotLegends`"]
position = {0.25, 0.25};
size = {0.3, 0.2};
ListPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, PlotLegend -> {label1, label2}, LegendShadow -> None, LegendBorder -> Automatic, LegendSize -> size, LegendPosition -> position]
```

You can easily vary the position of your Legend and in will be in the same place in exported file as well.

Answer (score 0):

With "Export " you can export the graph to the currect directory or another directory.

```
data1 = {1, 2, 3};
data2 = {3, 4, 5};
g = Show[ListPlot[data1, PlotLegends -> {"Somedata1"}], 
  ListPlot[data2, PlotLegends -> {"Somedata2"}]]

currentdirectory = NotebookDirectory[]
Export[currentdirectory <> "/mylistplot.pdf", g]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Show[]` as in your example code, you can also **right-click on** the **output cell bracket** (on the right of your nb) **-> Save selection as** -> your desired filetype (e.g. .svg, .pdf). This will also include the `PlotLegends`.