# Legends for multiple curves

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

Dear users I am a new member here and I would like to ask a question about `PlotLegends`.

I have multiple curves and want to make their legends bit more *visible*. Here is a sample code:

```
Plot[{Sin[h], Cos[h], Tan[h]}, {h, 5, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{GrayLevel[0], Dashing[None],Thickness[0.005]}, 
                {GrayLevel[0], Dashing[0.01],Thickness[0.005]}, 
                {GrayLevel[0], Dashing[0.02],Thickness[0.005]}, 
                {GrayLevel[0], Dashing[0.03],Thickness[0.005]}}, 
  Axes -> False, Frame -> True,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"sin", "cos", "tan"}, Top]]
```

I assume that the problem comes from the `Dashing[]` specifications making the legends line not *visible* enough.I may have up to 7 curves so i need and alternative to `Dashing[]` or any other way to increase lengths of legends and make them more  *visible*.

Comment: Welcome to MMA.SE! What do you mean by "a bit more visible"? If you can post some code you already tried, then all the better. Otherwise it might be difficult to answer your question properly.

Comment: You can try [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/creating-legends-for-plots-with-multiple-lines/4028#4028) if you are using `PlotLegend` on a version of _Mathematica_ < 9.

Comment: i applied standard PlotLegend; and i was sure every body would know that the legends created by it are too short and dashing is not visible at all in most of the cases. i want to know if i could increase the length of these legends. i have read something about legendmaker in this forum but i couldn't figure it our well. i cannot customize it for my problem so i will be really thankful if someone can guide me in that.

Comment: PlotLegend was standard pre version 9 (and there were many complaints about it). In v9 you use PlotLegends which is much better. Please state your version. If it is <9 follow Öska's link, if v9 then I'd say there's no general acknowledged problem with that.

Comment: But why using `Dashing[]` and not `Dotted`/`Dashed`/`DotDashed`?

Comment: Its version 9 and i used PlotLegends. but the legends are too short and dashing can not be distinguished. is there any standard way to increase their length so they might be distinguished? i have used dashing as some times we have to draw even 5 to 7 curves and i feel easier to control it that way.

Comment: As Yvers Klett said you should edit your question and add the `PlotLegends` that you used.

Comment: @yves I'm glad someone is still remembering to welcome new users!

Comment: Thanks Öskå for refining my post. For more (up to 7 say)curves,it is the best method which i have therefore i use dashing. if you have any other alternative which can serve the purpose i would be glad to know that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scaling of the `Dashing` gets messed up a little, therefore I suggest the following:

```
Plot[{Sin[h], Cos[h], Tan[h]}, {h, 5, 10}, 
      PlotStyle -> {
        {GrayLevel[0], Dashing[None], Thickness[0.005]}, 
        {GrayLevel[0], Dashing[Tiny], Thickness[0.005]}, 
        {GrayLevel[0], Dashing[Small],Thickness[0.005]}, 
        {GrayLevel[0], Dashing[Medium],Thickness[0.005]}}, 
      Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
      PlotLegends -> Placed[
                      LineLegend[
                        Automatic, {"sin", "cos", "tan"}, 
                        LegendMarkerSize -> {{45, 15}}],
                      Top]
     ]
```

`LegendMarkerSize` increases the `Length` of the Legend lines and {`Tiny`,`Small`,`Medium`} instead of numeric arguments transfer properly to the Legend.

[image]

Comment: Dear i think it solves my problem, but can you please tell me full list of these styles,i mean Tiny,Small,Medium then what? big or larg? please if you can tell me 7 of these my problem will be solves

Comment: Here i had 4 dashing styles; I need 3 more please let me know about them as well.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of `Dashing` here http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dashing.html. 
You only get four with Tiny, Small, Medium, Large (see Details section of page), but you can just specify `r` manually or a series of these (for different dash size patterns).