# A few specific questions on a number of plots in a do loop

Tags: plotting, legending

I have created the picture displayed below, with the following line of code:

```
Colors = List[Brown, Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Pink, Purple, Black];    
Show[Table[ 
      Plot[Part[list, i, 2]*Prob[Part[list, i, 2]*n] /. {y -> a, 
         z -> Part[list, i, 3]}, {n, 0, 3}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Thick, Part[Colors, i]}], {i, Length[list]}], 
     PlotRange -> {All, {0, 1.2}}]
```

The array list just contains sum numbers of the form { {a,b,c}, {c,d,e}, ...} and Prob is just some function, with constants y and z which I specify in the above.
There are a few questions I have concerning this code:

-Note that the axis of the graph appears to lie above zero. I would like to make a graph with its x axis really at y=0. How to do this?

-I would like to give every graph in the picture a different label, which is stored in Part[list, i,2]. However, I have two problems: PlotLegends gives an error and I only know how to include text between " ", not a number which is determined by the running of the do loop.

Any help is very much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Regarding the axes look for `AxesOrigin` like `Plot[Sin@x, {x, 0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, .5}]`. Regarding `PlotLegends`: are you on _V9_ or on _V8_?

Comment: @Öskå Thanks, AxesOrigin works! I am on V8 at work and on V9 at home :)

Comment: `PlotLegends` only works on _V9_. For the _V8_ you have to import `PlotLegend` (which is pretty ugly!) or use `autoLegend` from [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/1356)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to create the plots individually and then combine them with `Show`. You can specify the options as lists and one of the comments already tells you how to position the axes origin.

```
functions = {x, x^2};
styles = Thread[{Thick, {Red, Brown}}];
legends = Table["function " <> ToString[i], {i, 2}];
Plot[functions, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> styles, 
   PlotLegends -> legends, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0.6}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful. I have but one last question: if I use your method and I save the graphic, the legend is not included. How do I included it when I export the graph as a picture?

Comment: @Funzies: Are you exporting by selecting only the graph and the using the menu commands or are you exporting with `Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "test.png"}], 
 Plot[functions, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> styles, 
  PlotLegends -> legends, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0.6}]]`?