# Parametric plot of multiple graphs on the same axes

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, legending

I'm trying to plot on a single axes system multiple graphs but ran into a problem when tryinf to label my graphs. 
Here's what I've used so far

Mathematica code:

```
r1 = 0.5;
r2 = 1;
r3 = 2;
r4 = 2.5;
z[r_, t_] = {r ^2 Cos[2 t] - 2 r Sin[t], 2 r Cos[t] + r^2 Sin[2 t]};
zz[t_] = Table[z[r, t], {r, 0.1, 4, 0.5}];
ParametricPlot[{z[r1, t], z[r2, t], z[r3, t], z[r4, t]}, {t, 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> {Thick}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Re(z)", "Im(z)"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Large]]
```

Now, I can't seem to get the legends show, I simply want a number next to each color, say, 0.5 - (green) etc..

Ideally I would like a more elegant solution than having to manually set r1,r2,...

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, is `PlotLegends -> {r1, r2, r3, r4}` what you are after? Or you want to put `zz[t]` into `ParametricPlot` but one color is used, then [evaluation in `Plot`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/difference-in-plot-when-using-evaluate-vs-when-not-using-evaluate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In these cases I usually do the legend by hand (kind of like Kuba):

```
Module[{z, rmin = 0.1, rmax = 4, rstep = .5},
 z[r_, t_] := {r^2 Cos[2 t] - 2 r Sin[t], 2 r Cos[t] + r^2 Sin[2 t]};
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate@Table[z[r, t], {r, rmin, rmax, rstep}],
  {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
  PlotRange -> Full,
  PlotStyle -> {Thick},
  PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[
    Table[ColorData[1][r], {r, 1, Ceiling[(rmax - rmin)/rstep]}], 
    Table[ToString@z[r, t], {r, rmin, rmax, rstep}]],
  AxesLabel -> {"Re(z)", "Im(z)"},
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Large]]
 ]
```

[image]

but if you have a version earlier than 8, Jens's is definitely the way to go - don't go anywhere near the plot legends package!

Comment: Thanks! This works well. Any chance to avoid two contours having the same color?

Comment: The plot thickens, how do I copy both the plot and the legends as a single graphic file? Through the use of palette and save as or is there any other more direct way?

Comment: That depends on where do you want to copy to. If another notebook, just copy the whole cell by selecting the cell bracket. If a pdf file, use Export. Or you can select/highlight the whole graphic and choose Edit -> Copy As -> BitMap/PDF.

Comment: Indexed ColorData 1 and 63 are infinite number of colors palette, meaning colors don't repeat. However, there is no guarantee to always get a nice distinguishable color set.

Answer (score 4):

If you want legends, you may want to try the code I posted under [Creating legends for plots with multiple lines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/245). To use it, copy all the definitions in the first code block of that answer, then re-create your plot this way:

```
z[r_, t_] = {r^2 Cos[2 t] - 2 r Sin[t], 2 r Cos[t] + r^2 Sin[2 t]};
zz[t_] = Table[z[r, t], {r, 0.1, 4, 0.5}];
p = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[
    Table[
     Tooltip[z[rr, t], rr],
     {rr, {.5, 1, 2, 2.5}}
     ]
    ],
   {t, 0, 2 Pi},
   PlotRange -> Full,
   PlotStyle -> {Thick}, AxesLabel -> {"Re(z)", "Im(z)"},
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Large]
   ];

autoLegend[
 p,
 Table[rr, {rr, {.5, 1, 2, 2.5}}],
 Background -> Directive[LightOrange, Opacity[.5]],
 Alignment -> {Right, Bottom},
 BaseStyle -> Larger
 ]
```

[image: Legended]

Here I also added a `Tooltip` for each line in your plot (that's optional, I just wanted to point out this alternative). You may want to play with the positioning and size of the legend. It is explained in the examples for `autoLegend` in the linked answer.