# add a legend show the expression for each contour?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to visualizing the unit circle under different norm functions, here is the code:

```
ContourPlot[{
Abs[x]^(1/2)+Abs[y]^(1/2)==1,
Abs[x] + Abs[y] == 1,
x^2+y^2==1,
Abs[x]^3+Abs[y]^3==1,
Max[Abs[x], Abs[y]] == 1
},
{x, -1.1, 1.1}, {y, -1.1, 1.1}
]
```

I want to add a legend show the expression for each circle, how can this be done?

Comment: This can be easily found in docs: `PlotLegends -> "Expressions"`.

Comment: @Artes it does not label the curves though, does it?

Comment: `ContourLabels -> All` additionally displays tooltips...

Comment: @YvesKlett it would be nice to be able to grab/fix those?

Comment: @chris yes, in the help examples those are rendered as well.

Comment: qed, does Artes comments solve your problem? Also notice the you can use `Norm[{x,y}, p]` for a p-norm.

Comment: @Artes `PLotLegends->...` gives me this error: `ContourPlot::optx: "Unknown option PlotLegends in ContourPlot[\!\({\*SqrtBox[\(Abs[x]\)] + \*SqrtBox[\(Abs[y]\)] == 1, Abs[x] + Abs[y] == 1, \*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + \*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)] == 1, \*SuperscriptBox[\(Abs[x]\), \(3\)] + \*SuperscriptBox[\(Abs[y]\), \(3\)] == 1, Max[Abs[x], Abs[y]] == 1}, {x, \(-1.1`\), 1.1`}, {y, \(-1.1`\), 1.1`}, PlotLegends -> \"Expressions\"\)]."`

Comment: @qed Are you using *Mathematica* version 8? Then maybe you can use the solution to [Creating legends for plots with multiple lines](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/245): Copy the first code block and then do this:  `autoLegend[cc,{Abs[x]^(1/2)+Abs[y]^(1/2)==1,Abs[x]+Abs[y]==1,Abs[x]^2+Abs[y]^2==1,Abs[x]^3+Abs[y]^3==1},Alignment->{.1,Center}]` where `cc` is your `ContourPlot`.