# Adding plot legends in version 8

Tags: plotting, legending, version-8

I use *Mathematica* to draw the displacement, velocity, and acceleration of one point in a graphic.

```
FinalGraphics[Joint_, plotRange_List, opt_String] := 
  Module[{JointDisplacement, JointVelocity, JointAccelaration},
    JointDisplacement = Plot[Joint, {t, plotRange[[1, 1]], plotRange[[1, 2]]}];
  JointVelocity = 
    Plot[Evaluate @ D[Joint, t], {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed}];
  JointAccelaration = 
     Plot[Evaluate @ D[Joint, {t, 2}], {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Orange, Dashed}];
   Column[{
     Show[{JointDisplacement, JointVelocity, JointAccelaration}, 
       AxesLabel -> {Style["t(s)", 15], ""}, 
       AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.04], 
       PlotRange -> plotRange, 
       ImageSize -> 450, 
       GridLines -> {None, Automatic}], opt},
     Center]]
```

Now I use my function:

```
Joint1 = 
  -0.609735 + 0.0436332 t^2 + 0.0327806 t^3 - 0.0133248 t^4 + 0.00120561 t^5;
FinalGraphics[Joint1, {{0, 5}, {-.6, .5}}, "Graphic5.1  the displacement, velocity, acceleration of joint1"]
```

[image]

However, the above graphic lacks plotlegends, so I rewrite my code:

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
FinalGraphicsLegend[Joint_, plotRange_List] := 
  Module[{},
   Plot[{Joint, Evaluate @ D[Joint, t], Evaluate @ D[Joint, {t, 2}]}, 
     {t, plotRange[[1, 1]], plotRange[[1, 2]], 
     PlotLegend -> {"displacement", "velocity", "acceleration"}}]]
```

but it fails.

```
FinalGraphicsLegend[Joint1, {{0, 5}, {-.6, .5}}]
```

> General::ivar: 0.00010214285714285715` is not a valid variable. >>

So my question is:

*How do I correct the function `FinalGraphicsLegend` or add plot legends to the function `FinalGraphic` in some other way?*

Comment: Which version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: @Pickett,Version 8.0.4

Comment: Haven't checked the whole  thing, but a quick fix: `FinalGraphicsLegend[Joint_, plotRange_List] := Module[{}, 
  Plot[{Joint, Evaluate@D[Joint, t], Evaluate@D[Joint, {t, 2}]}, {t, plotRange[[1, 1]], plotRange[[1, 2]]}, PlotLegend -> {"displacement", "velocity", "acceleration"}, Evaluated -> True]]`

Comment: It also works if you use the `autoLegend` function defined in the first code block of my answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/245) and write the `Column` like this: `Column[{Show[autoLegend[Show[{JointDisplacement, JointVelocity, JointAccelaration}, AxesLabel -> {Style["t(s)", 15], ""}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.04], PlotRange -> plotRange, GridLines -> {None, Automatic}], {"displacement", "velocity", "acceleration"}], ImageSize -> 450], opt}]`

Comment: @Jens,Wow,Perfect!

Comment: @tangshutao Glad you like it - I added the tag for version 8 to this question to make it clearer that you can't solve it by using version 9 commands.

Comment: @belisarius,thanks for your help.However,the `PlotRange` becomes invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, a solution that was originally designed for version 8 is my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/245). After executing the definitions in your question and in the first code block of my answer, you just rewrite the plotting function as follows:

```
FinalGraphics[Joint_, plotRange_List, opt_String] := 
 Module[{JointDisplacement, JointVelocity, JointAccelaration}, 
  JointDisplacement = 
   Plot[Joint, {t, plotRange[[1, 1]], plotRange[[1, 2]]}];
  JointVelocity = 
   Plot[Evaluate@D[Joint, t], {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed}];
  JointAccelaration = 
   Plot[Evaluate@D[Joint, {t, 2}], {t, 0, 5}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Orange, Dashed}];
  Column[
   {
    Show[
     autoLegend[
      Show[{JointDisplacement, JointVelocity, JointAccelaration}, 
       AxesLabel -> {Style["t(s)", 15], ""}, 
       AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.04], PlotRange -> plotRange, 
       GridLines -> {None, Automatic}], {"displacement", "velocity", 
       "acceleration"}, Alignment -> {Right, Bottom}
      ], ImageSize -> 450
     ], opt
    }
   ]]

FinalGraphics[Joint1, {{0, 
   5}, {-.6, .5}}, "Graphic5.1  the displacement,velocity,accelaration of joint1"]
```

[image: plotlegends]

Here I set the legend to appear at the bottom right by adding the option `Alignment -> {Right, Bottom}` to `autoLegend`. The `autoLegend` command wraps the contents of the first row of your `Column`. In addition, I then wrap that output of `autoLegend` in another `Show` to adjust the `ImageSize`.

Answer (score 1):

Add the legends to each plot as follows:

```
FinalGraphics[Joint_, plotRange_List, opt_String] := 
 Module[{JointDisplacement, JointVelocity, JointAccelaration}, 
  JointDisplacement = 
   Plot[Joint, {t, plotRange[[1, 1]], plotRange[[1, 2]]}, 
    PlotLegends -> {"displacement"}]; 
  JointVelocity = 
   Plot[Evaluate@D[Joint, t], {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed},
     PlotLegends -> {"velocity"}]; 
  JointAccelaration = 
   Plot[Evaluate@D[Joint, {t, 2}], {t, 0, 5}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Orange, Dashed}, 
    PlotLegends -> {"acceleration"}]; 
  Column[{Show[{JointDisplacement, JointVelocity, JointAccelaration}, 
     AxesLabel -> {Style["t(s)", 15], ""}, 
     AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.04], PlotRange -> plotRange, 
     ImageSize -> 450, GridLines -> {None, Automatic}], opt}, Center]]

Joint1 = -0.609735 + 0.0436332 t^2 + 0.0327806 t^3 - 0.0133248 t^4 + 
  0.00120561 t^5; FinalGraphics[Joint1, {{0, 
   5}, {-.6, .5}}, "Graphic5.1 the displacement,velocity,accelaration \
of joint1"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Joint1 = -0.609735 + 0.0436332 t^2 + 0.0327806 t^3 - 0.0133248 t^4 + 0.00120561 t^5;

Needs["PlotLegends`"]

FinalGraphicsLegend[Joint_, plotRange_List] :=
  Plot[Evaluate[NestList[D[#, t] &, Joint, 2]], {t, plotRange[[1, 1]], plotRange[[1, 2]]},
    PlotLegend -> {"displacement", "velocity", "acceleration"},
    LegendPosition -> {0.25, -0.5},
    LegendSize -> {.6, .35}]

FinalGraphicsLegend[Joint1, {{0, 5}, {-.6, .5}}]
```

Comment: Thanks!I discovered that `the plotrange of y axis` will in valid in this solution.