# Plotting legends in contourplot

Tags: plotting, legending

In Mathematica 8.

Given this:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := z - x^2 - y^2 (*relation among the variable f[x,y,z]==0*)
parameter = Range[0.1, 1, 0.1];(*choice of parameter values*)
```

I'm trying to plot the level curves

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@Table[f[x, y, z] == 0, {z, parameter}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1,1}, PlotLegends -> parameter]
```

I have the next error message:

> ContourPlot::optx: "Unknown option PlotLegends in ContourPlot[{0.1
>   -x^2-y^2==0,0.2 -x^2-y^2==0,0.3 -x^2-y^2==0,0.4 -x^2-y^2==0,0.5 -x^2-y^2==0,0.6 -x^2-y^2==0,0.7 -x^2-y^2==0,0.8 -x^2-y^2==0,0.9 -x^2-y^2==0,1. -x^2-y^2==0},{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},PlotLegends->parameter]"

I tried using:

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]

ShowLegend[ 
  ContourPlot[Evaluate@Table[f[x, y, z] == 0,
    {z, parameter}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1,1}, PlotLegends -> parameter] ]
```

what I should do?

Comment: I had no problem evaluating what you provided ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8qh4N.png)). Which version of MMA are you using? Mine's 10.

Comment: @seismatica His post started with `[Mathematica 8]` though the formatting may have made it difficult to read.

Answer (score 5):

There are several problems here.  First, you are mixing syntax for two different systems: the old (poor) Plot Legends package from version 8 and prior, and the new improved integrated legend functions in version 9 and later.  The old package used the Option name `PlotLegend` while the new one uses `PlotLegends`, which I admit is confusing.

The second problem is that the [Plot Legends package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/PlotLegends/tutorial/PlotLegends.html) does not work for `ContourPlot` directly:

> There are two ways to use the functions in this package to place a legend in a graphic: the first can only be used as an option to the built-in functions Plot, ListPlot and ListLinePlot, while the second can be applied to any graphic.

You would need to manually specify the legend:

[image]

Something like this generic example from the documentation:

```
ShowLegend[
  DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, π}, {y, 0, π}],
  {ColorData["LakeColors"][1 - #1] &, 10, " 1", "-1", LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.4}}
]
```

[image]

Frankly I wouldn't bother however as almost no one likes the look of those legends.  Instead you could roll your own and use [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inset.html), or use Jens's solution from:

- [Creating legends for plots with multiple lines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4025/121)