# Add a legend to a DiscretePlot - Version 8

Tags: plotting, legending

I have found several topics with legend issues but no answer to my problem.
I have a function and I need to plot it for integers only (hence discrete plot) and then add a legend too. But `PlotLegend` does not work, its always red (my code gets red) and does not plot it. I can confirm that it does work when I use `Plot` instead of `DiscretePlot`. Nevertheless I need my variable to be positive integer.

```
function[gh_, ga_] := 
      If[gh == ga, 1 + 0.18^((gh + ga)^0.25), 
       1 + 0.18^((gh - ga)^2)^0.25];

DiscretePlot[{function[0, i]^i, function[0 + 1, i]^i, 
      function[0 + 2, i]^i}, {i, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

any ideas? I use *Mathematica 8.0.0.0*.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/1356)?

Comment: yes but it seems too complicated for what I needed to do. I cannot understand why I am not allowed to use PlotLegend with discreteplot. Nevertheless thanks for answering!

Comment: DiscretePlot[{function[0, i]^i, function[0 + 1, i]^i, 
  function[0 + 2, i]^i}, {i, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotLegends -> {"x", "y", "z"}] works fine in 10.0.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork V8 has a very bad legend maker :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I voted to close this as a duplicate but since the OP said "*it seems too complicated for what I needed to do*" here is a way to do it.

Copy the [whole code given by Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/1356) and modify the function `legendMaker` by commenting `Line[...]` in `f`:

```
If[#1 === {None} || (PlotStyle /. {opts}) === None, {}, Line[{{-.1,0}, {.1,0}}]]
```

should be:

> ```
> If[#1 === {None} || (PlotStyle /. {opts}) === None, {}, (* Line[{{-.1,0}, {.1,0}} *)]]
> ```

<sub>You can simply remove the whole line but commenting it allows you to use it afterwards.</sub>

---

Then simply use:

```
function[gh_, ga_] := If[gh == ga, 1 + 0.18^((gh + ga)^0.25), 1 + 0.18^((gh - ga)^2)^0.25];
p = DiscretePlot[{function[0, i]^i, function[0 + 1, i]^i, function[0 + 2, i]^i}, {i, 0, 30},
  PlotRange -> Full];

opts = Sequence[Background -> Transparent, RoundingRadius -> 10];
Overlay[{p, 
  legendMaker[{"1", "2", "3"}, 
   PlotStyle -> (ColorData[1][#] & /@ Range@3), 
   PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledSmallCircle]}, opts]}, 
 Alignment -> {Right, Top}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]