# PlotLegend frame disappears during Export

Tags: plotting, bugs, legending

**Bug introduced in 11.2 or earlier and persisting through 12.0**

---

I placed a framed `PlotLegend` and it works just fine in the notebook, but  after exported to `PDF` the legend frame disappeared.

Here's the data as example.

```
list={{{2, 2, 2, 2}, {10.9323, 10.9323, 10.9323, 
   10.9323}, {4.233}}, {{21.8656, 358.919}, {21.9156, 
   103.891}, {21.9656, -21.9377}, {22.0156, -52.9273}, {22.0656, 
   -32.5523}, {22.1156, 9.22699}, {22.1656, 54.4444}, {22.2156, 
   94.4478}, {22.2656, 124.699}, {22.3156, 143.77}, {22.3656, 
   152.507}, {22.4156, 153.301}, {22.4656, 147.381}, {22.5156, 
   136.734}, {22.5656, 122.683}, {22.6156, 107.942}, {22.6656, 
   92.2245}, {22.7156, 76.9519}, {22.7656, 63.8046}, {22.8156, 
   51.9468}, {22.8656, 42.5287}}}
```

And the plot function

```
fig = 
     ListPlot[Select[Re@#[[2]], # \[Element] Reals &] & /@ #, 
      PlotRange -> {{Min[#1] - 0.1, 
           Max[#2] - 
            0} &@(Sequence @@ (Transpose[{First[#[[2]]][[1]] - 0.1, 
                Last[#[[2]]][[1]]} & /@ #])), All}, Joined -> True, 
      ImageSize -> 500, 
      PlotLegends -> 
       Placed[LineLegend[(ToString[#[[1, 1, 1]]] <> "+" <> 
             ToString[#[[1, 1, 2]]] <> "\[Rule]" <> 
             ToString[#[[1, 1, 3]]] <> "+" <> 
             ToString[#[[1, 1, 4]]]) & /@ #, 
         LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}(*,LegendMarkerSize\[Rule]20*), 
         LegendMargins -> 3, LegendFunction -> "Frame"], {Right, 
         Top}], Frame -> True]&@ {list}
```

and now export

```
Export["~/Desktop/3.pdf", fig]
```

It's probably not caused by the exporting format because I tried `eps` but had no effect.

The figure before export:

[image: The figure before export]

The figure after export:

[image: The figure after export]

BTW my MMA version is 11.2.

Comment: Hello, did you figure out what happened? Same thing is happening to me. Would appreciate if you could share a hint of what's going on! thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`Export` is clearly not working correctly. One thing that works for me is:

1. click the graphic in your notebook to select it
2. right-click to bring up the context menu
3. "Save Graphic As..." and choose `PDF`.

This preserves the frame around the legend.

You could also try my `autoLegend` function from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/245). It's from the bad old days before `PlotLegends` were introduced in *Mathematica*, but it still works fine for me, and also exports properly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's wrong with the export,but a little bit change will do the job right. You could change `LegendFunction -> "Frame"` to `LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 4]&)` and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Export["TestPlot18" <> #, fig, ImageResolution -> 300] & /@ {".pdf", ".png", ".jpg"}
```

[image: poly]

Comment: I don't understand. I presume the only difference is `ImageResolution`? But I added it and it didn't work. Well, png works but that's the same as `Rasterize` I think? And it would looks really bad inside a pdf file, I mean, with latex.

Comment: But, we found that its works well  for pdf and jpg same ag png. We can sent you if you want.

Comment: That's weird. What's your MMA version? And thank you for your kindness but I want to solve this problem, at least find out what went wrong.

Comment: I am using MMA 10. There is typo in your  list data (inserted / at  {22.0656, \-32.5523} this point) . I found only one plot. as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You can click before the figure (Fig). Then write `Export["Fig is here",eps]`. Using this method you can export all parts of your figure.

Comment: The legend frame would become "Unevaluated["the legend"]".

Comment: I cannot run your `fig`. There are some errors.

Comment: There was an extra line break last line, it should be fine now.