# Plot legend inside a Show

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using PlotLegends with Show messes up the graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3518/using-plotlegends-with-show-messes-up-the-graphics)

I have created a composite plot function:

[image]

I want to add a legend to it, however `` << PlotLegends` `` seems not to work when inside a Show (Mathematica 8). Plots will probably be printed, so `Tooltip` won't work.

How can I create a legend for this plot?

Comment: please post the supporting code so we can see what can be done with it to solve your issue.

Comment: @RHall Note the use of **ShowLegend** instead **Show**. I did roll my own custom graphics, because I found it easier to archive prettier results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `ShowLegend` when you need to use the package's functionality with `Show`. Here's an example:

```
eqns = {Sin[3 Tanh[#]], Sin[Erf[#]]} &;
colors = {Blue, Red};
legends = TraditionalForm /@ eqns[x];

plot1 = Plot[Evaluate@eqns[x], {x, 0, π}, PlotStyle -> colors, 
    Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, LightGreen}}];
plot2 = ListPlot[Select[RandomReal[{0, Pi}, {1000, 2}], 
    IntervalMemberQ[Interval[Sort[eqns[First@#]]], Last@#] &], PlotStyle -> Darker@Green];

ShowLegend[Show[plot1, plot2], {{Graphics[{#1, Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}], #2} & @@@ 
   Transpose[{colors, legends}], LegendPosition -> {-0.65, -0.5}, 
   LegendSpacing -> 0, LegendShadow -> None, LegendSize -> 0.6}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the cool plot. I'll keep quiet about the legend aesthetics...

Comment: @Jens I had to restrain myself heavily to not say anything about the package and the quality of the output. I absolutely dislike `PlotLegends`, but for some reason, people continue to use it (and most likely don't want to be bothered with using primitives).

Comment: +1 for great answer. Exactly what I was hoping for :D Btw, to get default 'colors = Table[Hue[FractionalPart[0.67 + 2.0 (i - 1)/GoldenRatio], 0.6, 0.6], {i, 1, 2}];'

Answer (score 11):

You could perhaps use the `legendMaker` function I posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/creating-legends-for-plots-with-multiple-lines/4028#4028) (or a modified version of it). I use it with `Overlay` instead of `Show`. So you would do:

```
legendedPlot = Overlay[{plot, legendmaker[...]},Alignment->{...}]
```

Then you can export the result as

```
Export["file.pdf", legendedPlot]
```

Instead of exporting, the output of `Overlay` can also be **copied** into other applications (even though the overlay box isn't an editable graphic by default). Just highlight the output graphic and do a usual copy operation.

**Edit**

Thanks to R.M. for the nice example plot, which I couldn't resist trying to label my way, too... so here I repeat R.M.'s definition first,

```
eqns = {Sin[3 Tanh[#]], Sin[Erf[#]]} &;
colors = {Blue, Red};
legends = TraditionalForm /@ eqns[x];

plot1 = Plot[Evaluate@eqns[x], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotStyle -> colors, 
   Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, LightGreen}}];
plot2 = ListPlot[
   Select[RandomReal[{0, Pi}, {1000, 2}], 
    IntervalMemberQ[Interval[Sort[eqns[First@#]]], Last@#] &], 
   PlotStyle -> Darker@Green];
```

and now I label it to show the difference to the `Legends` package:

```
Overlay[{Show[plot1, plot2], 
  legendMaker[legends, PlotStyle -> colors]}, Alignment -> {-.5, -.8}]
```

[image: labeled plot]

Comment: Nice, you could also make your legend a `Locator` like in Simon's [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7221397), so that it can also be moved around where you want it — sometimes simpler than fiddling with positioning.

Comment: It seems this once was the state of the art for creating legends. Since quite a few years have passed since this answer was written and we are a few Mathematica versions further I was wondering whether this is this still the state of the art way to create labels. Or is using built in Mathematica functions now the way to go?

Comment: @Kvothe I still use the approach in my linked answer because it's less verbose than the built-in functionality - and because it gives you `Graphics` objects as output, instead of `Legended` which can cause confusion because it's an invisible wrapper (i.e., you get plot outputs that are of different `Head` merely by adding legends with the built-in option to the same plot command - which I think is terrible design). What I really use mostly is `autoLegend` from my other answer.