# How to manipulate nested expressions?

Tags: manipulate, replacement, expression-manipulation

I have the following expression, only slightly complicated, and I'd like to do two things:

1. `Plot` the elements of the lists (though messy, all are in the same
   range) in terms of the range of the random variable in
   `Expectation`. (0.1 in the working example)
2. Let the `Plot` work with `Manipulate` so that the user can
   experiment with different underlying values.

With all these `SetDelayed` used, I could not get `Manipulate` to work (`Plot` is simply slow). Basically, I am not sure if I can simply feed a new value for `underlying` into the last line (`Expectation`), or I need `Replace`, or some rule, a `Block`, or `With`?

```
underlying := {0.8,0.7,0.5,0.4,0.8,0.7}
answers := MapThread[(Min[1,Max[#1 + #2 ,0]])&,{underlying, {e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6}}]
disc :={answers[[5]],answers[[6]],answers[[3]]/answers[[1]],answers[[4]]/answers[[2]]} 
DB :={disc[[2]]/disc[[1]],disc[[1]]^2/disc[[2]]} 
db :={disc[[4]]/disc[[3]],disc[[3]]^2/disc[[4]]} 
deltasbetas = Expectation[{disc,DB,db},{e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6}
      \[Distributed]UniformDistribution[Table[{0,0.1},{6}]]]

(* {{0.85,0.75,0.647807,0.600891},{0.883373,0.965877},{0.931221,0.705072}} *)
```

Comment: Could you post your (non-working) Plot?

Comment: @belisarius: Thanks for your code below, I tried to comment on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Manipulate` of course works with `CompoundExpression`, sot the code below does what I was after. Thank you for all the help.

```
Manipulate[u={u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,u6};
  answers=MapThread[(Min[1,Max[#1+#2,0]])&,{u,{e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6}}];
  disc={answers[[5]],answers[[6]],answers[[3]]/answers[[1]],answers[[4]]/answers[[2]]};
  DB={disc[[2]]/disc[[1]],disc[[1]]^2/disc[[2]]};
  db={disc[[4]]/disc[[3]],disc[[3]]^2/disc[[4]]};
  deltasbetas[x_]:=NExpectation[{DB,db},{e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6}
   \[Distributed]UniformDistribution[Table[{0,x},{6}]]];
  Needs["PlotLegends`"];
  ListPlot[Transpose@Table[Flatten@deltasbetas[x],{x,0.01,0.51,0.05}],
   Joined->True,PlotLegend-> {"Delta","Beta","delta","beta"},
   LegendPosition->{1.1,-0.4},LegendShadow->None],
   {{u1,0.8},0,1,0.1},{{u2,0.7},0,1,0.1},{{u3,0.5},0,1,0.1},{{u4,0.4},0,1,0.1},
   {{u5,0.8},0,1,0.1},{{u6,0.7},0,1,0.1}]
```

The question is: Could it be any faster, like with some `Compile` or parallelization?

Answer (score 4):

Still slow, but much faster than yours:

```
u = {0.8, 0.7, 0.5, 0.4, 0.8, 0.7};
answers = MapThread[(Min[1, Max[#1 + #2, 0]]) &, {u, {e1, e2, e3, e4, e5,  e6}}];
disc = {answers[[5]], answers[[6]], answers[[3]]/answers[[1]], answers[[4]]/answers[[2]]};
DB = {disc[[2]]/disc[[1]], disc[[1]]^2/disc[[2]]};
db = {disc[[4]]/disc[[3]], disc[[3]]^2/disc[[4]]};
deltasbetas[x_] := NExpectation[{disc, DB, db}, {e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6} \[Distributed] 
                   UniformDistribution[Table[{0, x}, {6}]]]

ListPlot[Transpose@Table[Flatten@deltasbetas[x], {x, .1, 1, .1}], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice to keep it numeric, thanks!

Comment: I got a `$Failed` (in version 8.0.4), as NIntegrate tried to `e1 = x` as a limit and could not. Does the code you pasted work for you, verbatim? Just curious, I suspect my mistake, as usual. Thanks!

Comment: @László It works here. Try starting a clean session

Comment: Strange, that indeed did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Now I only need the whole thing to respond to the numbers in `u`. :) (Well, and also labeling this many lines somehow.)

Comment: `CompoundExpression` is enough, I'll post the answer...

Answer (score 3):

Several observations as a basis for paper-and-pencil approach which, in turn, "might" suggest the first steps of an alternative formulation working with univariate expectations:

- the components of the random vector `e` and, hence, those of the random vector `answers` are independent random variables
- the remaining random variables `discs`,`DB` `db` are products of independent random variables, hence their expectations are the products of the expectations of constituent RVs
- For each component of `answers`, we need four central moments (namely, 1,2, -1 and -2) to compute the expectations of the remaining random variables.

So, let

```
z[a_, e_] := Min[1, Max[a + e, 0]]
moment[a_, d_, m_Integer] := 
Expectation[z[a, e]^m, e \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, d}]]

Table[{i, moment[a, d, i]}, {i, {1, 2, -1}}] // TableForm
```

[image]

EDIT: Using the observations above and a modification of [Istvan's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3524/125) for making the legends:

```
expVal[a_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ] :=  
     NIntegrate[Min[1, Max[a + x, 0]]^m PDF[UniformDistribution[{0, d}], x], {x, 0, d}];

capDelta[a5_?NumericQ, a6_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ] := expVal[a6, d, 1] expVal[a5, d, -1];

capBeta[a5_?NumericQ, a6_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ] := expVal[a5, d, 1] expVal[a6, d, -1];

delta[a1_?NumericQ, a2_?NumericQ, a3_?NumericQ, a4_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ] := 
         expVal[a4, d, 1] expVal[a2, d, -1] expVal[a3, d, -1] expVal[a1, d, 1];

beta[a1_?NumericQ, a2_?NumericQ, a3_?NumericQ, a4_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ] := 
         expVal[a3, d, 2] expVal[a1, d, -2] expVal[a4, d, -1] expVal[a2, d, 1];

tbl[a1_?NumericQ,a2_?NumericQ,a3_?NumericQ, a4_?NumericQ,a5_?NumericQ, a6_?NumericQ] :=
   Transpose[{capDelta[a5, a6, #], capBeta[a5, a6, #], delta[a1, a2, a3, a4, #], 
              beta[a1, a2, a3, a4, #]} & /@  Table[i, {i, .1, 1, .1}]];

labels = {"Delta", "Beta", "delta", "beta"};
```

Using the definitions above:

```
Manipulate[lp = ListPlot[tbl[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6], 
     Joined -> True, DataRange -> {.1, 1}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", ImageSize -> 400]; 
  linestyles = Cases[lp, {directive__, line_Line} :> {directive}, \[Infinity]]; 
  Row[{lp, Grid[Table[{Graphics[Append[linestyles[[i]], Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}]], 
        ImageSize -> 50, AspectRatio -> 1/10], labels[[i]]}, {i, 4}], 
        Spacings -> 2, Alignment -> Left]}], 
{{a1, .5, "a1"}, .1, 1, .1}, 
{{a2, .5, "a2"}, .1, 1, .1}, 
{{a3, .5, "a3"}, .1, 1, .1}, 
{{a4, .5, "a4"}, .1, 1, .1},
{{a5, .5, "a5"}, .1, 1, .1}, 
{{a6, .5, "a6"}, .1, 1, .1}]
```

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks again, this is great. On pen-and-paper though, I hoped to have Mathematica and esp. Manipulate as a nice environment to track how my observations would change with different errors, so it would be great if things would work numerically whatever I throw at it (non-uniform errors, correlation etc.). But thanks!